# User Appreciation Challenge #1: Dennis ♦

Tags: code-golf, string, palindrome

I got the spontaneous idea of making a series of challenges of users that have helped and continue to help the PPCG community be an enjoyable place for everyone, or maybe just specifically for me. :P

If you convert Dennis's name to an array of `1`s and `0`s where each consonant is `1` and each vowel is `0`, the array is `[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`, which is symmetrical. Thus, your challenge is to determine what other names are like this.

## Challenge

Given an ASCII string, remove all characters that aren't letters and determine if the configuration of vowels and consonants are symmetrical. `y` is not a vowel.

Please note that your program does not have to be this type of string itself.

## Test Cases

```
Dennis -> truthy
Martin -> truthy
Martin Ender -> truthy
Alex -> falsy
Alex A. -> truthy
Doorknob -> falsy
Mego -> falsy
```

## Reference Implementation

This Python 3 code will give the correct output given a test case. It is as ungolfed as I could make it without being ridiculous.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)

```python
s = input()
l = []
for c in s:
	if c in 'AEIOUaeiou':
		l.append(0)
	elif c in 'BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
		l.append(1)
print(l == list(reversed(l)), end = '')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#VY7JCsIwFEXXzVdklwREdCt0odZ5nidcVPuq0ZjGJK3Dz9eAILg7HA6XmxvsYy5VailDwvFuj@JE46OT2FSQx@Mvk2qjM1qEwJOUOO2JYqgUyIiWGPJA/LJaPWi22t1efzAcT6az@XK13mwPEcSn8@UqblLdtbHZ4/l6/8@UGVKaS0vdCR8LbizVkIE2EFHBWAG7yN0jhOV5AFJy8wE)

Comment: When and who is #2?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks for reminding me. It's going to be about *Mego* (TNB RO hence the italics) but I haven't gotten around to finalizing it yet.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I'm pretty sure he knows already; I said I'd do one about him but I haven't decided if I'm going to do something relating to penguins or TNB yet.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Umm, you can't use italics in titles.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Aww :( That sucks.

Comment: @Hyperneutrino so multicharacter variable names are ridiculous now? ;)

Comment: @dylnan Yes, this is code golf :P At least I don't have spaces in my variable names (cough Kotlin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ǍAḂ⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLHjUHhuILigbwiLCIiLCJEZW5uaXMiXQ==)

```
Ǎ    # Non-alphabet chars removed
 A   # Vowel mask (1 for vowel, 0 for not)
  Ḃ⁼ # Is equal to its reverse?
```

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/releases/tag/v2.4.1), 7 bytes

```
Ǎk∨vcḂ⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C7%8Dk%E2%88%A8vc%E1%B8%82%E2%81%BC&inputs=eoiurhejweiei&header=&footer=)

-6 thanks to lyxal
-1 thanks to Underslash

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%C7%8D%C6%9Bk%E2%88%A8c%3B%E1%B8%82%E2%81%BC&inputs=Dennis&header=&footer=) for 8 bytes

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C7%8Dk%E2%88%A8v%E2%88%A9%E2%80%A0%E1%B8%82%E2%81%BC&inputs=Dooo&header=&footer=) for a flagless 8 bytes

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C7%8Dk%E2%88%A8vvc%E1%B8%82%E2%81%BC&inputs=dennis&header=&footer=) another 8 bytes, but this time it uses a fancy double vectorize :D

Comment: @Underslash Nice! I think that works with a single vectorise, so 7!

Comment: @Ausername I have mixed feelings about that, on the one hand, rip the double vectorize, but on the other hand, ez 7 bytes

Comment: @Underslash I'm not actually sure how double vectorise is meant to work :P

Comment: @Ausername that's strange, I assumed having multiple vectorizes would go a layer deeper so to speak, but it actually doesn't, so the fact that it worked there I believe is just coincidence.

Answer (score 20):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ŒufØAe€ØCŒḂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//xZJ1ZsOYQWXigqzDmEPFkuG4gv///yJEZW5uaXMi)

Alternate versions:

```
ŒlfØae€ØCŒḂ
```

```
ŒufØAe€ØcŒḂ
```

```
ŒlfØae€ØcŒḂ
```

Of course a challenge appreciating Dennis must have an answer in a language of his.

Comment: [Œuf](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C5%93uf) is _Egg_ in french. Just sayin'

Answer (score 18):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
žM¹álSåÂQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6D7fQzsPL8wJPrz0cFPg//8uqXl5mcUA)

-2 thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan).

This attacks Jelly's pain point exactly. It uses `l` and `A`, 1-byte equivalents for Jelly's `Œl` and `Øa` respectively.

Comment: Are you sure that this works? [Run this](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/x/Fwc/DRfQGHl7oEBf7/H1KeDwA)

Comment: @MCCCS Hmm, you may be right.

Comment: You can replace `AÃ` by `á` and `DR` by `Â`.

Comment: @Adnan Forgot about `á`, didn't know what `Â` does, thanks!

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but I'm pretty sure this is not 9 bytes in _any_ encoding. :-) Nine characters is another thing entirely... Is there some guidance on this in the site docs?

Comment: @alexis most of these golfing languages use 256 different characters and a custom codepage that maps hex `00` to `FF` to those 256 characters, see the Jelly answer

Comment: @alexis 4.5 years later, but to clarify _Stephen_'s comment a bit more: 05AB1E uses [this custom codepage of the 256 characters it knows](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage). The program `žM¹álSåÂQ` above are the bytes `9E 4D B9 E1 6C 53 E5 C2 51`. We can use the `--osabie` flag to compile and run it in Python. [Here a Bash script with the same program as raw bytes.](https://tio.run/##PcuxDoMgEIDh3ae4mK5I0WLi0A5V3@IWsJfgwpHAcD49tWni9g3/710OdeMPPVuUaUV5LCjvCWU1KOOMYofTFmXuT5u20hYYVARFcPt98IJCuXTOU5OOEjgOoDkVfbfOG9Kcnd@pSwco9ffV17pQjHv@Ag)

Answer (score 18):

### x86 32-bit machine-code function, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

Currently the shortest non-golfing-language answer, 1B shorter than [@streetster's q/kdb+](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123194/user-appreciation-challenge-1-dennis/123222#123222).

**With 0 for truthy and non-zero for falsy: <s>41</s> 40 bytes.**  (in general, saves 1 byte for 32-bit, 2 bytes for 64-bit).

**With implicit-length strings (C-style 0-terminated): <s>45</s> 44 bytes**

**x86-64 machine-code (with 32-bit pointers, like the x32 ABI): <s>44</s> 43 bytes**.

**x86-64 with implicit-length strings, still 46 bytes (the shift/mask bitmap strategy is break-even now).**

This is a function with C signature `_Bool dennis_like(size_t ecx, const char *esi)`.  The calling convention is slightly non-standard, close to MS vectorcall/fastcall but with different arg registers: string in ESI and the length in ECX.  It only clobbers its arg-regs and EDX.  AL holds the return value, with the higher bytes of EAX holding garbage (as allowed by the SysV i386 and x32 ABIs, and the Windows x64 calling convention.)

---

**Explanation of the algorithm**:

Loop over the input string, filtering and classifying into a boolean array on the stack:  For each byte, check if it's an alphabetic character (if not, continue to next char), and transform it to an integer from 0-25 (A-Z).  Use that 0-25 integer to check a bitmap of vowel=0/consonant=1.  (The bitmap is loaded into a register as a 32-bit immediate constant).  Push 0 or 0xFF onto the stack according to the bitmap result (actually in the low byte of a 32-bit element, which may have garbage in the top 3 bytes).

The first loop produces an array of 0 or 0xFF (in dword elements padded with garbage).  Do the usual palindrome check with a second loop that stops when pointers cross in the middle (or when they both point to the same element if there were an odd number of alphabetic characters).  The upward-moving pointer is the stack pointer, and we use POP to load+increment.  Instead of compare / setcc in this loop, we can just use XOR to detect same/different since there are only two possible values.  We could accumulate (with OR) whether we found any non-matching elements, but an early-out branch on flags set by XOR is at least as good.

Notice that the second loop uses `byte` operand-size, so it doesn't care what garbage the first loop leaves outside the low byte of each array element.

---

It uses the [undocumented `salc` instruction](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-salc.html) to set AL from CF, in the same way that `sbb al,al` would.  It's supported on every Intel CPU (except in 64-bit mode), even Knight's Landing!  [Agner Fog lists timings for it](http://agner.org/optimize/) on all AMD CPUs as well (including Ryzen), so if x86 vendors insist on tying up that byte of opcode space ever since 8086, we might as well take advantage of it.

Interesting tricks:

- [unsigned-compare trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932273/how-to-access-a-char-array-and-change-lower-case-letters-to-upper-case-and-vice/35936844#35936844) for a combined isalpha() and toupper(), and zero-extends the byte to fill eax, setting up for:
- immediate bitmap in a register for `bt`, [inspired by some nice compiler output for `switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97987/advantage-of-switch-over-if-else-statement/32356125#32356125).
- Creating a variable-sized array on the stack with push in a loop.  (Standard for asm, but not something you can do with C for the implicit-length string version).  It uses 4 bytes of stack space for every input character, but saves at least 1 byte vs. optimal golfing around `stosb`.
- Instead of cmp/setne on the boolean array, XOR booleans together to get a truth value directly.  (`cmp`/`salc` isn't an option, because `salc` only works for CF, and 0xFF-0 doesn't set CF.  `sete` is 3 bytes, but would avoid the `inc` outside the loop, for a net cost of 2 bytes (1 in 64-bit mode)) vs. xor in the loop and fixing it with inc.

```asm
; explicit-length version: input string in ESI, byte count in ECX
08048060 <dennis_like>:
 8048060:       55                      push   ebp
 8048061:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp  ; a stack frame lets us restore esp with LEAVE (1B)
 8048063:       ba ee be ef 03          mov    edx,0x3efbeee ; consonant bitmap

08048068 <dennis_like.filter_loop>:
 8048068:       ac                      lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[esi]
 8048069:       24 5f                   and    al,0x5f    ; uppercase
 804806b:       2c 41                   sub    al,0x41    ; range-shift to 0..25
 804806d:       3c 19                   cmp    al,0x19    ; reject non-letters
 804806f:       77 05                   ja     8048076 <dennis_like.non_alpha>
 8048071:       0f a3 c2                bt     edx,eax    # AL = 0..25 = position in alphabet
 8048074:       d6                      SALC     ; set AL=0 or 0xFF from carry.  Undocumented insn, but widely supported
 8048075:       50                      push   eax
08048076 <dennis_like.non_alpha>:
 8048076:       e2 f0                   loop   8048068 <dennis_like.filter_loop>   # ecx = remaining string bytes
 ; end of first loop

 8048078:       89 ee                   mov    esi,ebp  ; ebp = one-past-the-top of the bool array
0804807a <dennis_like.palindrome_loop>:
 804807a:       58                      pop    eax      ; read from the bottom
 804807b:       83 ee 04                sub    esi,0x4
 804807e:       32 06                   xor    al,BYTE PTR [esi]
 8048080:       75 04                   jne    8048086 <dennis_like.non_palindrome>
 8048082:       39 e6                   cmp    esi,esp             ; until the pointers meet or cross in the middle
 8048084:       77 f4                   ja     804807a  <dennis_like.palindrome_loop>

08048086 <dennis_like.non_palindrome>:
 ; jump or fall-through to here with al holding an inverted boolean
 8048086:       40                      inc    eax
 8048087:       c9                      leave  
 8048088:       c3                      ret    
;; 0x89 - 0x60 = 41 bytes
```

This is probably also one of the fastest answers, since none of the golfing really hurts too badly, at least for strings under a few thousand characters where the 4x memory usage doesn't cause a lot of cache-misses.  (It might also lose to answers that take an early-out for non-Dennis-like strings before looping over all the characters.)  `salc` is slower than `setcc` on many CPUs (e.g. 3 uops vs. 1 on Skylake), but a bitmap check with `bt/salc` is still faster than a string-search or regex-match.  And there's no startup overhead, so it's extremely cheap for short strings.

Doing it in one pass on the fly would mean repeating the classification code for the up and down directions.  That would be faster but larger code-size.  (Of course if you want fast, you can do 16 or 32 chars at a time with SSE2 or AVX2, still using the compare trick by range-shifting to the bottom of the signed range).

---

**Test program (for ia32 or x32 Linux)** to call this function with a cmdline arg, and exit with status = return value.  `strlen` implementation from [int80h.org](http://www.int80h.org/strlen/).

```asm
; build with the same %define macros as the source below (so this uses 32-bit regs in 32-bit mode)
global _start
_start:
    ;%define PTRSIZE 4   ; true for x32 and 32-bit mode.

    mov  esi, [rsp+4 + 4*1]  ; esi = argv[1]
    ;mov  rsi, [rsp+8 + 8*1]  ; rsi = argv[1]   ; For regular x86-64 (not x32)

%if IMPLICIT_LENGTH == 0
        ; strlen(esi)
         mov     rdi, rsi
         mov     rcx, -1
        xor     eax, eax
        repne scasb    ; rcx = -strlen - 2
        not     rcx
        dec     rcx
%endif

    mov  eax, 0xFFFFAEBB   ; make sure the function works with garbage in EAX
    call dennis_like

    ;; use the 32-bit ABI _exit syscall, even in x32 code for simplicity
    mov ebx, eax
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80           ; _exit( dennis_like(argv[1]) )

    ;; movzx edi, al   ; actually mov edi,eax is fine here, too
    ;; mov eax,231     ; 64-bit ABI exit_group( same thing )
    ;; syscall
```

---

A 64-bit version of this function could use `sbb eax,eax`, which is only 2 bytes instead of 3 for `setc al`.  It would also need an extra byte for `dec` or `not` at the end (because only 32-bit has 1-byte inc/dec r32).  Using the x32 ABI (32-bit pointers in long mode), we can still avoid REX prefixes even though we copy and compare pointers.

`setc [rdi]` can write directly to memory, but reserving ECX bytes of stack space costs more code-size than that saves.  (And we need to move through the output array.  `[rdi+rcx]` takes one extra byte for the addressing mode, but really we need a counter that doesn't update for filtered characters so it's going to be worse than that.)

---

**This is the YASM/NASM source with `%if` conditionals.  It can be built with `-felf32` (32-bit code) or `-felfx32` (64-bit code with the x32 ABI), and with implicit or explicit length**.  I've tested all 4 versions.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36901649/224132) for a script to build a static binary from NASM/YASM source.

To test the 64-bit version on a machine without support for the x32 ABI, you can change the pointer regs to 64-bit.  (Then simply subtract the number of REX.W=1 prefixes (0x48 bytes) from the count.  In this case, 4 instructions need REX prefixes to operate on 64-bit regs).  Or simply call it with the `rsp` and the input pointer in the low 4G of address space.

```asm
%define IMPLICIT_LENGTH 0

; This source can be built as x32, or as plain old 32-bit mode
; x32 needs to push 64-bit regs, and using them in addressing modes avoids address-size prefixes
; 32-bit code needs to use the 32-bit names everywhere

;%if __BITS__ != 32   ; NASM-only
%ifidn __OUTPUT_FORMAT__, elfx32
%define CPUMODE 64
%define STACKWIDTH 8    ; push / pop 8 bytes
%else
%define CPUMODE 32
%define STACKWIDTH 4    ; push / pop 4 bytes
%define rax eax
%define rcx ecx
%define rsi esi
%define rdi edi
%define rbp ebp
%define rsp esp
%endif

    ; A regular x86-64 version needs 4 REX prefixes to handle 64-bit pointers
    ; I haven't cluttered the source with that, but I guess stuff like %define ebp rbp  would do the trick.


    ;; Calling convention similar to SysV x32, or to MS vectorcall, but with different arg regs
    ;; _Bool dennis_like_implicit(const char *esi)
    ;; _Bool dennis_like_explicit(size_t ecx, const char *esi)
global dennis_like
dennis_like:
    ; We want to restore esp later, so make a stack frame for LEAVE
    push  rbp
    mov   ebp, esp   ; enter 0,0 is 4 bytes.  Only saves bytes if we had a fixed-size allocation to do.

    ;         ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
    mov  edx, 11111011111011111011101110b   ; consonant/vowel bitmap for use with bt

;;; assume that len >= 1
%if IMPLICIT_LENGTH
    lodsb   ; pipelining the loop is 1B shorter than  jmp .non_alpha
.filter_loop:
%else
.filter_loop:
    lodsb
%endif

    and   al, 0x7F ^ 0x20  ; force ASCII to uppercase.
    sub   al, 'A'          ; range-shift to 'A' = 0
    cmp   al, 'Z'-'A'      ; if al was less than 'A', it will be a large unsigned number
    ja  .non_alpha
    ;; AL = position in alphabet (0-25)

    bt    edx, eax              ; 3B
%if CPUMODE == 32
    salc                        ; 1B   only sets AL = 0 or 0xFF.  Not available in 64-bit mode
%else
    sbb   eax, eax              ; 2B   eax = 0 or -1, according to CF.
%endif
    push  rax

.non_alpha:
%if IMPLICIT_LENGTH
    lodsb
    test   al,al
    jnz .filter_loop
%else
    loop .filter_loop
%endif
    ; al = potentially garbage if the last char was non-alpha
    ; esp = bottom of bool array

    mov   esi, ebp  ; ebp = one-past-the-top of the bool array
.palindrome_loop:
    pop   rax

    sub   esi, STACKWIDTH
    xor   al, [rsi]   ; al = (arr[up] != arr[--down]).  8-bit operand-size so flags are set from the non-garbage
    jnz .non_palindrome

    cmp   esi, esp
    ja .palindrome_loop

.non_palindrome:  ; we jump here with al=1 if we found a difference, or drop out of the loop with al=0 for no diff
    inc   eax     ;; AL transforms 0 -> 1  or  0xFF -> 0.
    leave
    ret           ; return value in AL.  high bytes of EAX are allowed to contain garbage.
```

I looked at messing around with DF (the direction flag that controls `lodsd` / `scasd` and so on), but it just didn't seem to be a win.  The usual ABIs require that DF is cleared on function entry and exit.  Assuming cleared on entry but leaving it set on exit would be cheating, IMO.  It would be nice to use LODSD / SCASD to avoid the 3-byte `sub esi, 4`, especially in the case where there's no high-garbage.

---

#### Alternate bitmap strategy (for x86-64 implicit-length strings)

It turns out this doesn't save any bytes, because `bt r32,r32` still works with high garbage in the bit-index.  It's just not documented the way `shr` is.

Instead of `bt / sbb` to get the bit into / out of CF, use a shift / mask to isolate the bit we want from the bitmap.

```asm
%if IMPLICIT_LENGTH && CPUMODE == 64
    ; incompatible with LOOP for explicit-length, both need ECX.  In that case, bt/sbb is best
    xchg  eax, ecx
    mov   eax, 11111011111011111011101110b   ; not hoisted out of the loop
    shr   eax, cl
    and   al, 1
%else
    bt    edx, eax
    sbb   eax, eax
%endif
    push  rax
```

Since this produces 0/1 in AL at the end (instead of 0/0xFF), we can do the necessary inversion of the return value at the end of the function with `xor al, 1` (2B) instead of `dec eax` (also 2B in x86-64) to still produce a proper [`bool` / `_Bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Boolean_type) return value.

This used to save 1B for x86-64 with implicit-length strings, by avoiding the need to zero the high bytes of EAX.  (I had been using `and  eax, 0x7F ^ 0x20` to force to upper-case and zero the rest of eax with a 3-byte `and r32,imm8`.  But now I'm using the 2-byte immediate-with-AL encoding that most 8086 instructions have, like I was already doing for the `sub` and `cmp`.)

It loses to `bt`/`salc` in 32-bit mode, and explicit-length strings need ECX for the count so this doesn't work there either.

But then I realized that I was wrong: `bt edx, eax` still works with high garbage in eax.  It masks the shift count [the same way `shr r32, cl` does](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html) (looking only at the low 5 bits of cl).  This is different from `bt [mem], reg`, which can access outside the memory referenced by the addressing-mode/size, treating it as a bitstring.  (Crazy CISC...)

Intel's insn set ref [manual entry for `bt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bt) does document the masking in the description section:  *If the bit base operand specifies a register, the instruction takes the modulo 16, 32, or 64 of the bit offset operand (modulo size depends on the mode and register size).*  Apparently I missed it when writing this answer originally; I checked a Jan 2015 version of the PDF and it was already there.

A neat trick here is using `xchg eax,ecx` (1 byte) to get the count into CL.  Unfortunately, BMI2 `shrx  eax, edx, eax` is 5 bytes, vs. only 2 bytes for `shr eax, cl`.  Using `bextr` needs a 2-byte `mov ah,1` (for the number of bits to extract), so it's again 5 + 2 bytes like SHRX + AND.

---

The source code has gotten pretty messy after adding `%if` conditionals.  **Here's disassembly of x32 implicit-length strings** (using the alternate strategy for the bitmap, so it's still 46 bytes).

The main difference from the explicit-length version is in the first loop.  Notice how there's a `lods` before it, and at the bottom, instead of just one at the top of the loop.

```asm
    ; 64-bit implicit-length version using the alternate bitmap strategy
    00400060 <dennis_like>:
      400060:       55                      push   rbp
      400061:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
      400063:       ac                      lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[rsi]
    
    00400064 <dennis_like.filter_loop>:
      400064:       24 5f                   and    al,0x5f
      400066:       2c 41                   sub    al,0x41
      400068:       3c 19                   cmp    al,0x19
      40006a:       77 0b                   ja     400077 <dennis_like.non_alpha>
      40006c:       91                      xchg   ecx,eax
      40006d:       b8 ee be ef 03          mov    eax,0x3efbeee  ; inside the loop since SHR destroys it
      400072:       d3 e8                   shr    eax,cl
      400074:       24 01                   and    al,0x1
      400076:       50                      push   rax
    00400077 <dennis_like.non_alpha>:
      400077:       ac                      lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[rsi]
      400078:       84 c0                   test   al,al
      40007a:       75 e8                   jne    400064 <dennis_like.filter_loop>

      40007c:       89 ee                   mov    esi,ebp
    0040007e <dennis_like.palindrome_loop>:
      40007e:       58                      pop    rax
      40007f:       83 ee 08                sub    esi,0x8
      400082:       32 06                   xor    al,BYTE PTR [rsi]
      400084:       75 04                   jne    40008a <dennis_like.non_palindrome>
      400086:       39 e6                   cmp    esi,esp
      400088:       77 f4                   ja     40007e <dennis_like.palindrome_loop>
    
    0040008a <dennis_like.non_palindrome>:
      40008a:       ff c8                   dec    eax  ; invert the 0 / non-zero status of AL.  xor al,1 works too, and produces a proper bool.
      40008c:       c9                      leave  
      40008d:       c3                      ret    

   0x8e - 0x60 = 0x2e = 46 bytes
```

Update: instead of using 32-bit pointers, I could have used `push rsp` / `pop rbp` to copy a 64-bit register in 2 bytes of code.  ([Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/190636#190636)).  But `sub rsi,0x8` and `cmp    rsi,rsp` would need REX prefixes which I'm avoiding here by using 32-bit pointers.  Perhaps comparing the low 32 could work if the stack doesn't cross a 4GiB boundary, so just the `sub`.

I wonder if `pop rdx` / `std` / `lodsq` / `cld` / `xor al, dl` could work?  No, that's 7 bytes, break-even with just using `sub rsi, 8` in the loop body.

Comment: Some tricks I used in [Vowels up, consonants down](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201568) probably apply here, but I haven't yet re-golfed this one.  Ideally we could have the interesting bit from the bitmap shifted to bit 7 so we could XOR / JS or JNS without needing `and al, 1` anywhere, but that would require the top of the bitmap to extend past 32 bits.

Answer (score 8):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <del>49 47</del> 45 bytes

```
\P{L}

i`[aeiou]
1
\D
2
+`^(.)(.*)\1$
$2
^.?$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxZd8FAGIDh@@9XpAQJ7ZBo6WYJsYutOxEJBmOZYVBa1b8ePU5v3ufu5XhDqOP6pILtmo1D9QhA7I6DCdt2QQFTBxVCtiUhWUJB2VREEFWwUEp0XR1TStZgOPxv8Y@Qo0PMQZvj/TmChkBnjM8o64OBxwyEC49X9PkDkhwMXV6hcERRo9c3sfjt3f3DYyKZSmuZrJ7LF4qlcqVq1OqNZuvp@eX17f2j3TG7Vs92@oMhHo0nZDqbLyhbrvh6s/3c7b@@Dz/H3xM)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Neil.

Saved another 2 bytes thanks to Martin.

Removes non-letters then replaces vowels with 1 and consonants with 2, to get consistent values. Then repeatedly removes the first and last character if they are the same. Once they aren't, the word was symmetric if there are one or zero characters remaining.

Comment: Does `\D` `2` work to save you a couple of bytes over ``T`lL`2``?

Comment: @Neil Yes it seems to, nice catch!

Comment: Well done. I was trying to do this :(

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 82 Bytes

```php
<?=strrev($s=preg_replace(["#[^a-z]#i","#[aeiou]#i","#\pL#"],["",0,1],$argn))==$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVfJNLCrJzFNwzUtJLVKy5rK3@29jb1tcUlSUWqahUmxbUJSaHl@UWpCTmJyqEa2kHB2XqFsVq5yppANkJ6Zm5pdCOTEFPspKsTrRSko6BjqGsTpg4zU1bW1Viq3//wcA)

Comment: You could prepend typecasting `(bool)` and remove the `$s=` and the `==$s` check to save 1 byte.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you could replace the `(bool)` with just `0||` to say _false, or …_ instead, saving 3 additional bytes.

Comment: Hm. Couldn't you use `\w` for _word_ characters instead of the `a-z`?

Comment: @kaiser `\w` contains digits underscore and letters . This will not work and `[^/p{L}]` is longer as `[^a-z]` plus i. I compare the reverse string with the string so `$s` is needed to create the boolean

Comment: That is true. Still the others should work. "Should" … they do.

Comment: @kaiser If really neccessary somewhere then typecast to bool is best done by `!!`.

Answer (score 7):

## MATL, 14 bytes

```
t3Y2m)13Y2mtP=
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=t3Y2m%2913Y2mtP%3D&inputs=%27Martin+Ender%27&version=20.0.0).

[Here](https://matl.io/?code=%60i%0A++++t3Y2m%2913Y2mtP%3D%0A%3F%27TRUE%27D%7D%27FALSE%27D%5DT&inputs=%27Dennis%27%0A%27Martin%27%0A%27Martin+Ender%27%0A%27Alex%27%0A%27Alex+A.%27%0A%27Doorknob%27%0A%27Mego%27&version=20.0.0) is a slightly modified version to check all test cases.

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab the input as a string
        %     STACK: {'Martin Ender'}
t       % Duplicate the input
        %     STACK: {'Martin Ender', 'Martin Ender'}
3Y2     % Push the string 'ABC...XYZabc...xyz'
        %     STACK: {'Martin Ender', 'Martin Ender', 'ABC...XYZabc...xyz'}
m       % Find which characters of the input are letters using this string
        %     STACK: {'Martin Ender', [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1]}
)       % Use this boolean array to select only the letters
        %     STACK: {'MartinEnder'}
13Y2    % Push the string literal 'aeiouAEIOU' to the stack
        %     STACK: {'MartinEnder', 'aeiouAEIOU'}
m       % Check for membership of each letter of the input in this string.
        %     STACK: {[0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0]}
tP      % Create a reversed copy
        %     STACK: {[0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0], [0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0]}
=       % Perform an element-wise comparison yielding a truthy (all 1's) or 
        % falsey (any 0's) result
        %     STACK: {[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]}
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: You demonstrate it with "Martin Ender" instead of "Dennis"? i have to look at the challenge title again.

Comment: Presumably Suever wanted a demonstration that had some amount of filtering at the first step.

Comment: Then he should use "Alex A." instead, it has a period too.

Comment: I'm confused what the issue is. I chose Martin Ender because it would actually be true if you remove spaces and false otherwise. I also included a link to all test cases

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, <strike>84</strike> <strike>75</strike> <strike>74</strike> 69 bytes

-10 thanks to @nimi
-5 thanks to @Zgarb

```
f x=(==)<*>reverse$[elem c"aeiouAEIOU"|c<-x,'@'<c,c<'{','`'<c||c<'[']
```

The list comprehension replaces each letter with a boolean and removes all other characters. The first part checks whether or not the resulting list is a palindrome.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mUGGrYWuraaNlV5RallpUnKoSnZqTmquQrJSYmplf6ujq6R@qVJNso1uho@6gbpOsk2yjXq2uo54AZNcAxdWj1WO5uHITM/MUbBVS8rkUFAqKMvNKFDTSFJQyUnNy8pU0UcRS8tPRRBJNTCz0rPXTdQ0sLcxLUtFkDU3QBAwsE4Em/P8PAA)

Comment: Two tips: 1) A list comprehension is often shorten than `filter` followed by `map` even if you have to switch to non-poitfree. 2) The `<$>id` is superfluous. `f x=(==)<*>reverse$[elem c"aeiouAEIOU"|c<-x,c`elem`['A'..'Z']++['a'..'z']]`.

Comment: You can drop the space between `c` and `"` for one more byte.

Comment: I think ``c`elem`['A'..'Z']++['a'..'z']`` can be shortened to ``'@'<c,c<'{','`'<c||c<'['``

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>18</s> 15 bytes

```
_I/L"aeiou"@Gr0
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_I%2FL%22aeiou%22%40Gr0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Dennis%22%0A%22Martin%22%0A%22Martin+Ender%22%0A%22Alex%22%0A%22Alex+A.%22%0A%22Doorknob%22%0A%22Mego%22&debug=0)

-2 thanks to [KarlKastor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56557/karlkastor), and subsequently -1.

Comment: 16 bytes: `_I/L"aeiou"@Grz0` (using the invariance operator I)

Comment: @KarlKastor I knew there had to be some operator like that...thanks. (BTW I can now remove the `z` too, I will assume quoted input)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
ḷ{∈Ṿg|∈Ḅg}ˢ.↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9wx/bqRx0dD3fuS68B0Tta0mtPL9J71Dbl/38lx5zUCgVHPaX/AA)

#### Explanation

```
ḷ                Lowercase the input
 {       }ˢ.     Select each char if:
  ∈Ṿg              it's a vowel, and replace it with ["aeiou"]            
     |             Or
      ∈Ḅg          it's a consonant, and replace it with ["bcdfghjklkmnpqrstvwxyz"]
           .↔    The resulting list is a palindrome
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>72</s> 69 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to Neil*

Returns a boolean.

```js
s=>(a=s.match(/[a-z]/gi).map(c=>!/[aeiou]/i.exec(c)))+''==a.reverse()
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>(a=s.match(/[a-z]/gi).map(c=>!/[aeiou]/i.exec(c)))+''==a.reverse()

console.log(f("Dennis"))        // -> truthy
console.log(f("Martin"))        // -> truthy
console.log(f("Martin Ender"))  // -> truthy
console.log(f("Alex"))          // -> falsy
console.log(f("Alex A."))       // -> truthy
console.log(f("Doorknob"))      // -> falsy
console.log(f("Mego"))          // -> falsy
```

Comment: Save a couple of bytes by replacing the 2 empty strings with `2`.

Comment: Do you even need the `+''` at the end? That would save 3 bytes instead.

Comment: I like @Neil's idea better!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>72</s> 71 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @ovs

```python
def f(s):s=[c in'AEIOU'for c in s.upper()if'@'<c<'['];return s==s[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@5@SmqaQplGsaVVsG52skJmn7ujq6R@qnpZfpADiKhTrlRYUpBZpaGamqTuo2yTbqEerx1oXpZaUFgElbW2Lo62sdA1j//8HAA)

Comment: `def f(s):s=[c in'AEIOU'for c in s.upper()if'@'<c<'['];return s==s[::-1]` for 71 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 28 bytes

```
/uia.QN."-e@
\1"lyuy.Ra$i1/o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1@/NDNRL9BPT0k31YErxlApp7K0Ui8oUSXTUD///3@X1Ly8zGIA)

Outputs `1` as truthy and nothing as falsy.

#### Explanation

Every command in this program executes in ordinal mode, but with a slight twist in the template that allows me to save a byte.  If a newline is an acceptable truthy value, I can save one more byte by the same method.

Linearized, the program is as follows:

```
1il.uN."aei ou"ayQy.R-$@1o1@

1                           % Append "1" to top of stack
                            % STACK: ["1"]
 i                          % Push input to stack
                            % STACK: ["1", "Dennis"]
  l                         % Convert to lowercase
                            % STACK: ["1", "dennis"]
   .                        % Duplicate
                            % STACK: ["1", "dennis", "dennis"]
    u                       % Convert to uppercase
                            % STACK: ["1", "dennis", "DENNIS"]
     N                      % Take multiset difference; this removes all non-alphabetic characters
                            % STACK: ["1", "dennis"]
      .                     % Duplicate
                            % STACK: ["1", "dennis", "dennis"]
       "aei ou"             % Push "aei ou"
                            % STACK: ["1", "dennis", "dennis", "aei ou"]
              a             % Push newline
                            % STACK: ["1", "dennis", "dennis", "aeiou", "\n"]
               y            % Transliterate: replace all vowels with newlines
                            % STACK: ["1", "dennis", "d\nnn\ns"]
                Q           % Reverse stack
                            % STACK: ["d\nnn\ns", "dennis", "1"]
                 y          % Transliterate: replace remaining characters with "1"
                            % STACK: ["1\n11\n1"]
                  .         % Duplicate
                            % STACK: ["1\n11\n1", "1\n11\n1"]
                   R        % Reverse top of stack
                            % STACK: ["1\n11\n1", "1\n11\n1"]
                    -       % Remove occurrences: for same-length strings, result is "" iff strings are equal.
                            % STACK: [""]
                     $      % Pop stack, and skip next command if ""
                      @     % Terminate (skipped if c/v pattern is palindromic)
                       1o   % Output "1"
                         1  % Push "1" (useless)
                          @ % Terminate
```

Answer (score 3):

## Braingolf,  <s>4</s>  3 bytes

```
&JP
```

*-1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer*

Turns out I had `P` all along, even before this challenge.

<s>`J` however, despite being created before this challenge, wasn't pushed to github before the challenge, thus is still non-competing.</s>

#### Explanation:

```
&JP  Implicit input, push ASCII value of each char in string to stack
&J   Replace each item in stack with 1 if vowel, otherwise 0
  P  Pop entire stack, push 1 if stack is palindromic, 0 otherwise
     Implicit output of last item on stack
```

Comment: Why do you need `n`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer because I'm a certified moron

Comment: Hmm, you forgot to remove it from the explanation.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I was gunna write "Erick" then strike out the c, but it just looks like "Eriek"

Comment: Won't this fail for the likes of `Alex A.`?

Comment: @Shaggy no, because after `J`, the stack would be `101001`, assuming you exclude the dot, if you include it there'd be an extra `0` at the end. Either way the result would be `0` for false, as expected because `Alex A.` is not a Dennis name

Comment: You might want to double check the spec ;) Non-letter characters should be ignored completely, making `Alex A.` truthy.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>92</s> <s>87</s> <s>74</s> <s>72</s> <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```python
l=[c in'aeouiAEOUI'for c in input()if c.isalpha()]
print(l==l[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8c2OlkhM089MTW/NNPR1T/UUz0tv0gBJAZEBaUlGpqZaQrJepnFiTkFGYkamrFcBUWZeSUaOba2OdFWVrqGsZr//7uk5uVlFgMA)

Comment: You can remove the space before the `for c in s`

Comment: And you can remove the `s` variable by replacing `s` on the second line to `input().lower()`

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 26 bytes

```
lel_'{,97>--"aeiou"fe=_W%=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Pyc1J169WsfS3E5XVykxNTO/VCkt1TY@XNX2/3/HnNQKBUc9AA)

-1 thanks to [Esolanging Fruit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61384/esolanging-fruit).

Comment: You can replace `26,'af+` with `'{,97>` to save a byte.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit such an old answer...

Comment: A byte saved half a year ago is no different than a byte saved now. It's not like there's byte inflation or anything :P

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I was referring to my always developing experience with golfing...of course you got a credit as usual, don't worry!

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 113 bytes

```
PalindromeQ@StringCases[StringReplace[#,{Characters["aeiouAEIOU"]->"1",CharacterRange["A","z"]->"0"}],{"0","1"}]&
```

Comment: You can get rid of quite a few bytes: `PalindromeQ@StringReplace[#,{Characters@"aeiouAEIOU"->"1",LetterCharacter->"0",_->""}]&`

Answer (score 2):

## q/kdb+, <s>42</s> 38 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x~|:[x]}{inter[x;.Q.a]in"aeiou"}lower
```

**Example:**

```
q){x~|:[x]}{inter[x;.Q.a]in"aeiou"}lower"Dennis"
1b
q){x~|:[x]}{inter[x;.Q.a]in"aeiou"}lower"Adam"
0b
q){x~|:[x]}{inter[x;.Q.a]in"aeiou"}lower"Alex A."
1b
```

**Explanation:**

```
lower        // converts argument on the right to lowercase
.Q.a         // lowercase alphabet "abc..xyz"
inter[x;y]   // intersection of x and y (thus only return a-z)
x in "aeiou" // returns boolean list whether x is a vowel; "dennis" = 010010b
|:           // k shorthand for 'reverse'
```

**Edits:**

- -4 bytes; switching out `reverse` for k equivalent `|:`

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 42 bytes

```
{123,65>.26>6<-?)},{"AEIOUaeiou"?)!}%.-1%=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v9rQyFjHzNROz8jMzsxG116zVqdaydHV0z80MTUzv1TJXlOxVlVP11DV9v9/x5zUCgVHPQA)

The hard part is generating both the uppercase and lowercase alphabet in one string, which we'll use in a filter function to filter the letters out of the input. Luckily, since strings in GolfScript are just codepoint arrays with a special property, so we can just generate the codepoints in an efficient way. Here's how we generate them:

First, we generate range [0..122], 122 being the codepoint for `z`. Then, we take the elements from the element at index 65 onwards. 65 is the codepoint for `A`. Right now, we have [65..122]. All fine, except we have some unwanted codepoints ([91..96]) in there. So, we first make a duplicate of that range. Then, we take the elements from index 26 onwards, and we have [91..122]. After that, we get the elements up to and including index 5. Now we have [91..96]. Finally, we remove those elements from our [65..122], leaving us wil [65..90, 97..122]. Those are the codepoints we want.

Now that we made the upper/lower alphabet codepoint list, we continue our filtering function. The function gets mapped to each character on the input string, which, as I initially said, gets parsed as its codepoint instead. So now we essentially have `[codepoint, [65..90, 97..122]]`. To find out if char `codepoint` is a letter, we simply take its index in the list we made. If it isn't there, we'll get `-1` as the index instead.

Right now, we get a falsey value only if `codepoint == 65`, i.e. the first index of our list, since only then would the index be 0. But a single increment will fix this problem, and, now, if `codepoint` is in our list, we'll get its index + 1, which is always a positive number, thus always truthy, while if it's not there we'll get -1 + 1 = 0, i.e. falsey.

We finally apply the function I described to every char of the input, and we only take the chars for which the function returned a truthy result.

Next up we have to determine if each char is a vowel or consonant. Since the vowels are fewer than the consonants, creating a string of vowels so that we check for that condition is shorter than creating a string of consonants, so we check if each char is a vowel. But, to check if the boolean list is palindromic, we need booleans, which we don't get just by taking the index + 1, since that can result in any number of [1..10] if the char is a vowel. And, as most golfing languages, this one, doesn't have a `bool` function either. So, we simply use `not not x`, since `not` always returns a boolean. But wait; do we really need to have specific booleans? Since `not` always returns a boolean, why don't we just remove the second `not`, and actually check if each char is a consonant? Yeah, that's exactly what we'll do!

After the check, which returns a list of booleans, we check if this boolean list we got is a palindrome, which is what this challenge asks us to do. Well, what is the definition of a palindrome? Yes, a palindrome is a list or string which is equal to its reverse. So, how do we check? Simple, we duplicate it, take its reverse, and check against the original list. The result we get is, *finally*, what our code should return.

Comment: Giant explanation for a 42-byte program. Now I guess that it's pretty much self-explanatory...

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 87 bytes

Regex free PHP version. Added a "vowel" since stripos can return 0 which is false in PHP.

Flaw fixed by Jörg.

```php
for(;a&$c=$argn[$p++];)!ctype_alpha($c)?:$s.=stripos(_aeiou,$c)?0:1;echo$s==strrev($s);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#HclRCoMwDADQ/91CCdLiGO7XrHgCTyBDQqlrYdiQdANP3@F@33tMHPkCJK/dtTNJSXuLdctikDrw7j8LcN8/0Ta@HBxWenMkA95OI@jNaZHEWc1KIeXP9fRhvGPwMYO6syV8DajFWn8)

Comment: Same Byte count. `for(;a&$c=$argn[$p++];)ctype_alpha($c)?$s.=stripos(_aeiou,$c)?0:1:0;echo$s==strrev($s);` but it get the right result for strings that contains zero

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
⌠╟%╜«¥│▒g♦°pC₧╤WsV
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%5E%22%5B%5EA-Z%5D%22zR%7BVVI0%3CFLcr%3D&i=Dennis%0AMartin%0AMartin+Ender%0AAlex%0AAlex+A.%0ADoorknob%0AMego&m=2)

### Explanation

```
^"[^A-Z]"zR{VVI0<FLcr=
^                      capitalize input
 "[^A-Z]"zR            remove all non alphabet characters
           {     F     loop over modified string
            VV         "AEIOU"
              I        Index of character (-1 if not present)
               0<      less than 0
                       push the result to stack
                  L    wrap the stack in an array
                   c   duplicate it
                    r  reverse it
                     = are they equal?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 24 bytes

Saved bytes thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319)

```apl
≡∘⌽⍨'AEIOU'∊⍨⎕a∩⍨819⌶⍨∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/FR24RHnQsfdcx41LP3Ue8KdUdXT/9Q9UcdXUDOo76piY86VgJZFoaWj3q2gYQ6ZhgCdR1aoe6SmpeXWayuoO6bWFSSmQdnKLjmpaQWAbmOOakVUErBUQ/IcsnPL8rOy08CKU1Nz1cHAA)

`819⌶⍨∘1` uppercase argument

`⎕a∩⍨` intersection with uppercase alphabet

`'AEIOU'∊⍨` belongs-to-`'AEIOU'`? resulting in a boolean vector

`≡∘⌽⍨` reversed equivalent to self?

Comment: Save a byte with `819⌶⍨∘1`

Comment: And two with `(⊢≡⌽)`

Comment: … but I can solve this in 24. Want any hints?

Comment: @Adám That `⌶` trick is nice, thanks, got 24 too after over two years

Comment: In a few of months, you can save another 2 bytes with `819⌶` → `⎕C`, or you can go Extended today, and do `819⌶⍨∘1` → `⌈`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 83 bytes

```
def f(x):k=map(lambda y:y.lower()in"aeiou",filter(str.isalpha,x));return k==k[::-1]
```

Defines a function that either gives `True` or `False`

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by using `"aeiouAEIOU".__contains__` instead of `lambda y:y.lower()in"aeiou"`.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 79 bytes

First-timer! (I did what I could)

```
r{:X"AEIOUaeiou"#W>{X"BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"#W={'0}&}'1?~}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19UbRWh5Ojq6R@amJqZX6qkHG5XHaHk5Ozi5u7h5e3j6xcQGBQcEhYeERmVlJKWnpGVnZObV1BYVFxSVl5RWQVUb1utblCrVqtuaF9Xq/r/v0tqXl5mMQA)

Comment: Welcome to PP&CG!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, <s>19</s> 11 bytes

```
k\L mè\v ê¬
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=a1xMIG3oXHYg6qw=&input=IkRlbm5pcyI=)

---

### Explanation

```
        :Implicit input of string U.
 k\L    :Remove all non-letter characters from U.
 m      :Map over resulting string, replacing each character ...
 è\v    :with the count of the number of vowels in each single character substring.
 ê¬     :Is the above a palindrome?
        :Implicit output of boolean result.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 57 bytes

```
->s{x=s.scan(/\p{L}/).map{|c|c=~/[aeiou]/i};x==x.reverse}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7P9r2tXXF1hW6xXnJyYp6EfU1DtU6uvqZebWFBdk1yTbFunH52YmplfGqufWWtdYWtboVeUWpZaVJxa@79AIS1aySU1Ly@zWCmWC8zzTSwqycxD5Sm45qWkFsHEHHNSK5DZCo56MK5Lfn5Rdl5@Elx7anq@Uux/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 82 bytes

```bash
i=${1//[^a-zA-Z]};a=aeouiAEOUI;b=${i//[$a]/0};c=${b//[!0$a]/1};[ $c = `rev<<<$c` ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#LY27DoJAEEV7v@JKNnYIti7EkEBhQaxsJBgWGHWj2UnWR3zx7bgSmjv3nElmDmyhoQ1SMkZfkSt7c@SNMzMtWQ/JhZ7whkzmHlJmezZcI6cjQ6LlCTUnhm8g9FL2OhYfHQTFXvnvxN@VnVSxIr7rJNts17Ie10KVQdjJxmHtcBr@xaKTBUSDGJWlRxRFoqlQ9s6t3H1CiHI2G76Z7xdDeclJy4b6Hw)

Recives name as parameter, removes non-leters, replaces vowels with 0, non-vowels nor 0 with 1 and compares with same reversed.

Could golf some more if can get to work [double or triple substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68042/double-and-triple-substitution-in-bash-and-zsh)

Exit status is 0 for true and 1 for no.

Comment: In recent bash versions, `i=${i^^*};` converts `i` to uppercase.  But I think it only saves you an `a-z` and an `aeiou`, which is less than the 10B it costs.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 42 bytes

```
s!(.)\PL*!1+aeiou=~lc$1!ge;$_=$_==reverse
```

Run with `perl -p`.

Answer (score 1):

## 64-bit machine code, 89 bytes.

A function of following signature: `eax = f(char * edi)`

```
48 89 F8 48 89 FE 41 B8 22 82 20 00 8A 0E 84 C9
74 23 89 CA 83 E2 DF 0F BE D2 83 EA 41 83 FA 19
77 0E 44 89 C2 48 FF C0 D3 FA 83 E2 01 88 50 FF
48 FF C6 EB D7 C6 00 02 48 FF C7 48 FF C8 8A 17
40 8A 30 40 38 77 FF 75 05 80 FA 02 75 EA 31 C0
80 FA 02 0F 94 C0 C3
```

Assembled using NASM, from such assembly code:

```
; edi => input string.
; eax <= 1 or 0.

; notes:
; the string needs to be null terminated and located in a
; writable memory location, as it will be mutated.

BITS 64

DENNIS: MOV RAX, RDI
        MOV RSI, RDI
        MOV R8D, 0x208222
.CTOR:  MOV CL, BYTE [RSI]
        TEST CL, CL
        JE .SP
        MOV EDX, ECX
        AND EDX, -33
        MOVSX EDX, DL
        SUB EDX, 65
        CMP EDX, 25
        JA .LI
        MOV EDX, R8D
        INC RAX
        SAR EDX, CL
        AND EDX, 1
        MOV BYTE [RAX-1], DL
.LI:    INC RSI
        JMP .CTOR
.SP:    MOV BYTE [RAX], 2
.EQL:   INC RDI
        DEC RAX
        MOV DL, BYTE [RDI]
        MOV SIL, BYTE [RAX]
        CMP BYTE [RDI-1], SIL
        JNE .EQE
        CMP DL, 2
        JNE .EQL
.EQE:   XOR EAX, EAX
        CMP DL, 2
        SETE AL
        RET
```

Not a killer, not even close, but it has a couple of advantages over the 41-byte answer:

- Requires no memory (not even stack).
- Doesn't require to check the length of a string - it uses null-termination instead.
- Doesn't use undocumented CPU instructions.

Just my $0.02 :).

Comment: My answer includes a 46-byte x86-64 version using implicit-length (null-terminated) strings, vs. the smaller C++ `std::string` style explicit-length string version.  It uses 32-bit pointers in 64-bit mode (x32 ABI), but I had a look and I think it 64-bit pointers could be done with only 1 extra byte.  My 64-bit versions don't use any undocumented instructions or behaviour (at the time I thought `bt`'s masking of the count was undocumented, but I just missed it in the manual!)  `salc` was removed in 64-bit mode.

Comment: So the interesting thing about your answer is not using any stack space. But using the input string for scratch space is using memory.  Many callers would need to copy the string before calling this function, which is even worse than just needing to find its length if they didn't already have that value.  Anyway, a different approach is fine and interesting; I don't mean to rain on your parade. :P

Comment: `MOVSX EDX, DL` could be avoided if you did `MOVSX EDX, CL` earlier, before the `AND EDX, -33`.  Or loaded ECX originally with `movsx ecx, byte [rsi]`.  `-33` is all-ones outside the low 8 bits, so doing it before or after sign-extension is equivalent.  I'm not sure you even need to sign-extend to 32-bit at all, though; the `sub`/`cmp`/`ja` trick to check for alphabetic ASCII works in 8-bit, after setting or clearing the lower-case bit like you're doing with `and edx, ~32`.  You can probably use `lea` to copy-and-subtract, and mask `cl` instead of `dl` (the shift count gets masked mod 32)

Comment: Also, you can copy 64-bit registers in 2 bytes using `push reg` / `pop reg`. [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190636) .  Using different registers could let you use AL for more of your 8-bit operations, allowing 2-byte instructions like `cmp al, 25`.  ([Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160739)).  Having a pointer in RSI would allow `lodsb` to load into AL, and then you could copy from there into CL.  Or not if the pointer increment needs to be conditional.

Comment: `bt edx, ecx` / `setc BYTE [RAX-1]` might save space over sar/and/mov.  In the 2nd loop, CL instead of SIL would avoid a REX prefix.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>84</s> 64 bytes

```
"aeiou">0i['aL[p' +0]ps'a,Gf'z`Lfp*[p<l~sp>rlr0]p]p&sJ>lrJs<l=u;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18pMTUzv1TJziAzWj3RJ7pAXUHbILagWD1Rxz1NvSrBJ61AK7rAJqeuuMCuKKcIKBVboFbsZZdT5FVsk2Nbav3/v29iUUlmnoJrXkpqEQA)

Still not that short, but getting a stack oriented language with no concept of characters to do this seemed interesting enough to submit.  Plus it's a lot shorter than the initial version I posted in June...

1. Setup a vowel testing stack

```
    "aeiou"   - push vowels onto a stack
           >  - swtich to a clean stack
```

2. Switch to an input processing stack, prep input

```
    0   - add a "0", acts as a stopper
     i  - read input into the stack as codepoints
```

3. Check each codepoint/char on the stack, building a `0|1` list

```
    [                                      ]p - loop over the stack
     'aL[p' +0]p                              - lowercase the char
                s                             - stash the character
                 'a,Gf'z`Lfp*                 - check if in "a-z" (3.1)
                             [p<l~sp>rlr0]p   - do 0,1 vowel check (3.2)
```

3.1 Make sure the character is in `a-z`

```
'a,G          - load "a", decrement, do ">" check
    f         - pull char forward (flip top two on stack)
     'z`L     - load "z", increment, do "<" check
         fp   - pull char forward, delete it
           *  - compute "and" of two tests
```

3.2 Compare char to vowel list, generate `0` or `1` result

```
    [p         0]p  - if/then, true if char in "a-z"
      <             - switch to "vowel check" stack
       l            - load current char
        ~           - search stack, get 0,1 result
         sp         - save results, delete from stack
           >        - switch to processing stack
            rlr     - reverse stack, load result, reverse again
```

4. Compare `0|1` list against it's reverse

```
    &s             - copy the 0,1 stack to the backup cell
      J            - join the stack elements
       >lrJs       - repeat on another stack, reversed
            <l     - switch back, load 2nd joined stack
              =u;  - print 0,1 depending on equals check
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 130 bytes

```c
d(a,l)char*a,*l;{char*y=alloca(*l),*z=y;for(*l=1;*a;a++)if(isalpha(*a))*y++=!strchr("aeiou",*a|32);for(a=y-z;a--;*l*=*z++==*--y);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BTsMwEETPzVcYS0W2EyNRblg@VCpH/oDL4jiJxWJXdhAkJb9OiNNLBLeZp5nRrpGtMfNcM6iQmw6igEqguqxy0IAYDDCBvBKjHlQT4mL0vRKgoCy5a5hLgOduyQDnYihLfZP6aLrIKFgXPmgl4PvhwNcq6EGOCqRUAoUW45LWQsqBq2nuberZ9QJ@KXZZESSaLGtoPQOuil0@8xazOkfn@4bRfXok@/rF0yo/oIqpeAfnWV5YB@nJeu8SzZ0reIbYO/8PkCdf27jBR7Rffyw53m3IKYT45sPrdsq2Idtp/jENQptm@fkL)

Takes input as the string and its length, with the length passed by reference (`d(str, &len)`), and outputs by modifying `len`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 58 bytes

```arturo
$=>[=reverse<=map replace&{/\p{^L}}""=>[in?&"aeiouAEIOU"]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?3mZKiZ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 78 bytes

Golfed version. [Attempt it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVHNSgMxEMbrPsXY0wbaXLxIcYVKvbVe1JNISdPZGt1mlslsq4hPIkIv-k71aUyb-gfVQDKZ-b5vmJ_nt2BNZQ6Wq7mb1cQCG1834iptb4zzzk_1KMusCQi2MiHABQbJna8b6cK5cCS0gRrZ-CdEFRqvsozGt2gFhjEFPGZzU0H5SYfi-JNYvDZSdg5XZyNdukqQ85F2YYASv0rPTJ3b4rhl0FHT0pa8xHQht1poQItIUbp2Na5JtiisZpwjB1Qp6_veC8AES5hFVW54GrrQYzYPV6mOa9WFS-8EilghxLOuUmJ3IUYGLna5iULquNVH711otUG4QdX-hQ0Ni_P_YXDqJ8i7Gb0K7yNSmirsgqCnd-v6RHznafyHdohT-oI2SHpLYsi_t9gGvK_jrnCi4KiTBqC2E0kzMVaaaAook0JtMVdCvsX2ix9Z5IZpAR4X0AsBY_fkT5mJ8yR8ytb3KUtbWi6T_QA)

```scala
_.filter(_.isLetter).map(c=>"aeiou".contains(c.toLower)).pipe(c=>c==c.reverse)
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJNTsMwEIX3OcWQlSOFHKAiSEHtrl3xs0EIuc6kGFy7mnHaItSzBzdOA5UKm8ieb97I701YSSO7TklGUEYywwOyF9puWj@Be0/arnJwre/vd84ZlDZLErd8R@VhIbWFrwSgxgYawZOoyMZWKHsMsJUGGm08EtahyEW8iNdC8xx9OGZj39bt0HDoSiVq16Yj0Px0RIGcRhVruREKyttBVChnfXgUC1V4Nw81yuLgUVuejgXhFokx4MNgYR2kQtKKJ1ARyc/n6OclGHq02p@58SGo4yPnOgTWVyGGl07RWs1pDp5azPIztpDktf2PwczWSJc7KoP7QBpp@BKCqrismzpHH9Yt/9AucOVG1JP4bRyB@PkhcsD9Jqwd6wxurmMA2ZBIzEQq38p@P1GRDUw3IAZ2Vf6a4t/I7cDiDipmDO6dnRE5ElF46FdzSLruGw)

```scala
case class Test(input: String, output: Boolean)

object Main {
  def f(s:String): Boolean = {
    val filtered = s.filter(_.isLetter)
    val vowels = "aeiou"
    val isVowel = filtered.map(c => vowels.contains(c.toLower))
    isVowel == isVowel.reverse
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val tests = List(
      Test("Dennis", true),
      Test("Martin", true),
      Test("Martin Ender", true),
      Test("Alex", false),
      Test("Alex A.", true),
      Test("Doorknob", false),
      Test("Mego", false)
    )
    for (Test(input, expected) <- tests) {
      val actual = f(input)
      if (actual != expected) throw new AssertionError()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ỊṃḲ⁼
```

##### Explanation

```python
ỊṃḲ⁼  # Implicit input
Ị     # Remove non-alphabets
 ṃ    # For each character: 1 if vowel, 0 otherwise
  Ḳ   # Bifurcate (i.e. duplicate and reverse)
   ⁼  # Are the two lists exactly equal?
      # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot] (click to enlarge)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), 65 bytes

```python
lambda s:(l:=[c in'aeiou'for c in s.lower()if'`'<c<'{'])==l[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvBCsIwEETv@Yq9pT1YEC8S2kNBj/2CWjBtE11Md0sS0eLHR1ucwwyP4c1LvDMdjrNPFiq4JKenftQQVOZU1Q6AJLVBfkrLHlaEUDh@GZ/laOVVlkMpP7LLq8q1Su32XcJpZh8hLEGIVXJIZvOWUIQ4IikBv8weKWY2W@88TydDhEE02kek/8CZRuNF7cx7K6gLcWL2D@JeNObGXw)

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, 108 bytes

```
read-host|%{[char[]]$_|%{$d=$_-replace'\P{L}'-replace'[aeiou]',0-replace'\D',1;$s="$s$d";$r="$d$r"};$s-eq$r}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 126 bytes

```
g(x)==~member?(x,alphabetic());v(s:String):Boolean==(w:=remove(g,s);a:=[member?(w.r,"aeiouAEIOU")for r in 1..#w];a=reverse(a))
```

test

```
(8) -> [[i,v(i)] for i in ["Dennis", "Martin", "Martin Ender", "Alex", "Alex A.", "Doorknob", "Mego"]]
   (8)
   [["Dennis",true], ["Martin",true], ["Martin Ender",true], ["Alex",false],
    ["Alex A.",true], ["Doorknob",false], ["Mego",false]]
                                                      Type: List List Any
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 20 bytes

```
ù⌠úc⌡░⌠"aeiou"c⌡M;R=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/6hnwf/DO4Hk4V3Jj3oWPpo2EchWSkzNzC9VAgn4WgfZ/gfRmf@jlVxS8/Iyi5V0lHwTi0oy8@AMBde8lNQiINcxJ7UCSik46gFZLvn5Rdl5@Ukgpanp@UqxAA) (runs all test cases)

-3 bytes from Erik the Outgolfer's [suggestion on a different answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125237/its-hip-to-be-square/125254?noredirect=1#comment308855_125254)

Explanation:

```
ù⌠úc⌡░⌠"aeiou"c⌡M;R=
ù                     lowercase input
 ⌠úc⌡░                characters where function is truthy:
  úc                    is the character a lowercase letter?
      ⌠"aeiou"c⌡M     for each letter:
       "aeiou"c         does the vowel string contain the letter?
                 ;R=  compare equality with reverse (is it a palindrome?)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 47 bytes

```
i(`[^a-z]

[aeiou]
1
\D
0
+`^(.)(.*)\1$
$2
^.?$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP1MjITouUbcqlosrOjE1M780lsuQK8aFy4BLOyFOQ09TQ09LM8ZQhUvFiCtOz17l/3@X1Ly8zGIu38QioCFQSsE1LyW1iMsxJ7UCTCg46nG55OcXZeflJ3H5pqbncykoKimrqKqpa2hqaevo6ukbGBoZm5iamVtYWlnb2NrZOzg6Obu4url7eHp5@/j6@QcEBgWHhIaFR0RGRcfExsUnJCYlp6SmpWdkZmXn5OblFxQWFZeUlpVXVFZV19TWAQA)

This is just a different approach for non alphabet chars

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 12 bytes

```
#B)l1~-L{D_q
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%23B%29l1%7E-L%7BD_q&input=Dennis%21)

```
#B)          -    filter(is_alpha, input)
   l1        -   ^.lower()
     ~-L{    -  ^ - "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
         D_q - ^ == reversed(^)
```

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 87 Bytes

```
$s=("$args"-replace '\P{L}'-replace'[aeiou]',0-replace'\D',1);$s-eq(-join($s[-1..-99]))
```

Get a copy of the string where vowels are 0 and consonants are 1, with all special chars removed,
compare that string to a reversed version joined back to a string

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\Connor> "Dennis","Martin","Martin Ender","Alex","Alex A.","Doorknob","Mego" | % {
    $s=("$_"-replace '\P{L}'-replace'[aeiou]',0-replace'\D',1);$s-eq(-join($s[-1..-99]))
}
True
True
True
False
True
False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 248 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(UPPER(A1),"[^A-Z]",""),"[AEIOU]","0"),"[^0]","1")=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(UPPER(JOIN("",(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1)))),"[^A-Z]",""),"[AEIOU]","0"),"[^0]","1"))
```

Three nested `REGEXREPLACE` functions transform it from the original to a string of ones and zeroes. The `JOIN` function is used to reverse the original string so it's nested into the same `REGEXREPLACE` functions to transform it to the reverse string of ones and zeroes. It's a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 115 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
For i=1To[Len(A1)]:a=Mid([A1],i,1):b=IIf(Instr(1,"AEIOU",a,1),1,IIf(a Like"[A-Za-z]",0,""))&b:Next:?b=StrReverse(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 75 bytes

```kotlin
filter{it.isLetter()}.map{"aeiou".contains(it,true)}.let{it==it.reversed()}
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
filter { it.isLetter() }.map { "aeiou".contains(it, true) }.let { it == it.reversed() }
```

### Test

```kotlin
data class Test(val input: String, val output: Boolean)

val tests = listOf(
    Test("Dennis",true),
    Test("Martin",true),
    Test("Martin Ender",true),
    Test("Alex",false),
    Test("Alex A.",true),
    Test("Doorknob",false),
    Test("Mego",false)
)

fun String.f() =
filter{it.isLetter()}.map{"aeiou".contains(it,true)}.let{it==it.reversed()}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for ((input, expected) in tests) {
        val actual = input.f()
        if (actual != expected) throw AssertionError()
    }
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##dVHLboMwELzzFVtORkJ8QFQqUSW3Rj20P+DCmlpxvGi9pKkQ304NJFWkpnuxNbOzj9kDibN+ShotGmqnQ4B3DKJO2oH1XS8beBO2vs1hhqiXBXsmcqh9liQzKlERoARng7walUCMpUq6Re9tSHPhHrP8hthrFuv/JWDnG+Q7dOXwnOZGu/AXh6q4o9gS8cHTxz3VHlu64klcxvT+sm5hVAblZKwT5MFKYcMLSvyrbCyOuhtSjZb6tKjJi7Y+KCtr77FwKFFRllHFeEIO2ETVNBc/xlSluQ0bqJj19+Pa7SmDYRnLEINSi/E54LnDWrDJ4iVWj69pc8zG61r6+JTrqeaZf2lrQF3oh/KmlHwyfUEVAkafye+YiS+yMRmnHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 65 bytes

```julia
f(s,b=[c in "aeiouAEIOU" for c in s if isalpha(c)])=b==reverse(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcoxD4IwEAXg3V9xdqKJYXQjEYODA3HRyTi0cOApuZoeGP99LZqoxOXy7nvvMnRkliE0iSxsdqyAGJRBckO@2e4OChrn4aUC1ACJ6W5nk1T6pDObZR7v6AUTq8MgxC2sjWC6R@lnqz5ewR7UGKCKhSiw2BK/O2gSVSAzidJfKY3vif8FNlyj//g8FnmHj9/h@EOeTjaFc/7Kzk6wxNZFQK7DEw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 59 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ɬ←ąĐ0↔ą∈⇹6²Ĩ*ž1ᴇ-5²⁺%⁺+ĐĐĐĐ1=⇹5=⇹04Ș9=06Ș+35*=0↔+37*=∨∨∨∨+₽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5JpHbROOtB6ZYPCobcqR1kcdHY/ad5od2nRkhdbRfYYPt7Trmh7a9KhxlyoQax@ZAIGGtkBFpiDCwOTEDEtbA7MTM7SNTbVsQYZoG5tr2T7qWAFH2o@a9v7/75Kal5dZDAA)

Much of this code is because Pyt is not very good at strings.

Explanation:

```
ɬ               Push "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
←ą              Get input string as an array of characters
Đ               Duplicate the array of characters
0↔              Push 0 and flip the stack
ą               Get the top of the stack as an array of characters
∈               Is each character in the input a letter?
⇹               Swap top two on the stack (input as array of characters)
6²Ĩ             Interpret element-wise as base-36 **
*ž              Remove all non-letters
1ᴇ-             Subtract 10 from each element
5²⁺%            Mod 26
⁺               Increment
+               Let's get rid of that 0
ĐĐĐĐ            Push 4 additional copies of the top of the stack
1=⇹             Is it equal to 1 ('a')
5=⇹04Ș          Is it equal to 5 ('e')
9=06Ș           Is it equal to 9 ('i')
+               Get rid of a 0
35*=            Is it equal to 15 ('o')
0↔              Push 0 and flip the stack
+               Get rid of a 0
37*=            Is it equal to 21 ('u')
∨∨∨∨            OR the arrays
+               Get rid of that last 0
₽               Is the top of the stack a palindrome?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 34 bytes

```
{32|}%.123,97>--{"aeiou"?)!}%.-1%=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v9rYqKZWVc/QyFjH0txOV7daKTE1M79UyV5TESisa6hq@/@/Y05qhYKjHgA)

## Explanation

```
{32|}%                             # Convert to lowercase (Works at least with alpha)
      .123,97>--                   # Keep only lowercase letters
                {"aeiou"?)!}%      # Foreach: is it a vowel?
                             .-1%= # Is it a palindrome?
```