# Divisibility Streak

Tags: code-golf, number, division

We can define the Divisibility Streak `k` of a number `n` by finding the smallest non-negative integer `k` such that `n+k` is not divisible by `k+1`.

#### Challenge

In your language of choice, write a program or function that outputs or returns the Divisibility Streak of your input.

#### Examples:

```
n=13:
13 is divisible by 1 
14 is divisible by 2 
15 is divisible by 3 
16 is divisible by 4 
17 is not divisible by 5
```

The Divisibilty Streak of `13` is `4`

```
n=120:
120 is divisible by 1 
121 is not divisible by 2
```

The Divisibilty Streak of `120` is `1`

#### Test Cases:

```
n      DS
2      1
3      2
4      1
5      2
6      1
7      3
8      1
9      2
10     1
2521   10
```

More test cases can be found [here](https://tio.run/##ZY8xa8MwEIXn6lc8DAUJO0FpRzVTQqYECh66dBGuGgSxBNLFKBj/dldyITT0DbrH3fdOUhdXnQ9mvkbrzmhvkUyv5u6iY8R78OegezYyZEXSZDsM3n7hpK3jYmmP7GnnXfQXs/4IlszROsMrlyf79tNVQrEFK/r2AXzQAYQtXlQub3iVUmZX1@KOjXdXVPiUeake2ssuBU6okQSewVN2G4FtQZHywsfA/0e2FPKf1wcfek28GuVULt9MVUNNEn/iE/s9p3n@AQ).

#### Notes

- Based on [Project Euler Problem 601](https://projecteuler.net/problem=601)
- This sequence can be found on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A055874), shifted down by 1.

#### Rules

- You can assume the input is greater than 1.

#### Scoring

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf):The submission with the lowest score wins.

Comment: I suggest changing "smallest positive integer" to "smallest nonnegative integer". It doesn't change the challenge at all, but with the current description, it implies we don't need to check for divisibility by 1 (which we technically shouldn't need to). Either that, or you could remove the divisibility by 1 checks from the description.

Comment: The smallest positive integer is 1, and `k + 1` is 2, where `k` is the smallest positive integer. Sorry for the nitpick.

Comment: Isn't this the same as finding the smallest `k` which doesn't divide `n-1`?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Take `n=7` where `k=3`: `n-1` is divisible by `k`.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `+1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
f%tQh
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%25tQh&input=13&debug=0)

Answer (score 19):

## Java 8, <s>44</s> <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

[<sup>*Crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(*</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136384/52210)

```java
n->{int r=0;for(;~-n%--r<1;);return~r;}
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@LeakyNun*.
-1 byte thanks to *@TheLethalCoder*.
-2 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##dU9LCoMwEN33FLMpGCSiQlcxvUHduCxdpDGWtDpKjEIRvbpN1G1hPsznvXnzFqOgbafwXX5WWYu@h5vQOJ0ANFplKiEV5L7cGiADH5Ew15mdO@utsFpCDggcVqTXya8YHrOqNQFbKJ4pNVnCCDPKDgYXw@aV7eBueNYOfHCMrS6hcfeDwhqNr/sDBNmPey7Pq3nKQGc8iV0Kw2MKUHx7q5qoHWzUOaitMcDIqSWb1F3s3630kibk@Glefw)

```java
n->{                 // Method with integer as parameter and return-type
  int r=0;           //  Result-integer (starting at 0)
  for(;~-n%--r<1;);  //  Loop as long as `n-1` is divisible by `r-1`
                     //   (after we've first decreased `r` by 1 every iteration)
  return~r;          //  Return `-r-1` as result integer
}                    // End of method
```

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##dU9LDoIwEN17itmY0BiIJXFV8QayYWlcVKymCgMZCokhcPU6Bbcm88l83ps3Lz3ouGkNvu5vX1a66@CsLY4bAIvO0EOXBvJQLg0ooxBRKO5M7Gyd086WkANCBh7j0xhWKJPq0VCk5hi38UxHqWi3E4qM6wmB1OTVim/7W8X4H83Q2DvULCEqHFl8Xq6gxXo/0AVqm6UK7DGTe07MuU4Bik/nTJ00vUtahroKI0xYsFjUrnr/bqWHVIrfW5P/Ag)

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##dU9LCoMwEN33FLMpJIiiQlfR3qBuXJYu0hhLWh0lRqGIXj1N1G1hPsznvXnz5hMPu17iu/pY0fBhgBtXOJ8AFBqpay4kFL7cGiCIj0iZ6yzOnQ2GGyWgAIQcLIbX2a/oPGZ1pwlbQzyHaxDoLGGUaWlGjaDZYtkO78dn4@AHy9SpClqngJRGK3zdH8Dpft6zeWaVpwxUliexS0FwTAHK72BkG3WjiXoHNQ0SjJxeuond5f7dSi9pQo@vFvsD) Just shaved a byte from LeakyNun's suggestion.

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##dU9LCoMwEN33FLMpGCSiQlcxvUHduCxdpDGWtDpKjEIRvbpN1G1hPsznvXnzFqOgbafwXX5WWYu@h5vQOJ0ANFplKiEV5L7cGiADH5Ew15mdO@utsFpCDggcVqTXya8YHrOqNQFbKJ4pNVnCCDPKDgYXw@aV7eBueNYOfHCMrS6hcfeDwhqNr/sDBNmPey7Pq3nKQGc8iV0Kw2MKUHx7q5qoHWzUOaitMcDIqSWb1F3s3630kibk@Glefw "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 35 bytes

```hs
f n=[k|k<-[1..],rem(n+k)(k+1)>0]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY6uybbRjfaUE8vVqcoNVcjTztbUyNb21DTziBWUdHgf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYJGmoKhgSaXAhDY2SGJGWOKGZkaGWr@BwA)

Using `until` is also 35 bytes

```hs
f n=until(\k->rem(n+k)(k+1)>0)(+1)1
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
ḟ§%→+⁰N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO@YeWqz5qm6T9qHGD3////41MjQwB)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
Ý+āÖ0k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVln5//Bc7SONh6cZZP@vVDq830rh8H4lnf9GXMZcJlymXGZc5lwWXJZchgZcRqZGhgA)

**Alternate 7 byte solutions:**
`<DLÖγнg`
`Ls<ÑKн<`

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 13 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429)

```apl
⊃∘⍸⍳(×+∘×|+)⊢
```

-1b thanks to Adám

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/x91NT/qmPGod8ej3s0ah6drAzmHp9doaz7qWvQ/DajiUW8fRHFX86H1xo/aJgJ5wUHOQDLEwzP4/6PeuQp5CmDgEsyVpmAEZoJEgcAQKGCMLGAEFDBBV2GKrsIMXYU5soAxUMACXYUluhmGBmgqjEyNDBECBgA)

Previous solution made tacit (i.e. using trains)

---

```apl
{⊃⍸×(1+⍳⍵)|⍵+⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sfdTU/6t1xeLqGofaj3s2Perdq1gAJKLv2fxpQ1aPePoiGruZD640ftU0E8oKDnIFkiIdn8P9HvXMV8hTAwCWYK03BCMwEiQKBIVDAGFnACChggq7CFF2FGboKc2QBY6CABboKS3QzDA3QVBiZGhkiBAwA)

Only my second APL answer so I'm sure it can be golfed further!

Justification for only searching up to 2n is due to [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) which states that for any n>3, there exists a prime number between n and 2^n-2. Since by definition a prime only has factors of itself and 1, it will always terminate the divisibility streak.

### Explanation

```apl
{⊃⍸×(1+⍳⍵)|⍵+⍳⍵}  ⍝
{              }  ⍝ dfn, in this case taking a single argument (e.g. 13) mapped to ⍵
             ⍳⍵   ⍝ computes array of digits 0,1,2,3,4...,12
           ⍵+     ⍝ adds the original argument to each element of this array - 13,14,15,16...25
    (1+⍳⍵)        ⍝ computes a new array from 1...13
          |       ⍝ applies modulo to elements at the same index across the two arrays, e.g. 13%1,14%2,15%3,16%4,17%5...26%14 = 0 0 0 0 2...12
   ×              ⍝ converts any number >1 to 1, e.g. 0 0 0 0 1...1
  ⍸               ⍝ find the index of all 'true's. e.g. 4 6 7 8 9 10 12 13
 ⊃                ⍝ take the first, e.g. 4
```

Comment: -1: `⊃∘⍸⍳(×+∘×|+)⊢` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/x91NT/qmPGod8ej3s0ah6drAzmHp9doaz7qWvQ/DajiUW8fRHFX86H1xo/aJgJ5wUHOQDLEwzP4/6PeuQp5CmDgEsyVpmAEZoJEgcAQKGCMLGAEFDBBV2GKrsIMXYU5soAxUMACXYUluhmGBmgqjEyNDBECBgA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

```js
n=>g=(x=2)=>++n%x?--x:g(++x)
```

---

### Test it

```js
o.innerText=(f=

n=>g=(x=2)=>++n%x?--x:g(++x)

)(i.value=2521)();oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)()
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>23</s> 21 + 1 (-p) = 22 bytes

```perl
1until$_++%++$\}{$\--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@wNK8kM0clXltbVVtbJaa2WiVGVxcobPwvv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaHBf90CAA)

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
0//.i_/;(i+1)∣(#+i):>i+1&
```

An unnamed function that takes an integer argument.

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox](http://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com)

Usage:

```
0//.i_/;(i+1)∣(#+i):>i+1&[2521]
```

> `10`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x=1:n%x<1and-~f(n+1,x+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxCsIwFAXQPV9xF6GlV@iLVm0xXyIOkRoM6GtpM8TFX4/i2c/8To9JbSnBPf3rNnoos5NBN/ksXsftJ1TaCHMjdUn3Na1wuFhiR@yJjjgQR@JE9IS0hO2sXI0J04KIqPinweBnXqImhCrW5Qs)

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>23</s> 15 bytes

```
#1_(~!/)(1+)\1,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X9kwXqNOUV9Tw1BbM8ZQx9D4/38A)

**Explanation:**

```
(~!/)(1+)\1, / the solution
          1, / prepend 1 to input
     (1+)\   / iterate, increasing by 1
(~!/)        / until the modulo (!) is not (~) zero
```

- -8 bytes thanks to @Traws!

Comment: 15 bytes with `#1_(~!/)(1+)\1,`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun)!*

```python
i=input();k=1
while~-i%-~k<1:k+=1
print k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERD0zrb1pCrPCMzJ7VON1NVty7bxtAqWxsoVlCUmVeikP3/v6ExAA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda i,k=1:~-i%-~k<1and f(i,k+1)or k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIVMn29bQqk43U1W3LtvGMDEvRSFNAyiobaiZX6SQ/b@gKDOvRCNNw9BYU/M/AA)

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERD0zrb1pCrPCMzJ7VON1NVty7bxtAqWxsoVlCUmVeikP3/v6ExAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 17 bytes

```
)uUqI1%?;)qUO(;/@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/1@zNLTQ01DV3lqzMNRfw1rf4f9/I1MjQwA)

Cubified

```
    ) u
    U q
I 1 % ? ; ) q U
O ( ; / @ . . .
    . .
    . .
```

- `I1` setup the stack with input and divisor
- `%?` do mod and test

  - `;)qU)uqU` if 0 remove result and increment input and divisor.   Bit of a round about path to get back to `%`
  - `/;(O@` if not 0, drop result, decrement divisor, output and exit

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICkgdQogICAgVSBxCkkgMSAlID8gOyApIHEgVQpPICggOyAvIEAgLiAuIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=MjUyMQo=&speed=20)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-æ`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>9</s> <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
N°u°U
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LeY&code=TrB1sFU&input=MjUyMQ)

### Original (w/o flag), 7 bytes

```
@°uXÄ}a
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QLB1WMR9YQ&input=MjUyMQ)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
@     }a
```

Return the first integer that returns a truthy value (a number `>0`) when passed through a function (with `X` being the current integer)  ...

```
°
```

That postfix increments `U` ...

```
uXÄ
```

And modulos it (`u`) by `X+1`.

Comment: I wish `U` got auto-added after the `@` here, but it doesn't do that on `+` and `-`. Bummer. Maybe we should request it gets auto-added when followed by `++` or `--`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>44</s> 40 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun.*

```python
f=lambda n,x=1:~-n%-~x and x or f(n,x+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxNCsIwGAX3OcXbFCy@gon2x0JOIi4iNRjQr6XNIm569Ric7TCzfONrFpOzt2/3eUwOwmT1uDdSNXuCkwkJ8wp/KOKo6xyfW9xgcTPEmbgQLdERPTEQV0KfCNMafVfKlzAgCP7RqFBY1iCx7EKdfw)

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxNCsIwGAX3OcXbFCy@gon2x0JOIi4iNRjQr6XNIm569Ric7TCzfONrFpOzt2/3eUwOwmT1uDdSNXuCkwkJ8wp/KOKo6xyfW9xgcTPEmbgQLdERPTEQV0KfCNMafVfKlzAgCP7RqFBY1iCx7EKdfw)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```cs
n=>{int r=0;while(~-n%--r<1);return~r;}
```

Essentially a port of [@Kevin Cruijssen's Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139000/38550) with further golfing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxC8IwFIT3/Iq3CAkaaQtOaboITgqCg3OJqT5oXyBJFSntX4/p7nLH3XecCXJw5NIYkJ5w@4ZoB8WY6dsQ4MomFmIb0cDb4QMuLRIXuTyNZGqkuIMsDXSgE@lmygG8LtTnhb3li6SNlL4uhfI2jp4Wr@aUzzvnga9bBA2VylZrKAsF2y2u70dHwfV2f/cY7RnJ8o6jEIrNf1F1qMqVZjynHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift 4](https://www.swift.org), 56 bytes

This is a full function `f`, with an integer parameter `i` that prints the output.

```swift
func f(i:Int){var k=0;while(i-1)%(k+1)<1{k+=1};print(k)}
```

**[Try it here.](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5991c724cb3d25200b15340f)**

## [Swift 4](https://www.swift.org), 56 bytes

This is an anonymous function, that returns the result.

```swift
{var k=0;while($0-1)%(k+1)<1{k+=1};return k}as(Int)->Int
```

**[Try it here.](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5991c72ecb3d25200b153410)**

**[Check out the Test Suite!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5991c652cb3d25200b15340e)**

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>34</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
f=->n,d=1{n%d<1?1+f[n+1,d+1]:0}
```

A recursive lambda. Still new to Ruby, so suggestions are welcome!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P1vBViE9taRYryQ/PpOLK81W1y5PJ8XWsDpPNcXG0N5QOy06T9tQJ0XbMNbKoJaLq6C0pFghLTo79v9/Q2MA)

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 28 bytes

```
1si[1+dli1+dsi%0=M]dsMxli1-p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2RqZPjfsDgz2lA7JScTSBRnqhrY@samFPtWAPm6Bf//AwA)

This feels *really* suboptimal, with the incrementing and the final decrement, but I can't really see a way to improve on it. Basically we just increment a counter `i` and our starting value as long as value mod `i` continues to be zero, and once that's not true we subtract one from `i` and print.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 8 bytes

```
@1Ė₌)†↺(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/38HwyLRHTT2ajxoWPGrbpfH/v6ExAA)

#### Explanation

```
@         Push input (call it n).
 1        Push 1 (call it i).
      ↺   While...
  Ė₌       n is divisible by i:
    )†     Increment both n and i.
       (  Decrement the value of i that failed this test and print.
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 17 bytes

```
[:{.@I.>:@i.|i.+]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WL9qqWs/BU8/OyiFTryZTTzuWiys1OSNfIU3ByNTI8P9/AA)

I think there's still room for golfing here.

#### Explanation (ungolfed)

```
[: {.@I. >:@i. | i. + ]
                 i. + ]  Range [n,2n)
                 i.       Range [0,n)
                    +     Added to each
                      ]   n
         >:@i. | i. + ]  Divisibility test
         >:@i.            Range [1,n+1)
               |          Modulo (in J, the arguments are reversed)
                 i. + ]   Range [n,2n)
    {.@I.                Get the index of the first non-divisible
       I.                 Indices of non-zero values
    {.                    Head
```

The cap (`[:`) is there to make sure that J doesn't treat the last verb (`{.@I.`) as part of a hook.

The only sort of weird thing about this answer is that `I.` actually duplicates the index of each non-zero number as many times as that number's value. e.g.

```
   I. 0 1 0 2 3
1 3 3 4 4 4
```

But it doesn't matter since we want the first index anyways (and since `i.` gives an ascending range, we know the first index will be the smallest value).

Finally, here's a very short proof that it is valid to check division only up to `n`.

We start checking divisibility with `1 | n`, so assuming the streak goes that far, once we get to checking divisibility by `n` we have `n | 2n - 1` which will never be true (`2n - 1 ≡ n - 1 (mod n)`). Therefore, the streak will end there.

Comment: `0{[:I.>:@i.|i.+]` to save one byte.  The alternative I came up with independently before noticing your answer, also 16: `0{]I.@(>:@]|+)i.`.  [Includes test cases](https://tio.run/##Nc5PC4JAEAXw@3yKhxddqml3zf4YhhQEQnToKkuEKNmlg930u2/atgMDjx/D8F424LBBliLEHBLpuAvG6XY5W9mXacGHNG95aHlmrKDrkSF7U3AejW6GmWiZ6ur5RgMVE32qR1d3yBgB7/muYaafkjR@oyh2QdPKS@Jl7WXjQkxbLzt/o@RfdKLVFCQJcgUigwxNXoploOB62C8 "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah I must admit, it’s been a while since I wrote this answer. I’d have no qualms with you posting that as its own answer, seeing as you came up with it independently.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
õ b!%UÉ
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9SBiISVVyQ==&input=MTM=)

Answer (score 2):

## x86 Machine Code, 16 bytes

```
49                 dec    ecx        ; decrement argument
31 FF              xor    edi, edi   ; zero counter

                Loop:
47                 inc    edi        ; increment counter
89 C8              mov    eax, ecx   ; copy argument to EAX for division
99                 cdq               ; use 1-byte CDQ with unsigned to zero EDX
F7 FF              idiv   edi        ; EDX:EAX / counter
85 D2              test   edx, edx   ; test remainder
74 F6              jz     Loop       ; keep looping if remainder == 0

4F                 dec    edi        ; decrement counter
97                 xchg   eax, edi   ; move counter into EAX for return
C3                 ret               ;  (use 1-byte XCHG instead of 2-byte MOV)
```

The above function takes a single parameter, `n`, in the `ECX` register. It computes its divisibility streak, `k`, and returns that via the `EAX` register. It conforms to the 32-bit [fastcall calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall), so it is easily callable from C code using either Microsoft or Gnu compilers.

The logic is pretty simple: it just does an iterative test starting from 1. It's functionally identical to most of the other answers here, but hand-optimized for size. Lots of nice 1-byte instructions there, including `INC`, `DEC`, `CDQ`, and `XCHG`. The hard-coded operands for division hurt us a bit, but not terribly so.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NboMwEEbX@BQjqkp2EqoC@SEizYaKS9QVcg0mloipjKksVbl66ZA0yy5Gb8bf03hk1Eo5TbI3gwN5EhZ8ti36unl7hxcIuU9j7suS@/Uea8d9hiwy7vfIcnfLsg33rwn3uzXOW/TwbY9ZkYY5GZxwWsJoBt2apoaqEs5Z/TG6pqooVWJwUnQdY0AXitG7x/D7v1Py6UEb2Y11A4fB1bp/Oh2JNg7OQhs6N8K2cnU7f7HA4YuRbxKo3sI11rgryREHiOMclkvNSIBC8GkxVjR8rLmLjtwhTbgCvQJFNWM5CS7kPynZJPHszbyqJLCNG62B55xcph@pOtEOU3ROk18)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 34 bytes

```php
for(;$argv[1]++%++$r<1;);echo$r-1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVEovSy6INY7W1VbW1VYpsDK01rVOTM/JVinQNrf/b2/3/b2gMAA)

Simple enough. Checks the remainder of division (mod) each loop while incrementing each value, outputs when the number isn't divisible anymore.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 19 bytes

```
#v_1+::&+1-\%
1<@.-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X7ks3lDbykpN21A3RpXL0MZBT/f/fyNTI0MA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Ḷ+%RTḢ’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm3aqkEhD3csetQw8////0amRoYA)

Explanation:

```
Ḷ+%RTḢ’  main link, argument: n
Ḷ+       [n, 2n-1]
   R     [1, n]
  %      modulo
    TḢ   index of first truthy value (first value where k+1 does not divide n+k), 1-indexed
      ’  decrement
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 17 bytes

```
®n0&{©n⑻+⑹⑻%0=|}⑺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////0Lo8A7XqQyvzHk3crf1o4k4gpWpgW1P7aOKu//8Njf/rFgUBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

**Solution:**

```
*(1+)/[{y=x*_y%x}. 1+;]1,
```

**Explanation:**

Pretty naive. Start with list of [1, x] and increment both until no longer divisible.

```
*(1+)/[{y=x*_y%x}. 1+;]1, / the solution
                       1, / prepend input with 1
 (  )\[              ;]   / (loop)\[condition;start]
       {        }.        / lambda taking implicit x & y
                   1+     / add 1 (vectorised) [1, 13] => [2, 14]
             y%x          / divide y by x
            _             / floor
          y*              / multiply by x
        y=                / equals y?
  1+                      / add 1 (vectorised) [1, 13] => [2, 14]
*                         / take first [2, 14] => 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 30 bytes

```powershell
for(;!($args[0]++%++$i)){}$i-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3bCoJAEIbv9yk22MLFFVztSASCD1BkdxFRNnbAsHZXCsxnN63Uba6G7//nm1vyACFPEMdWmAgoSDTLiigRxrRjkJ04yrW9Mc2uaZIzpVlOzhYvcoQ8A@FymGc4jNN6d5nT7H2NDzQ@1PiIuc0@1vhE63NbC5yBwxm3KaL4hbs4@3CiQCp/J4FhAs8bhAoOeIbJ9psKkGmsStAjUdtFn3C9CPxUquQ631/Ku433NVYTpGEIUlaiRmrBvfZNm@LqZ6yatb1Nl/X3v7sc5ah4Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
?+n›%)Ṅ
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiPytu4oC6JSnhuYQiLCIiLCIyXG4zXG40XG41XG42XG43XG44XG45XG4xMFxuMjUyMSJd)

Explanation:

```
     )   # Lambda f from beginning of program
      Ṅ  # First non-negative integer n such that f(n) is truthy
?        # Push the input
 +       # Add n to it
    %    # Modulo
  n›     # N incremented
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 20 bytes

```
0\1-n;
?\1+:@$:1+}$%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDGUDfPmss@xlDbykHFylC7VkX1////umWGxgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 14 bytes

```
ĐřĐ0↔⁻⇹|¬*ž↓⁻+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISjM49MMHjUNuVR4@5H7TtrDq3ROrrvUdtkIFf7/38jAA)

Determines the first positive integer that does not divide \$n-1\$.

```
Đ                   implicit input; Đuplicate
 ř                  řangify
  Đ                 Đuplicate
   0                push 0 (so the next action will work properly)
    ↔               flip the stack
     ⁻              decrement
      ⇹             swap top two items
       |¬           divisibility test; negate
         *ž↓        multiply element-wise, remove žeros, get minimum
            ⁻       decrement
             +      add to get rid of pesky 0; implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 32 bytes

```
$[n][1while[0=%n-+1<=<=][+1]dec]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?LGAfk1)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5.5 bytes

```
?,~~%+@$+$~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWq-116upUtR1UtFXqICJQiQX7DI25DI0MuIy4jLlMuEy5zLjMuSy4LLkMgUKmRoYQVQA)

```
? Find the index of the first item
,  in the numbers from 1 to
~   infinity
~  such that the result of the following is positive
%   modulo
+    add
@     the input
$     the number
+    add
$     the number
~     1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ƙ+n⁺%
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU5OCUyQm4lRTIlODElQkElMjUmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xMyZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
Ƙ+n⁺%  # Implicit input
Ƙ      # Find the first positive integer, n, such that:
 +     #  input + n
    %  #  mod
  n⁺   #  n + 1
       #  is truthy (non-zero)
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
]e.-ē⁴I\
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTVEZS4tJXUwMTEzJXUyMDc0SSU1Qw__,inputs=MTM_)

Not bad for a language which is made for a completely different type of challenges.

Explanation:

```
]         do .. while top of the stack is truthy
 e          push the variable E contents, by default user input
  .-        subtract the input from it
    ē       push the value of the variable E and then increase the variable
     ⁴      duplicate the item below one in the stack
      I     increase it
       \    test if divides
            if it does divide, then the loop restarts, if not, outputs POP which is `e-input`
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 40 bytes

```
Min@Complement[Range@#,Divisors[#-1]-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfNzPPwTk/tyAnNTc1ryQ6KDEvPdVBWcclsyyzOL@oOFpZ1zAWiNT@BxRl5pU4pEUbGsf@BwA) (Mathics)

Mathematical approach, n+k is divisible by k+1 if and only if n-1 is divisible by k+1. And n-1 is not divisible by n, so `Range@#` is enough numbers.

Originally I intend to use `Min@Complement[Range@#,Divisors[#-1]]-1&`, but this also work.

Comment: Why does the captcha appear when I use the submission from tio?

Comment: Because you typed (copied-and-pasted) it too quickly. It isn't about TIO.

Answer (score 1):

### Julia 0.6.0 <strike>(47 bytes)</strike> (38 bytes)

<strike>`n->(i=1;while isinteger(n/i) i+=1;n+=1 end;i-1)`</strike>

`n->(i=1;while n%i<1 i+=1;n+=1end;i-1)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@19QlJlXoqHxP0/XTiPT1tC6PCMzJ1UhsxgompqeWqSRp5@pqZCpDZTJAxIKqXkp1pm6hpr/NTUMjTU1/wMA)

9 bytes were cut thanks to Mr.Xcoder

Comment: Normally a "Try it online" link allows people to actually *try* the code by defining some combination of header, footer, and arguments which mean that pressing the play button gives output.

Comment: @PeterTaylor By a pure guess, I tried running [it as such](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@19QlJlXoqHxP0/XTiPT1tC6PCMzJ1UhsxgompqeWqSRp5@pqZCpDZTJAxIKqXkp1pm6hpr/NTUMjTU1/wMA), and to my  surprise it worked. I recommend the OP to edit in with the testable version.

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@19QlJlXoqHxP0/XTiPT1tC6PCMzJ1UhsxgompqeWqSRp5@pqZCpDZTJAxKpeSnWmbqGmv81NQyNNTX/AwA) (removing one space): `n->(i=1;while isinteger(n/i) i+=1;n+=1end;i-1)`

Comment: Another pure guess allowed be to golf it down to 38 bytes: [`n->(i=1;while n%i<1 i+=1;n+=1end;i-1)`](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@19QlJlXoqHxP0/XTiPT1tC6PCMzJ1UhTzXTxlAhUxsokAckUvNSrDN1DTX/a2oYGmtq/gcA)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sorry forgot it!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 34 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=1;++n%++i<1;);n=i-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYvBDoIwEETvfMUGQ9JSMCmJF7f4JV5Ia2GJLqaiF8K319azpzeTN2Pb0dp4ILb3t7uBea2OluN0iYResNz8EgT1GpXiSikyGiVyT63GPRKv8BiIRQ5DGG0DdhoC1HUqHwlb8XsnOUMPHSYY0DpRKVk8QzJelJU7Q@WuXDYwN@DFLCX@k92p09ln5skevw)

Comment: Suggest `i--` instead of `n=i-1`

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 70 bytes

```
@set/an=%1-1,i=0
:l
@set/ai+=1,r=n%%~i
@if %r%==0 goto l
@echo %i%
```

All this is doing is finding the largest `i` such that `LCM(1..i)` divides `n-1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>43</s> 37 bytes

```r
n=scan();which((n+1:n)%%(1:n+1)>0)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTujwjMzlDQyNP29AqT1NVVQNIaRtq2hloRhvG/jcyNTL8DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
[;`%
I)@]
iIk2I(D(
rk[(&Xpu
```

I could save one byte if I don't have to exit.

#### Explanation:

We use three stacks: The left stack holds a counter starting at 2, the right one holds the given number (or its increments), the center stack is used for doing the modulo operations. We could, of course, do everything in one stack, but this way we can set the outer stacks to be "sticky" (values that are popped aren't really removed) and save ourselves many duplication operations. Here's the method in detail:

Read an integer, increment it, make the current stack sticky, and "move" it (and ourselves) to the stack to the left:

```
iI
rk[
```

Go one more stack to the left, push a literal 2, make this stack sticky, too. Remember this position in the code (`@`), and "move" a value and ourselves to the center stack again.

```
  @]
  k2
   (
```

Now we test: Is the modulo of the top two numbers not 0? If so, jump to the end, otherwise go one stack to the right, increment, and push the value and us to the middle. Then go to the left stack, increment it, too, and jump back to the mark that we set before.

```
[;`%
I)
    I(
    &
```

When the result of the modulo was not zero, we invert the position the IP is moving, go one stack to the left (where our counter lives), decrement it, and print the value, then exit.

```
      D(
     Xpu
```

Answer (score 1):

### F#, <s>86 bytes</s> 84 bytes

```fs
let s n = 
    let rec c n1 d r=if n1%d=0 then c(n1+1)(d+1)(r+1)else r
    c n 1 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BD4IwDIXv@xUvJiQQo8DJi3jzbuKRcCCjw0XYTDeJ/vpZONjDS9q@97UmHGbvfEoTRQQ4NFCQWlsmDY0FA7ixBks2NBXigxx0vuzrIh9WYRGaAoG3oBZGjUoJRrXnq4v8vXnr4qVTK3PurUPP44Lmf8fKUXFs42NbddvixTIyDrt7ZOqf8AaZhQ2iO0nkAbbYjBXKUl6NbxawW0E0EoM@NkL7gVJKpx8)

Edit: -2 characters from Oliver

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Does your program take stdin? You can use [TIO](https://tio.run/##HY7NCsIwEITvfYpBKLSI/bt4Md68Cx7FQ0k2NdgmsolFn75uO4eBHWY@1sbDFHxYlpESIjwUMojWk0lDY4YBK2cx50Y1SE/y0MW8b8vCrMZiNEYCb0MtjBZNJpjsfrr4xL9rcD6dH9nKnHrn0fMwQ211GxgOknVV1TUwYUtXvVlW1mN3S0z9C8Eil2YU38mkiHDlVm5Q1/Jr@rCQvbASDcSgr0vQwdCyHP8), which has an online F# interpreter. Also, can remove the whitespace in `r = if`?

Comment: @Oliver Thank you, I changed the link to TIO, so now you can actually pass the argument to test it. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 13 bytes

```
╗1⌠u;u@╜+%⌡╓u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9hY3R1YWxsef//4pWXMeKMoHU7dUDilZwrJeKMoeKVk3X//zI1MjE)

Explanation:

```
╗1⌠u;u@╜+%⌡╓u
╗              save n to register 0
 1⌠u;u@╜+%⌡╓   first k (starting with k=0) where the following is truthy:
   u             k+1
    ;u@╜+        n+k+1
         %       (n+k+1)%(k+1)
            u  increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
⊥⍨∘⌽0=⍳|-∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HX0ke9Kx51zHjUs9fA9lHv5hpdIMfwf9qjtgmPevse9U319H/U1XxovfGjtolAXnCQM5AM8fAM/v@od65CngIYuARzpSkYgZkgUSAwBAoYIwsYAQVM0FWYoqswQ1dhjixgDBSwQFdhiW6GoQGaCiNTI0OEgAEA)

Uses the alternative representation: the highest `k` such that `1..k` divides `n-1`.

#### How it works

```apl
⊥⍨∘⌽0=⍳|-∘1  ⍝ Input: n
        -∘1  ⍝ n minus 1
    0=⍳|     ⍝ Is divisible by 1..n?
⊥⍨∘⌽         ⍝ Count the leading ones
```

"Count leading ones" idiom can be found on [APLcart](https://aplcart.info/?q=leading%20ones#).

Answer (score 1):

## [asm2bf](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Asm2bf), 74 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVLRCsIwDPygWMH3kB8JfVBBEMEHwe@vubTN2qnzxTDIerldbredHsfr/fI830ohIWUVsc7MKYsoM4nYnSqOO7GGWQbDLiOnIIMNuvFZHVYcQISCjapkgopRFjZga8yb2xsJFH8Ua4TaaowBs6NeVYi7uyrQEGqA68GrSrdoiBny/Wki462q07DrpZNiK4pxY1oiC55nsvJYs1INfNnDKQjhQVdLEdksMi1A/D2PTCsP3qnt6N4H9TR5Rw4k/UOE/CdR4j@LRlzrwOa5fvswEVWVF11c6Lv4ZthjoBXNv37mtP/JGn3ZIZdyeAE)

I/O format: In most cases, it's ASCII, yet some interpreters will output numbers in decimal representation. That's why the test case has `1` return 4 => because in fact, `ASCII(1)` is `49`.

Golfed:

```
in r1
incr2
@l
movr3,r1
modr3,r2
ceqr3,0
cadr1,1
cadr2,1
cjn%l
decr2
outr2
```

Commented version:

```
; Read the number from the standard input.
in r1

; We start the division with 1.
inc r2

@l
    ; r3 = r1 mod r2
    mov r3, r1
    mod r3, r2

    ; if r3 is zero, then the streak
    ; isn't over.
    ceq r3, 0

    ; Pass around next number and divisor.
    cad r1, 1
    cad r2, 1

    ; Loop
    cjn %l

; Display the final result (it's always off-by-one), yet a dec fixes it.
dec r2
out r2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
∧.ℕ+↙?f-₁ⁿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/1HHcr1HLVO1H7XNtE/TfdTU@Khx////0YbGOoZGBjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65joWOpY6hkAhUyPDWAA)

```
 .            The output
∧             (which isn't necessarily the input)
  ℕ           is a non-negative integer, and
      f       the factors of
   +↙?        it plus the input
       -₁ⁿ    do not contain the output plus 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 27 bytes

```javascript
(n,i=2)=>n%i^1?--i:f(n,++i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvtfI08n09ZI09YuTzUzztBeVzfTKg0opq2dqfmfKzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dQ91QQcFWQV1HIU3DSFMTVcoILmWMLoXQZYJblyluXWboUsZwKXPcuixw22WJW5ehAR45S2MD3IYCZQ3x6sUIMhNkWYxQM0PIGmEabACPCFOQ7H8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
->x{1.step{|i|break i-1if x%i!=0;x+=1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDoIwEAXQq3wXrvwQpgpiTL0IYQFmGhs2BDCpaXv2@t72nX/F2VK9QpR6P3SNyad502mBr8Q7hLM/2eYZLlZyLoMhrsSNaImOuBM98SCkIUxrZKx1en8ikiascIOOyOUP)

Answer (score 1):

## [F#](https://fsharp.org), 64 bytes

```fs
let d n=
 let mutable m,l=n,1
 while m%l=0 do m<-m+1;l<-l+1
 l-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxNC4JAEIbv8yuGBUHRDVezD1IvXTvVobOxIwn7IboSQf/d1oRO78w8z7ztyLU1dp5tTwZv79GRBkUOJZoKcJn05JqHItSJqkwiAF/PblkDVaUoLeqS61icVMlV7KniYl4NN0zkBcCzNaNVtLkPnaOQ1TWyaO3uTO@w@gtXauSlMxRG@Kk9dID94KM1yALJMJS/j2gWOYgshQxy2EIBO9jDAY4g/KnIxBc)

Simple explanation:

```fs
let divisibilityStreak n = // Arg: 'n'
 let mutable l = 1         // For increase the 'divisible' number
 let mutable n2 = n        // Another one for storing mutable 'n'
 while n2 % l = 0 do       // While 'n' is divisible by 'l',
  n2 <- n2 + 1             // Add 1 to both 'n2' (mutable 'n')...
  l <- l + 1               // and 'l'
 l - 1                     // Finally, return 'l - 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 34 bytes

```
. as$x|0|until((.+$x)%(1+.)>0;.+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/19PIbFYpaLGoKY0ryQzR0NDT1ulQlNVw1BbT9POwFpP21Dz/38jLmMuEy5TLjMucy4LLksuQwMuQ2MuI1MjQwA)

---

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 40 bytes

```
[range(.)as$x|(.+$x)%(1+$x)<1//-$x]|-max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@6KDEvPVVDTzOxWKWiRkNPW6VCU1XDEETZGOrr66pUxNbo5iZW/P9vxGXMZcJlymXGZc5lwWXJZWjAZWjMZWRqZAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, <s>19</s> 21 bytes

```
Input N
Repeat remainder(N+Ans,Ans+1
Ans+1
End
Ans
```

Output is stored in `Ans` and displayed. This only works on TI-84+/SE with the 2.53 MP OS. The below version is 2 bytes bigger but works on earlier OS's.

---

#### <s>21</s> 23 bytes

```
Input N
Repeat fPart((N+Ans)/(Ans+1
Ans+1
End
Ans
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$10\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 8.231 bytes

```
Lt@!%mCG@}
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJMdEAhJW1DR0B9IiwiMTMiXQ==)

Argh y'all's "first number satisfying f" builtins.

```
Lt@!%mCG@}
       G@} # Generate an infinite list of numbers by incrementing the input
    %      # Modulo each in that list by
     mC    # [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
 t@        # Take while
   !       # The number is 0
L          # Length of the resulting list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Risky](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/risky), 7.5 bytes

```
0+0+0+0??+?\?+1
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIwKzArMCswXG4_XG4_Kz9cXD8rMSIsIlsyNTIxXSIsMF0)

Risky happens to be very good (for its own standards) at this specific problem.

```
0+0+0+0??+?\?+1
       ?        Find the
0+0+0+0         first
                number such that
        ?       (the number
         +       plus
          ?      the input)
           \    modulo
            ?   (the number
             +   plus
              1  1)
                is non-zero
```