# Generate every ASCII string

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence

**Description**

There are an infinite number of ASCII strings. Write a program that will output every possible ASCII string exactly once.

The ordering does not matter, but you must be able to show that for any possible ASCII string `s`, there exists an integer `n` such that `s` is the `n`th string in the output. This restriction means that you cannot output `'a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa', ...`, since the string `'b'` will never occur.

The simplest ordering (shown here in terms of letters so I don't have to type unprintables) is:

```
'', 'a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z', 'aa', 'ab', ..., 'az', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', ... 'zz', 'aaa', ...
```

Essentially, this is counting in base 128 using ASCII characters.

**Rules**

- The empty string is required
- You may use any valid ordering you want
- All possible strings using ASCII must be known to occur in the output
- The ordering does not need to be deterministic, as long as you can show that every string will be *guaranteed* to occur. Be careful if you use randomness for each string, because at some point your bits of entropy may not be enough to guarantee a unique string.

**Example orderings**

<sup>*Note that, again, I'm showing only letters for the examples, but you have to include all ASCII characters.*</sup>

**Valid:**

```
'', 'a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z', 'aa', 'ab', ..., 'az', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', ... 'zz', 'aaa', ...

'', 'z', 'y', 'x', ..., 'a', 'zz', 'zy', ...

'', 'a', 'b', 'ab', 'ba', 'c', 'ac', 'ca', 'bc', 'cb', ...
```

**Invalid:**

```
'', 'a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaa', ...

'', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', ..., 'abc...xyza', ...
```

Comment: This means only printable ascii right?

Comment: I actually intended this to be *all* ASCII.

Comment: uhhh should I repr before printing or something?

Comment: It's up to you. Maybe for testing purposes. Defining a Python generator expression would also be acceptable.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74273/20260), maybe dupe. In fact, I think a past challenge to output all ASCII strings was closed as a dupe.

Comment: *bijective base 128

Comment: Can we output the string in bytes (i.e. in Python `b'\x01'`) or must we print the actual character?

Comment: It would have been better to use only printable ASCII. It's difficult to output non-printable chars and check they are the correct ones

Comment: @xnor Ah. Yeah maybe a dupe. I searched for a good while looking for potential dupes, and I couldn't find that challenge.

Comment: And now find a program doing this by Gödel numbering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
]¶tēN»─{Rt
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTVEJUI2dCV1MDExM04lQkIldTI1MDAlN0JSdA__)

Note that this spams the stack with an extra item every iteration, and with how slow SOGL is, it gets out of hand quickly.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>69</s> 62 bytes

```python
a=0
while 1:
 k=a
 while k:print chr(k%128),;k>>=7
 print;a+=1
```

*-7 bytes thanks to @notjagan*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9HWgKs8IzMnVcHQiksh2zaRSwHCzbYqKMrMK1FIzijSyFY1NLLQ1LHOtrOzNedSAEtYJ2rbGv7/DwA)

Comment: [-7 bytes.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9HWgKs8IzMnVcHQiksh2zaRSwHCzbYqKMrMK1FIzijSyFY1NLLQ1LHOtrOzNedSAEtYJ2rbGv7/DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 96 bytes

```
i=0
(p=print)()
while++i for j:cartesianpower(i,0..128)p(j is tuple? ''.join(map(chr,j)):chr(j))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcUxCoAwDADA3VdkM0Ep6iSC@JYiFVO0CbHS51dvOTXJkmrldWhQVzVOmZCacvIVuo7hEIO47N5yeNgnlRIMuR@cG6eZFCPwA/nVK2zQti4KJ7y94n5aH4mWf/yv9QM)

Comment: I am sure there's some way to print an empty line that's shorter than `(p=print)()` but I can't find it if there is

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 12 bytes

```
.Vj^sCMS127b
```

[Finite version online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V3j%60M%5EsCMS127N&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 64 bytes

```
(f=->a{f[a.flat_map{|s|puts s;(1..127).map{|b|s+b.chr}}]})[['']]
```

Recursive function that prints the array `a` then calls itself on a newly constructed array whose contents are (in set notation) `{ sc | s in a, c in ASCII }`. We kick it off with an array containing the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>44</s> <s>41</s> 61 bytes

[<sup>Crossed out 44 is still regular 44...</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139000/60043)

```
0//.i_:>(Print@@@Array[FromCharacterCode,128,0]~Tuples~i;i+1)
```

Prints in the pattern:  `"", "a", "b", ... , "z", "aa", "ab", ... , "az", "ba", "bb", ... , "zz", "aaa", "aab", ...` (but with \00, \01, ...).

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/)

Unfortunately, I could not use the built-in `CharacterRange` function (which would have reduced 10 bytes) because it cannot generate the null character.

---

I recommend testing with the version that pauses 0.25 sec between each `Print` calls:

```
0//.i_:>((Pause[0.25];Print@##)&@@@Array[FromCharacterCode,128,0]~Tuples~i;i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>103</strike> 78 bytes

```python
n=0
while 1:print(n.to_bytes(n.bit_length()+7>>3,"big").decode());n+=n+1&128|1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8/WgKs8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69EI0@vJD8@qbIktRjITMosic9JzUsvydDQ1Da3szPWUUrKTFfS1EtJTc5PSdXQ1LTO07bN0zZUMzSyqDH8/x8A)