# Uncomment a COBOL program!

Tags: code-golf, string, comment

COBOL is a very old language, at the time of writing it is 58 years old.
It is so old, in fact, that it has a very interesting quirk: the first six characters of each line are comments.

Why is this, you ask? Well, those 6 characters were intended to be used as line numbers, back in the day where programs weren't completely digital and typed out on a computer.

In addition, the seventh character could only be part of a very small set (it is usually `*` to comment out the line or a space to separate the line number from the code)

But what if you're on a more digital system, and you just want the raw program?

### The comment system

There are two types of comments in COBOL: line comments and the aforementioned "line number" comments.

Uncommenting line numbers is simple: just take the first seven (six plus a single space) characters off each line.

```
000000 apple
000001 banana
celery donuts
```

would become:

```
apple
banana
donuts
```

Line comments make it a bit more difficult.
A line comment is started with an asterisk `*` placed in the seventh character position on the line, like so:

```
000323* this is a comment
```

This is not a line comment:

```
*00000 this isn't a comment
```

To uncomment a line comment, just remove the whole line.

An example commented "program":

```
000000 blah blah
000001* apples
000002 oranges?
000003* yeah, oranges.
000*04 love me some oranges
```

The uncommented version:

```
blah blah
oranges?
love me some oranges
```

In other words, to uncomment a string, remove the first six characters of each line, then return all but the first character of every line that does not begin with a star.

### The challenge

Create a program or function that takes a commented program and returns its uncommented variant.

### Clarifications

- Asterisks (`*`) will never be found anywhere outside the first seven characters on a line (we're not asking you to verify syntax)
- Each line will always have at least 7 characters.
- You may assume the seventh character is always an asterisk or a space.
- Input or output may be a matrix or list.
- Only printable ASCII characters (plus newline) must be handled.
- You may output with a trailing newline. You may also assume that the input will have a trailing newline, if you so choose.

### Scoring

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the answer with the least bytes wins!

<sub>DISCLAIMER: I do not actually know COBOL and do not claim to. If any of the claims about COBOL I have made in this question are incorrect, I take no responsibility.</sub>

Comment: Line numbers are not comments. They are a column. Terminology please.

Comment: Your examples all have a space after the `*`. Is this a coincidence?

Comment: @Neil Yes, it is. The eighth character can be anything.

Comment: Old does not automatically imply bad.  I have worked in an Agile COBOL shop.  They could do things on the AS/400 we could not do in Java.

Comment: Heh... I actually wrote a COBOL CopyBook parser that only works if the fields aren't packed. Just transforms it into JSON `key:{key:{key:length,key:length}}`. Strips all formatting data and typing data though.

Comment: Can there be a space in the first 6 characters?

Comment: Are you assuming no wholly blank lines (just carriage returns)?  I feel like that is something that'd be legal and important, but would force people to do a few more null-checks.

Comment: Can you assume that at least one line is not a line comment?

Comment: @stanri Yes, there can be.

Comment: @SouthpawHare An empty line would violate the rule that there will always be at least 7 characters in a line. Empty lines do not have to be handled.

Comment: @betaveros You cannot.

Comment: Would it be OK to have the input as an array where the last entry is something like `NULL`, to indicate end of input? e.g. `char** program = { "000000 hello", "000001 world", NULL };`

Comment: @gurka Sure, that's OK.

Comment: @EJP So true. Those of us who actually used punched cards had a strange fondness for our COBOL compilers which strictly enforced the ascending line numbers.

Comment: Is the line number significant, since it defines the order of program lines in COBOL?

Comment: @Kwebble It is not significant.

Comment: Column 7 in addition to a space, could also contain not only * (asterix) a comment but also - (hyphen) indicating a continuation line and / (forward slash) form feed

Comment: @ClickRick Sure. I built one. Well it was an option.

Answer (score 112):

## COBOL (GnuCOBOL), 191 + 17 = 208 bytes

I "learned" COBOL for this answer, so it's probably not fully golfed.

This is a full program, taking input on what I presume to be standard input and writing to what I presume to be standard output. Perhaps one day I'll return to this and (1) determine whether COBOL has functions and, if so, (2) see whether a function solution would be shorter.

Byte count includes program and compiler flags (`-free` and `-frelax-syntax`).

```cobol
program-id.c.select i assign keyboard line sequential.fd i. 1 l pic X(80). 88 e value 0.open input i perform until e read i end set e to true end-read if not e and l(7:1)<>'*'display l(8:73).
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##NY/BboMwEETv/Yq5JaBiQVMpKKra38h1gYVYXWzXNlH4@VAD7R5Gmje7I21rGyvFYKZlcd4OnsZCd6pVgYXbCA0KQQ8G3zw3lnwH0YYR@GdiEzWJ6jtohQoCp1tcj3WZKdQ1GHeSiVEq69hAGzetdY59b/2IKV1LWvJMqQBsulQaE4gW0ae7RIo97GHsmlDakeP5UmUfn4f80OnghOaE6sv5lKllKbdBI3Tb5GXzVQ5yTjjs9g3Wkxk4fO3@lGNmur3@Y7XivHyH2DtjTL/aJH/hs@2FhrAUvWfeVOhRhNlEevwC)

### Ungolfed program

```cobol
program-id. c.

select i assign to keyboard organization line sequential.

fd i.
    1 l pic X(80).
    88 e value 0.

open input i
perform until e
    read i
        end set e to true
    end-read
    if not e and l(7:1) <> '*'
        display l(8:73).
```

### Limitations

The output is, technically speaking, not correct. From my cursory research, it seems the only practical way to store a string in COBOL is in a fixed-size buffer. I have chosen a buffer size of 80 characters, since this is the line length limit for fixed-format programs. This presents two limitations:

- Lines longer than 80 characters are truncated.
- Lines shorter than 80 characters are right-padded with spaces.

I'm guessing this is acceptable since, well, it's COBOL. If not, I'd be willing to look into alternatives.

### Acknowledgments

- -166 bytes thanks to Edward H
- -2 bytes thanks to *hornj*

Comment: _Asterisks (*) will never be found anywhere outside the first seven characters on a line_ ... and yet ... ;)

Comment: @Cœur Haha yes...but my solution doesn't use that assumption, so maybe it's appropriate!

Comment: You win one internet.

Comment: @Cœur except in a COMPUTE statement.

Comment: I think you can remove the `program-id. c.`.

Comment: @Kwebble Doesn't work in TIO with the current setup.

Comment: Congratulations on your gold badge!

Answer (score 22):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to LyricLy. -1 byte thanks to Mego.*

```python
lambda s:[i[7:]for i in s if'*'>i[6]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYlBCsIwFAWv8nbRUKRWUShUDxKz@MXEfkiTkBShp49Sa2cxi5k4T0PwTbHdozga@ycht4rVtdU2JDDYI4OtkOLG6qJ1iYn9BLtTol5A72hYJCr82lGCYnQmb6VBSORfJt@3dJKYDQ3V/xzWI@szXHgbjAY5fLV@offlAw)

I/O as lists of strings.

Comment: Save a byte by replacing `!=` with `<`, since a space's code point is lower than an asterisk's one, and the seventh character will always be a space or an asterisk.

Comment: So, the 7th character will always be a space or an asterisk?

Comment: Yes. `You may assume the seventh character is always an asterisk or a space.`

Comment: Save 1 byte with `if'*'!=i[6]`

Answer (score 13):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>19</s> + 1 (-p) = <s>20</s> 16 bytes

*-4 bytes with Pavel's suggestions*

```perl
s/.{6}( |.*)//s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX6/arFZDoUZPS1Nfv/j/fwMwUEjKScwAE1xgvqGWQmJBQU5qMYRrpJBflJiXnlpsD@EbaylUpiZm6MCE9UDCWgYmCjn5ZakKuakKxflAAir5L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhwX/dAgA)

Comment: You can save three bytes if you replace `(\*.*$| )` with `( |.*)`

Comment: Not as short as @Pavel's comment, but [`/ /;$_=/\* /?$,:$'`](https://tio.run/##NUtbCsIwEPzPKVYoFYJtUrVfIp7AGwiS6mKFNBuSKvTyrjWNOzDMaz0G2zIrUIfielypiwRVlsWaWacD471FkXQDnXEzxA0thgnu5F5jFHnYWdMnymO5vOZ@CxSMe2A8LX4nYULTb/5x/Yul3oOlN8KAEGmmXH7Ij09ykatzW@tGc@W/ "Perl 5 – Try It Online") is another alternative

Comment: You also don't need the `^`.

Answer (score 11):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
Î6x<<
çª/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3CfWYWNDdfh5YdW6af8/28ABgpJOYkZYIILzDfUUkgsKMhJLYZwjRTyixLz0lOL7SF8Yy2FytTEDB2YsB5IWMvARCEnvyxVITdVoTgfSEAlAQ)

#### Explanation

```
Î       ' On every line
  x     ' delete the first...
 6      ' 6 characters
   <<   ' and unindent the line (removes the leading space)
ç /     ' on every line
 ª      ' matching \*
   d    ' delete the line
```

Hexdump:

```
00000000: ce36 783c 3c0a e7aa 2f64                 .6x<<.../d
```

Comment: Couldn't you do `7x` instead of `6x<<`?

Comment: Then it deletes the `*`

Comment: Would it work to delete the lins with `*` first and then do `Î7x` ? (assuming a * can not not in the chars 0-5)

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 unfortunately no, because there can be a `*` in the first 6 characters.

Answer (score 9):

## [Paradoc](https://github.com/betaveros/paradoc) (v0.2.8+), 8 bytes (CP-1252)

```
µ6>(7#;x
```

Takes a list of lines, and results in a list of uncommented lines.

Explanation:

```
μ        .. Map the following block over each line (the block is terminated
         .. by }, but that doesn't exist, so it's until EOF)
 6>      .. Slice everything after the first six characters
   (     .. Uncons, so now the stack has the 6th character on top
         .. and the rest of the line second
    7#   .. Count the multiplicity of factors of 7 in the character
         .. (treated as an integer, so '*' is 42 and ' ' is 32)
      ;  .. Pop the top element of the stack (the rest of the line)...
       x .. ...that many times (so, don't pop if the 6th character was a
         .. space, and do pop if it was an asterisk)
```

Hi, I wrote a golfing programming language. :)

I'm still developing this and added/tweaked a bunch of built-ins after trying to write this so that there are more reasonable ways to differentiate between a space and an asterisk than "`7#`", but I feel like that would make this noncompeting. It's fortunate that it still worked out (this only uses features from v0.2.8, which I committed three days ago).

Comment: "Hi, I wrote a golfing programming language." Was the version you're using released before or after this challenge was posted?

Comment: It works on this version from three days ago: https://github.com/betaveros/paradoc/releases/tag/v0.2.8

Comment: Right, you mentioned that, but somehow it didn't register explicitly...

Comment: @Mast [It doesn't really matter.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/8478)

Answer (score 7):

## Octave, 23 bytes

```matlab
@(s)s(s(:,7)~=42,8:end)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNYs1ijWMNKx1yzztbESMfCKjUvRfN/mq1CYl6xNVexbTSXkgEYKCTlJGaACSWokKGWQmJBQU5qMUzASCG/KDEvPbXYHiZirKVQmZqYoQOT0INIaBmYKOTkl6Uq5KYqFOcDCai0Uqw1F1ca0E3/AQ)

Comment: I never knew Octave could do strings like that... Take that, MATLAB. xD

Comment: Since [R2016b's introduction of string arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/matlab-ex32410134-create-string-arrays), I'm pretty sure this would work in MATLAB too @Sanchises! I only have access to R2015b currently so can't confirm though. MATLAB can do it in 74 bytes, probably fewer `@(s)cellfun(@(r)r(8:end),s(cellfun(@(r)r(7)~=42,s)),'uniformoutput',false)`, where `s` is a cell array, not a string array. Using regexp or something would likely be shorter, but the method I've written is comparable to the methodology in this answer just for old MATLAB

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
ṫ€7Ḣ⁼¥Ðf⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hztXmKo@a1hza@nDHIttHjdsObT08Ie3/4fbI//@jlQzAQCEpJzEDTCjpQIQMtRQSCwpyUothAkYK@UWJeempxfYwEWMthcrUxAwdmIQeRELLwEQhJ78sVSE3VaE4H0hApZViAQ)

Inputs and outputs as a list of lines.

*-2 bytes thanks to @EriktheOutgolfer and @JonathanAllan*

**How it works**

```
ṫ€7Ḣ=¥Ðf⁶
 €           On each line:
ṫ 7            Replace the line with line[7:]
      Ðf     Keep all lines that meet condition:
     ¥         Dyad:
   Ḣ             First Element (modifies line)
    =            Equals
        ⁶    Space
```

Comment: `7$€` can be `€7`

Comment: take it down to 9 like so: `ṫ€7Ḣ⁼¥Ðf⁶`

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 32 bytes

```powershell
$input-replace'^.{6}( |.*)'-ne''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYnLCsIwEEX3fsUshGiwoT5w658Io1yMMCZDYiuifnu0ab2LA@dcjQ@k7CFSyvwatLs3CSp8hjm61/6zoLezS9MEGFNKW0cnYV8xq762xKqCPOqGYuJwQT6MvrX0BPvVP7sh23ZHEnvQDZTjD9P5BQ)

Pipeline input comes in as an array of strings, `-replace` works on every string, and `-ne ''` (not equal to empty string) applied to an array, acts to filter out the blank lines.

Answer (score 5):

## Vim, 14 bytes

<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>`G5ld:%g/\*/d`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Loading the input file as the buffer to edit, then enter the above commands. Output is the new buffer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 9 bytes

Note that this only works if at least 1 line is *not* a comment and at least 1 line *is* a comment. All the other solutions work in all cases.

*-2 bytes thanks to [@pizzakingme](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72796/pizzakingme)!*

```
m>d7.m@b6
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%3Ed7.m%40b6&input=%5B%22000000+blah+blah%22%2C+%22000001%2a+apples%22%2C+%22000002+oranges%3F%22%2C+%22000003%2a+yeah%2C+oranges.%22%2C+%22000%2a04+love+me+some+oranges%22%5D&debug=0)**

#### Explanation

```
m>d7.m@b6     - Full program with implicit input. Takes input as a list of Strings.

m>d7          - All but the first 7 letters of 
    .m   (Q)  - The input, filtered for its minimal value using the < operator on
      @b6     - the 7th character -- note that "*" is greater than " "
              - Implicitly Output the result.
```

---

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 11 bytes

```
tMfqhTdm>d6
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tMfqhTdm%3Ed6&input=%5B%22000000+blah+blah%22%2C+%22000001%2a+apples%22%2C+%22000002+oranges%3F%22%2C+%22000003%2a+yeah%2C+oranges.%22%2C+%22000%2a04+love+me+some+oranges%22%5D&debug=0)**

#### Explanation

```
tMfqhTdm>d6 - Full Program with implicit input. Takes input as a list of Strings.

       m>d6 - Remove the first 6 characters of each line.
    hT      - Get the first character of each.
  fq  d     - Keep those that have the first character an asterisk.
tM          - Remove the first character of each.
            - Output Implicitly.
```

---

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 11 bytes

```
m>d7fqd@T6Q
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%3Ed7fqd%40T6Q&input=%5B%22000000+blah+blah%22%2C+%22000001%2a+apples%22%2C+%22000002+oranges%3F%22%2C+%22000003%2a+yeah%2C+oranges.%22%2C+%22000%2a04+love+me+some+oranges%22%5D&debug=0)**

#### Explanation

```
m>d7fq@T6dQ  - Full program. Takes input as a list of Strings.

      @T6    - The sixth character of each.
    fq   dQ  - Keep the lines that have a space as ^.
m>d7         - Crop the first 7 characters.
             - Output implicitly.
```

---

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 12 bytes

```
tMfnhT\*m>d6
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tMfnhT%5C%2am%3Ed6&input=%5B%22000000+blah+blah%22%2C+%22000001%2a+apples%22%2C+%22000002+oranges%3F%22%2C+%22000003%2a+yeah%2C+oranges.%22%2C+%22000%2a04+love+me+some+oranges%22%5D&debug=0)**

#### Explanation

```
tMfnhT\*m>d6 - Full Program with implicit input. Takes input as a list of Strings.

        m>d6 - Remove the first 6 characters of each line.
    hT       - Get the first character of each.
  fn  \*     - Filter those that aren't equal to an asterisk.
tM           - Remove the first character of each.
             - Output Implicitly.
```

---

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 12 bytes

```
m>d7fn@T6\*Q
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%3Ed7fn%40T6%5C%2aQ&input=%5B%22000000+blah+blah%22%2C+%22000001%2a+apples%22%2C+%22000002+oranges%3F%22%2C+%22000003%2a+yeah%2C+oranges.%22%2C+%22000%2a04+love+me+some+oranges%22%5D&debug=0)**

#### Explanation

```
m>d7fn@T6\*Q  - Full program. Takes input as a list of Strings.

      @T6     - Get the sixth character of each string
    fn   \*Q  - And filter those that aren't equal to an asterisk.
m>d7          - Crop the first 7 characters.
              - Output implicitly.
```

Comment: "_Keep those that have the first character an asterisk._" I think you meant "Keep those of which the first character is NOT an asterisk."

Comment: `m>d7.m@b6` should work at 9 bytes, abusing that `*` is after space in lexicographical order

Comment: I can edit it in with explanation / test link if you want!

Comment: @pizzakingme I'd be glad if you would edit in, because I am on mobile. Thanks a lot and don't forget to credit yourself for the new solution!

Comment: Does this work if all lines are line comments? (I'm not sure if you have to handle this case)

Comment: @betaveros All the solutions except for the 9-byter work in that case. I will add the remark.

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>63</s> <s>59</s> <s>55</s> <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes

Thanks to "*an anonymous user*" for getting rid off yet another byte.

Thanks to [Felix Palmen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71420/felix-palmen) for reminding me of "*You may assume the seventh character is always an asterisk or a space.*", which shaved off one more byte.

```
f(char**a){for(;*a;++a)(*a)[6]&2||puts(*a+7);}
```

Use like:

```
char** program = { "000000 apple", "000001 banana", "celery donuts", 0 };
f(program);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDbCoMwDIav9SmCF6OtbrgD24WMPYh4Ebt6AG1F3UDUZ3ddnSIshaT5kv4N4fuU82lKCM@wZgxpn6iaBAwD10VKNAiv0e40DNWrbXTq3mgwTrlsocRcEmr3tmWeAoYR3EGnluMbA6yqQjjeSo4Qo9RnRlwUou7gqaRWNsi3rTFY5OI/ubjAzLitJJt/aTbsBKpGmYrmsYFnBp3AzFtqh7XG/AsU6i2gFNAo7X4dm5FsKyFI9WhmCY7zvSYk1mGcPg)

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZDbCoMwDIav9SmCF6OtbrgD24WMPYh4Ebt6AG1F3UDUZ3ddnSIsgTT9kv4N4fuU82lKCM@wZgxpn6iaBAwD10V6DRlGu9MwVK@2IQzdGw3GKZctlJhLQu3etsxDwDCCO@ir5fjGAKuqEI63kiPEKLXPiItC1B08ldTKBvm2NQaLXPwnFxeYmbCVZPMvzYadQNUoU9E8NvDMoBOYeUvtsNaYf4FCvQWUAhqlw69jM5JtJQSpHs0swXG@aUJifYzTBw)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>53</strike> <strike>48</strike> 46 bytes

```c
x;main(y){for(y=&x;gets(y-6);x&2||puts(y+1));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYnBDoIwEAXvfsWeSFvFABoujfFb1mYtJoU2VEgb8durFH2HSWaeKrVSKQXZ42Ngkb/udmTxUgSp6elZLFsuQ9Esi5tW3decy3dKVR7cDHYZu@y1AHTOkN@0ATvioMlfNz8JiITd4Z@PaxbVGYydCXoCb7/4nR8)

*-5 bytes:* It was very tricky to get this "*whole program*" down to the same size as [gurka's function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140346/71420). It's now writing out of bounds (in both directions) of an array of wrong type and relies on *little endian* and *4 byte integers* to find the asterisk ... but hey, it works ;)

*-2 bytes:* Well, if we already write to some "random" `.bss` location, why bother declaring an *array* at all! So here comes the string handling program that uses *neither* the `char` type *nor* an array.

Comment: Nice! And the `*x&2` made me remember "You may assume the seventh character is always an asterisk or a space.", so I should be able to shave some bytes off my answer :-)

Comment: @gurka thanks :D -2, hehe

Answer (score 4):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>72</s> <s>70</s> <s>66</s> 50 bytes

```
R	INPUT POS(6) (' '  REM . OUTPUT | '*') :S(R)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYndCoIwAEav8ym@u80RYiVddBOVi6z8YeoDTBh5sZw0CILefaXWd3HgnM92pjE6ck7MkqyoKxR5Sdc@KAEBBE8RIK@r4XmDMOJjU1LhezyLnQvHodGyHeGNvmCQfa@VnXQJ85DdTdnt5CuGl5Lt/J@DIbMwgjZPhbuCNV/8Tm@3P8T8iFNyvlzTDw)

Pattern matching in SNOBOL is quite different from regex but the idea here is still the same: If a line matches "six characters and then an asterisk", remove it, otherwise, remove the first seven characters of the line and print the result.

This now actually takes better advantage of SNOBOL's conditional assignment operator.

The pattern is `POS(6) (' ' REM . OUTPUT | '*')` which is interpreted as:

Starting at position 6, match a space or an asterisk, and if you match a space, assign the rest of the line to `OUTPUT`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>39</s> <s>38</s> <s>36</s> <s>29</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 20 + 1 = 21 bytes

```ruby
$_[/.{6}( |.*
)/]=''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyU@Wl@v2qxWQ6FGT4tLUz/WVl39/38DMFBIyknMABNcYL6hlkJiQUFOajGEa6SQX5SYl55abA/hG2spVKYmZujAhPVAwloGJgo5@WWpCrmpCsX5QAIq@S@/oCQzP6/4v24BAA)

Uses `-p` flag.

Explanation:

The `-p` flag adds an implicit block around the code, so the code that actually gets run looks like this:

```ruby
while gets
    $_[/.{6}( |.*
)/]=''

    puts $_
end
```

`gets` reads a line of text and stores its result in `$_`.

`$_[/.../]=''` removes the first occurence of the regex `...` in `$_`.

`/.{6}( |.*\n)/` matches 6 of any character at the start of a line, followed by either a space or the rest of the line. Because the space appears first, it will try to remove only the first 6 characters and a space before attempting to remove the entire line.

`$_` is then printed out, and this process is repeated for each line.

Comment: Method calls in Ruby don't need parentheses, removing them will save you a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 13 bytes

```
⌠6@tp' =*⌡M;░
```

Input and output is done as a list of strings.

Explanation:

```
⌠6@tp' =*⌡M;░
⌠6@tp' =*⌡M    for each line:
 6@t             discard the first 6 characters
    p            pop the first character of the remainder
     ' =         is it a space?
        *        multiply the string by the boolean - returns the string if true, and an empty string if false
           ;░  filter out empty strings
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8//9RzwIzh5ICdQVbrUc9C32tH02b@P9/tJIBGCgk5SRmgAklHYiQoZZCYkFBTmoxTMBIIb8oMS89tdgeJmKspVCZmpihA5PQg0hoGZgo5OSXpSrkpioU5wMJqLRSLAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 9 bytes

```
6>¦'*«⁈ḥ¦
```

A function accepting a list of strings and returning a list of strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/38zu0DJ1rUOrHzV2PNyx9NCy/6mP2ib@j37UMMcADBSSchIzwMSjhrkKMGFDLYXEgoKc1GJkQSOF/KLEvPTUYntkUWMthcrUxAwdmKQeQlLLwEQhJ78sVSE3VaE4H0hAlQBVxAIA)

#### Explanation

```
6>¦        Remove the first 6 characters of each string
   '*«⁈    Filter out ones that start with *
       ḥ¦  Remove the initial space from each
```

Comment: I count ten characters, and since three are non-ASCII, do they not take more than a byte?

Comment: @WGroleau `⁈` and `«` are both 1 character. Out golfing languages that use non-ascii character (maybe except for Neim) use custom encodings, that allow all those non-ASCIIs to be counted as single bytes. Here is [Gaia's code page](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia/blob/master/codepage.md).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Neim has an encoding too.

Answer (score 3):

### R, <strike>47</strike> 45 bytes

```
function(x)gsub("(?m)^.{6}( |.*\\n)","",x,,T)
```

Comment: If you take the input as a list of strings I think you can shorten the regex to "^.{6}( |.*$)" for -6.

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar Correct. In this case, I could also drop the `pe=T` argument. However, I am not sure whether input as a list of strings is allowed.

Comment: From the OP: `Input or output may be a matrix or list.`

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar The problem is the presence of empty strings in the output.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Ah of course, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

Laikoni's version is shorter than mine:

```hs
f n=[x|' ':x<-drop 6<$>n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYlNCoMwFAav8hEEIVixP3RRtB5EXLzSZyONSUiKWOjd06LNLGYxoyg8WesYB5imWz458stS7@7eOpzr7Gr6ONFo0MD50byQYehEtYKbJrVKFFvaS5BzmkMKB1hP5sGhTeUo8WZSRRrlNmR1grYzY2IE@9N/iz5@AQ)

My version:

```hs
f n=[drop 7x|x<-n,x!!6<'*']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYlNCsIwFAav8jUIhRCl/mA3LR6kdPHEV1tMk5CIRPDuUVozi1nMjBQerHVKA0zb3bx1qOMnNlujYlGcm1KWfZppMmjh/GSe2GDoRLWAq6ZxkVBr2kuQc5pDDgdYT@bO4ZLLUeLNNKo8duuQ1QnavhgzI9if/lv06Qs)

Comment: 25 bytes: `f n=[x|' ':x<-drop 6<$>n]`.

Comment: @Laikoni That's nice!! I didn't know it was possible to match patterns in a generator of a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 40 bytes

Regular expressions: just about, but not quite, the wrong tool for the job. Lambda from `String` to `String` (assign to `Function<String, String>`). Input must have a trailing newline.

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(?m)^.{6}( |.*\\n)","")
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##ZVFNb8IwDD3TX2H1lFQQsQ9xYYCmTbvtxHHdJFMMhKVO1aTdGOO3d6Etmqbl4K/nZ78ke6xxZAvi/fq9KaqV0RlkBp2DZ9QMx2hQlLpGT@A8@gBuNKOBfaCpymujNhVnXltWT31wt/Sl5u0QOj@HULd5Tuwf7MoamDVuNHeqpMJgRvfGiFgscvmmjpOTgG@VpCnLeBjHshlMo7C/E9Wvr61eQx6kiW78yyugDCoHv4qWGTJTCa73M2D6gH@4WB6cp1xpltPA77tV5eiRjM61Dy1xmn7FLdw328qr8CDsxd9bKSwKcxCXIUyfXkh5Zp6iUzNuD6wM7loTtflVAmcWuS69Blsib8ktuvwmgQPhbngpq3M5Gd@CsTVBHj7EBtOD0Q8)

### Acknowledgments

- -3 bytes thanks to [Sven Hohenstein's regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140316)

Comment: The right tool! :)

Answer (score 3):

## GNU Sed, 19 + 2 = 21 characters

Requires `-E` argument to `sed` to enable extended regular expressions.

```
/^.{6}\*/d;s/^.{7}/
```

Comment: you could do the same thing as the perl guy, `s/^.{6}( |.*)//g`

Comment: which version of sed ignores absense of replacement substring for s command?

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 23 bytes

- 23 bytes assuming [SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS). In UTF-8 it'll be **42 bytes**

This is my first ever attempt at a code golf challenge, feel free to improve, i'm sure i could have saved one or two characters if i wasn't so adamant on making this code *'tacit'*

This assumes the input is a list of lines and return a list of uncommented lines, this makes everything a bit easier since APL was explicitly made to work on list!

```
(('*'≠7∘⌷)⊢⍤/(8≤⍳8)∘⊂)¨
```

Go ahead and [try it!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=09BQ11J/1LnA/FHHjEc92zUfdS161LtEX8PiUeeSR72bLTRB4l1NmodWAAA&f=S1NQNwADhaScxAwwoQ4VMtRSSCwoyEkthgkYKeQXJealpxbbw0SMtRQqUxMzdGASehAJLQMThZz8slSF3FSF4nwgAZVWBwA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f#) (Thanks @Sʨɠɠan)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! It's typically allowed to take I/O how you did; see [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/79857)

Comment: You can count it as 23 bytes, as there's an SBCS (single-byte character set) to cover the set of characters: https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS

Comment: Here's a link so others can test your code: [try it online!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=09BQ11J/1LnA/FHHjEc92zUfdS161LtEX8PiUeeSR72bLTRB4l1NmodWAAA&f=S1NQNwADhaScxAwwoQ4VMtRSSCwoyEkthgkYKeQXJealpxbbw0SMtRQqUxMzdGASehAJLQMThZz8slSF3FSF4nwgAZVWBwA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f#)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>44</s> 34 bytes

<sup>*[Crossed-out 44 is still regular 44.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139375/generate-every-ascii-string/139382#139382)*</sup>

*6 bytes saved thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)*

```
a=>a.replace(/^.{6}( |.*\n)/gm,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYnLDoIwEEX3fsXsaBss@Igbg/6IMYx1KJrSaaghMeq3VwW9i5Occ684YDT9Jdzmns@UmiphtUPdU3BoSBRH/di8BDy1OnhZ2C7PMpkM@8iOtGMrGlGX4@DksB0xG32hAENwFCddAvfoLcX95CsFd8I2/2f9zapcg@OBoCOI/MHvrKXcpjc)

Comment: `s=>s.replace(/^.{6}( |\*.*\s)?/mg,'')`

Comment: `s.match(/(?<=^.{6} ).*/mg)` [ESNext (Nonstandard, Stage3) Chrome62+](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/)

Comment: @tsh. Until there is a stable interpreter which allows it, I suppose it doesn't count as a valid programming language.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this gives the correct output if the last line is a comment line.

Comment: @LyricLy. It is because I assumed that input will always contain a trailing new line. You can see that it [works](https://tio.run/##NYnLCsIwEEX3/YrZNQk1rQ9wIbU/ItKxTh@SZkIiBRG/PWqrd3HgnHvDCUPjB3dfWb5SbMuI5RG1J2ewIZGf9XP/EqDVycoq78YsTWVs2AY2pA13ohV1MQ8uBvsZyexrBeicobDoBtij7ShUi28VPAj77J/1N6tip8DwRDASBP7g9ya1lIf4Bg) is there is an empty line after the input. If I should not assume it, then fix will cost 1 byte (adding `?` after `\n`).

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Yes, assuming a trailing newline on the input is fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>23</s> 15 bytes

*5 bytes saved thanks to [nmjcman101](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62346/nmjcman101)

1 byte saved thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

```
m`^.{6}( |.*¶)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/NyFOr9qsVkOhRk/r0DZNrv//DcBAISknMQNMcIH5hloKiQUFOanFEK6RQn5RYl56arE9hG@spVCZmpihAxPWAwlrGZgo5OSXpSrkpioU5wMJqCQXAA)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>160 145 90</s> 89 bytes

```
t=>{var o="";foreach(var s in i.Split('\n'))if(s[6]!=42)o+=s.Substring(7)+"\n";return o;}
```

Thanks to Pavel & auhmaan for reducing the size.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I would suggest adding a [try it online](https://tio.run/#cs-core) link to your answer so that others can test your code. Besides that, great first (well, second) answer!

Comment: You can make this shorter by writing a lambda in the form `t=>{...}`

Comment: @LyricLy I tried doing that, actually, but for some reason, this doesn't work there. It works perfectly fine in a VS console app, though.

Comment: @Pavel Like so? I'm not sure if I did it completely correctly; I've never needed to use a lambda expression before.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can test it by assigning it to a `func<string, string>`.

Comment: You can make it 90 bytes long: `i=>{var o="";foreach(var l in i.Split('\n'))if(l[6]!=42)o+=l.Substring(7)+"\n";return o;};`

Comment: Why is there a trailing semicolon outside the lambda body?  This is not a statement.  It can only possibly be an expression.

Comment: `delegate string y;y s=[my code...]` This requires a semicolon after it and that is how I tested it. The semicolon is a remnant of testing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 9 bytes

```
36 4C 3E 23 64 DE 29 6D 74
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=36+4C+3E+23+64+DE+29+6D+74&input=%22000323%2a+this+is+a+comment%22%2C%22000000+apple%22%2C%22000323%2a+this+is+a+comment%22%2C%22000001+banana%22%2C%22celery+donuts%22&warnings=1&hex=1)

Readable:

```
6L>#d.^)mt
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=6L%3E%23d.%5E%29mt&input=%22000323%2a+this+is+a+comment%22%2C%22000000+apple%22%2C%22000323%2a+this+is+a+comment%22%2C%22000001+banana%22%2C%22celery+donuts%22&warnings=1&hex=0)

```
6L>        -   [i[6:] for i in input]
   #d.^)   -  filter(i.startswith(" ") for  i in ^)
        mt - [i[-1:] for i in ^]
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

```
s=>s.map(c=>c[6]<"*"?console.log(c.substr(7)):1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BDoIwFET3nuKnq7bRBtRoohYOIi5KbQRT2oZfCXL5qgRn8ZJ5s5inGhTqvg1x4/zdJGsijCCBZHOgtqqZUblZ5BxUCNbg0rfge@UeBstF7Di8jWrWfy9mz7M9WD8Y6Ayg/2JZyXn1e5xkQlmg6FSgWhb6erhdCCel9g69NcL6B9UCXzXGnh4ZO@UsTXQUGGwbKakcYSx9AA)

Comment: This is neither a function, nor a full program as it assumes the input is stored in `z`, which isn't allowed here. You could however turn it into an anonymous arrow function, in order to make it valid.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing you're absolutely right. Updated the solution - not sure what the rules are regarding the `(` and `)` surrounding the fn, added them to be sure.

Comment: You don't need the `()` around the function, but otherwise it looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, <s>57</s> 53 Bytes

```
>i~i~i~i~i~i~i67*=\
<o$/?:$/?=a:;?(0:i<
\~$/~\ $
/  <o\?/
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3y6zDgmamWvZxnDZ5Kvo21sBsW2ilbW9hoFVpg1XTJ2Kfl2MggqXvoKCTX6Mvf7//wZgoJCUk5gBJrjAfEMthcSCgpzUYgjXSCG/KDEvPbXYHsI31lKoTE3M0IEJ64GEtQxMFHLyy1IVclMVivOBBFQSAA)

### Explanation

```
>i~i~i~i~i~i~i67*=    Read in the first seven bytes of the line
 i~i~i~i~i~i~         Read, and discard 6 characters
             i        Read the seventh
              67*=    Check if the seventh character was an 
                      asterisk (and leave that value on the stack );

<o$/?:$/?=a:;?(0:i<    Read characters until a newline or eof
                 i     Read the next character of the line
            ;?(0:      If it's a -1, terminate the program
       /?=a:           If it's a newline, break out of the loop
   /?:$                If the seventh character was not an asterisk
<o$                    Output this character
\~$/                   otherwise discard it

   /~\ $    Having reached the end of the line, output
/  <o\?/    the newline only if it was not a comment
```

## Edit: 53 bytes

```
>   i~i~i~i~i~i~i67*=\
/?=a<o/?$@:$@:$;?(0:i<
~   \~/
```

Basically the same stuff as before, but restructured slightly

<s>As a side note: I'm disappointed no-one's done this in cobol yet.</s>

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 62 bytes (no regex)

```python
def f(s):
 for w in s.split('\n'):
  if w[6]!='*':print(t[7:])
```

It works!

```python
>>> s="""000000 blah blah
000001* apples
000002 oranges?
000003* yeah, oranges.
000*04 love me some oranges"""
>>> f(s)
blah blah
oranges?
love me some oranges
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/) (builtins only), 35 bytes

```pascal
for l ("${(f)$(<p)}")<<<${l:7$l[7]}
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##NYnLCsIwEEX3/YpLCTQJIvUBBQn6IeIiytQsRic0IGjpt0dN9S4OnHNfKWS6BEHTluHMPhRUxVcWPkamNOsaMvj7ldJh9o3Fk3xY/PPym227BcuDcCMk@eB3Ntgj5l4GMHStRt0bpV00U22cc2rkXaf42J2mnKs3)

Scans file `p` per [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41212803/148889).
Other solutions: <s>[45 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYlNCsIwGAX3PcWjDbQJYusPLkLQhbcQN1G@mkU0oQFBS84ea6pvMTDz3sEkuhqHusvDxWqTUWRfCWjvLYVZ13CDftwoHGbfCLxIm8U/L79ZdFtY9yTcCcFN@J019vCpdwMsmpKNTc9ZozyPJVdKTX6SR8nZaOUuttVZtFVMqfgA)</s>, <s>[27b (illegal)](https://tio.run/##NYnRCoIwGEbv9xQfKKIjQ00QatCDRBeL/TRhbeKiqPDZl876Lg6c8729Dk/dG8JIUsH0lg5Qjnm6oyyRLiHkeZKkn/rUnSfRNkWRZUKIOey7KShniYUqDhcjdQSLXnPIYTDkV23gRmmv5I@r7zheJPXmn7dL5lUL4x6EG8G7Gb@TfQE)</s>

Comment: Aren't you supposed to input EVERY line of COBOL program, not a line of?

Comment: Ah, good point... will need to work on it again!

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 11 bytes + 3 bytes option `-nr` = 14 bytes.

```
s/^.{6} //p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/Tq/arFZBX7/g/38DMFBIyknMABNcYL6hlkJiQUFOajGEa6SQX5SYl55abA/hG2spVKYmZujAhPVAwloGJgo5@WWpCrmpCsX5QAIq@S@/oCQzP6/4v25eEQA)

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 16 bytes

```
#n
s/^.\{6\} //p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/XzmPq1g/Ti@m2iymVkFfv@D/fwMwUEjKScwAE1xgvqGWQmJBQU5qMYRrpJBflJiXnlpsD@EbaylUpiZm6MCE9UDCWgYmCjn5ZakKuakKxflAAioJAA)

`#n` on top of line is for `-n`, which is <s>GNU-extension</s> [POSIX-compatible](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

Answer (score 2):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL), 116 bytes.

```
DO;1<-#6DO,1<-#999DOCOMEFROM.1DOWRITEIN;1+,1(91)DO.1<-,1SUB#2(1)DO.2<-.1~#1DDOCOMEFROM.2DO,1SUB#3<-#0(95)DOREADOUT,1
```

[Try it online, although you need to copy and paste!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

### Assumption

- Each line should have <=80 characters except trailing newline character(s), although this program can handle up to 339 characters per line (or more, depending on what kind of characters are used).
- Does not matter whether input has trailing newline or not.

### Explaination

```
DONOTE stores first six characters of line
DO;1<-#6
DONOTE stores rest of characters of line except trailing newline
DO,1<-#999
DONOTE label one
DOCOMEFROM.1
DOWRITEIN;1+,1
DONOTE goto label one if tail one is asterisk
DONOTE first two items of tail one shall be
DONOTE 91 and 95 if space, or
DONOTE 91 and 95 if asterisk
(91)DO.1<-,1SUB#2
DONOTE goto label two if line is not empty
DONOTE obtw every item of tail will be zero
DONOTE if empty line
(1)DO.2<-.1~#1
DONOTE die here
D
DONOTE label two
DOCOMEFROM.2
DONOTE erase the space
DONOTE obtw zeros on tail are ignored
DONOTE when reading out
DONOTE see source code for more info
DO,1SUB#3<-#0
DONOTE goto label 1 after reading out
(95)DOREADOUT,1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 42 + 1 = 43 bytes

Filename must be `x`; it is for extra one byte.

```bash
read x||>x
((1${x:6:1}1))||echo ${x:7}
. x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYrJDoJAEETvfEWZcGBRAmg0gYjx5tGDPzBgxzEBhrCYNsK3jyzah0q9V52KRupWdZnEKs5koe7oXB57K545NqUbwvQTjokpQzo@gw3iStUtrufb5ahrEndw3ydsWFZgfjjaR8EQ2HbfUyYVJnMYDA@stT8f0lzIOYyZAweiqnJqFgyhalE@qDktvHXwJiHXf@1N2vF3yNWLUBAaNcZv/AI)

### Usage

- Input from stdin.
- Optional trailing LFs.
- Output to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), <sup>34</sup> <sup>24</sup> 15 bytes

```
sub(/^.{6} /,_)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704sTx7wYKlpSVpuhbri0uTNPTj9KrNahX0deI1IaJQyQU3kwzAQCEpJzEDTHCB-YZaCokFBTmpxRCukUJ-UWJeemqxPYRvrKVQmZqYoQMT1gMJaxmYKOTkl6Uq5KYqFOcDCagkxCoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ethproductions/japt/), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

Takes input as an array of strings and outputs an array of strings.

```
k_g6 x
®t7
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=a19nNiB4Cq50Nw==&input=WyIwMDAwMDAgYmxhaCBibGFoIiwiMDAwMDAxKiBhcHBsZXMiLCIwMDAwMDIgb3Jhbmdlcz8iLCIwMDAwMDMqIHllYWgsIG9yYW5nZXMuIiwiMDAwKjA0IGxvdmUgbWUgc29tZSBvcmFuZ2VzIl0KLVI=) (`-R` flag for visualisation purposes only)

- Saved a byte thanks to ETH.

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of array `U`.

```
f_
```

Filter (`f`) by passing each element through a function.

```
g6
```

Get the character at index (`g`) 6 (0-indexed).

```
x
```

Trim, giving either `*` (truthy) or an empty string (falsey).

```
®t7
```

Map (`®`) over the array and get the substring (`t`) of each element from the 7th character. Implicitly output the resulting array.

Comment: think the first line can be `k_g6 x`

Comment: @ETHproductions: Today was not a good day's golfing for me - I was playing around with solutions using `x`, as seen in my alt. solution, and I still didn't twig that! Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
|ʒ6èðQ}ε7F¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5tQks8MrDm8IrD231dzt0LL/tQig@d8ADBSSchIzwAQXmG@opZBYUJCTWgzhGinkFyXmpacW20P4xloKlamJGTowYT2QsJaBiUJOflmqQm6qQnE@kIBKAgA)

Comment: 10 bytes: [|ε6.$ćðQi,](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/5txWMz2VI@2HNwRm6vz/bwAGCkk5iRlgggvMN9RSSCwoyEkthnCNFPKLEvPSU4vtIXxjLYXK1MQMHZiwHkhYy8BEISe/LFUhN1WhOB9IQCX/6@rm5evmJFZVAgA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @Grimy Heh, `.$` didn't exist back then. :P

Answer (score 1):

## C++ (GCC), <s>121</s> 112 bytes

*Thanks to @gurka for saving 9 bytes!*

```
#import<bits/stdc++.h>
void f(std::list<std::string>l){for(auto s:l)if(s[6]-42)std::cout<<s.substr(7,s.size());}
```

Takes input as a list of lines.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5va4MwEMbf@ykO9yax1nVd2UCl@yDbXsQYNRCTkIuFTvzsLsSVlt3B8fC75/5wa/c95@v6JEdrnK8b6fEZfct3u2I4JxcjW@hIAGWpJPo6KvRO6v6s6NwZR9jkDWCpqAzGz7fv/elIo42bydc1Fjg1YYK850HKH0EorZZVag8jk5rQZE4gREfm9BADmLVKfOk038ALNEyHjIQLJdwVWqMnj4EstHo4lgZS/V/XKDbE8rAy247gHR3BOKZ7gR939prBVbAhv7WKWys7nECZi4BRAJpQ/gzbQ8my/gI)

Comment: `#import`? Also, I think that it's OK to omit standard includes.

Comment: `#import` isn't standard C++, but at least GCC and MSVC support it. Omitting some includes works with C, but not with C++. The code doesn't work without the includes, so they have to be counted in the total bytecount.

Comment: Aha, I thought you could just skip includes since you don't see any `import` in python answers or `using` in C# answers. Also, wouldn't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` be shorter for your answer?

Comment: @gurka Yes, it would be shorter. Thanks!

Comment: @gurka the imports *are* counted in Python answers, it's just that Python has a lot of functions that don't need importing. C# tends to not have using statement because it's generally shorter to write `system.foo()` than `using system;foo()`

Comment: `bits/stdc++.h` is not a standard header and thus is not "C++". You must specify a compiler and/or standard library implementation.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>95</s> <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```java
s->s.filter(x->x.charAt(6)<33).map(x->x.substring(7))
```

-42 bytes thanks to *@OliverGrégoire*, by using a `Stream<String>` instead of `String` as in- and output.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lVFNc8IgEL37K7Y5gaOMtZ32YLXj9FwvPbY9bBCVlEAGiDXTyW9PMcRpx4@DEGCy7@1j35LhFoemEDpbfjUyL4z1kIUYK71UzHkrMGcvRinBvbFu0rvEeWuPM/jcWqxCYo8rdA5eUeqfHoDUXtgVcgGL/S9AFHgKh9TrGXByFHB0Enh1WOFzHr3ksAANU2jccObYSqqgSHbD2Y7xDdq5Jw/0Zno/pizHIsZdmbpWjjxS2kyiVlGmKmh1klsjl5CHIkm8@P0TkHYVVs6LnJnSsyJAXmmiGSfRYNcHosU3HDJj2n4ko3YAFoUSyeAofgsp6jD/A1woYStYGl16l3TxmlLG42OQv0dhmZF6byr50AmlbZ/OVnsZudZHqnDTbqde@tGkO0HGYCzqtXDPJ9BdHyqBm8GBwY4Y/dE9KLMVkAtwJmwd7/q@1L26@QU)

```java
s->                          // Method with Stream<String> as parameter and return-type
  s.filter(x->x.charAt(6)<33)//  Filter out all lines containing an asterisk as 7th char
   .map(x->x.substring(7))   //  And remove the first 7 characters from the remaining lines
                             // End of method (implicit / single-line body)
```

Comment: Looks like you can use a `String[]` or `List<String>` as input for -12 bytes.

Comment: Or `Stream<String>` if that can help. Example : `s->s.map(x->x.charAt(6)!=42?x.substring(7):"")`

Comment: Oh, it's needed to filter... then `s->s.filter(x->x.charAt(6)!=42).map(x->x.substring(7))` for 54 bytes.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Could you provide a TIO regarding the input? `java.util.Arrays(the_string_array).stream()` it should be, right?

Comment: `java.util.Arrays.stream(yourStringWithNewLines.split("\n"))`

Comment: Okay, you're aware of this, you're likely making the changes right now. I'll leave soon, so I can +1 before I forget. ;)

Comment: Use `<42` instead of `!=42` because "You may assume the seventh character is always an asterisk or a space."

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, missed that rule, otherwise I would have done so myself. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

## TeX - 139 bytes

```
\let~\def~\a#1#2#3#4#5#6{\b}~\d#1{\catcode`#1=12}\obeylines\d\ ~\b#1#2
{\if#1*\else\write1{#2}\fi\egroup
}\everypar{\bgroup\d\\\d\{\d\}\a}
```

Eats up the first six characters of each line, then checks if the next one is an asterisk or something else. Recurses over lines by eating up anything that tries to get typeset. The rest of my bytes are spent on changing category codes of syntax related characters so it's robust.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 37 bytes

Regexp-based solution

```
s=>s.replace(/^.{6}( |(\*.+$\n?))/gm,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 24 bytes

```
select(.[6:]<"*")|.[7:]
```

Explanation

```
  select(.[6:] < "*")          # discard if '*' in column 7
| .[7:]                        # keep remaining portion
```

Sample run with `paste` to show input vs output

```
$ paste input <(jq -MRr 'select(.[6:]<"*")|.[7:]' input)
000000 blah blah                blah blah            
000001* apples                  oranges?                    
000002 oranges?                 love me some oranges 
000003* yeah, oranges.          
000*04 love me some oranges

$ wc -c <<<'select(.[6:]<"*")|.[7:]'
      24
```

[Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/qJLbZnr8qi)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell), 26 bytes

```sh
cut -c7-|grep ^\ |cut -c2-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvj/P7m0REE32Vy3Jr0otUAhLkahBiJipPv/vwEYKCTlJGaACS4w31BLIbGgICe1GMI1UsgvSsxLTy22h/CNtRQqUxMzdGDCeiBhLQMThZz8slSF3FSF4nwgAZUEAA)

---

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell), 29 bytes

```sh
cut -c7-|grep -vF \*|cut -c2-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvj/P7m0REE32Vy3Jr0otUBBt8xNIUarBiJopPv/vwEYKCTlJGaACS4w31BLIbGgICe1GMI1UsgvSsxLTy22h/CNtRQqUxMzdGDCeiBhLQMThZz8slSF3FSF4nwgAZUEAA)

OBTW it's POSIX-compatible, if I remember the specs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 88 bytes (filename) + 0 bytes (content) = 88 bytes, with non-printable characters.

- Filename (some unprintables are escaped): `\001.t.i.m.+.w.i.s.i.s.i.s.i.s.i.s.i*.zAB.z.i.c.o\n.a\002.tXX.a.m\002.zAB.i\n.z.i\n.aXX.a\001.t.i.m.+.a`
- Content: empty.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5VjtU9w2E/9@f8UCJXcHh4A8nefDPVwgbWlLp2meIelMZ9KMR2fr7lRsy5VkjoPwt6crS7blFwjpNJ/KDD57X367Wkm7K8l8vvm4AzGfH8rshiWHStPwisj5IBFRHjO4/D9SBwBhTJWCN4YLJ/BSSrpBKkDEFsBTrjmN@S0b7VG5VBN4No9FeDUuJABUnjH5AIsnWcyCcMXCq9GeYvHCclgaDSr8LFerp6gbiU/abCDnqVrxhf4y4CcnXwb33fvZl4kzTxWT@stgJzTb@qeRM8mvqWaVjYcDa94Jo@EKIgEf8OuDYwDwBYy2kEK4CugpXKSaLZkcV3wASbliuOSXecJSfS6lkCRlaxiWJEhypWHOSuVhpWwcbb7ZX/MsBuFvPY7aMpMMn2YDSvZnziWDoQppuhgO@nfkRa1U4FOtZUDDkCklJEwx7BlPlzVLMhoxiV/TYqdPYKpZkg369rLTnd3dl9E4cySYGVmaxzpwlNGYJEwuK6XWCtiB1xlLgaYRsBsW5poBBTMOWPC4nkCBQiNDmUDh3awY63RapB0T8wkYb2cpj0uXZJ6OvkcNMqeKpTRhhf54AgWxAhwTM3AHa1E6Lp43PQtFVHtmzBgcYwFRRC5DNhsOn@7nWa19ZtXNi/XmzAhjTEuRYqUG841mRIuAlvYa3jvYeb5YMIkQYS5xwieACEu9QrCuS0eT2gti5QYOZr1COowcCiZ4y653QbiiEkEr/XdO9H0lsQPfnX/z6w/w4/nluUd88/a788tLkuVawfbOnVO7n8LOncG8n7gXEq7k/XalWHqyP4PjxlZtuwjPnsHX/4XZzLqIX8Y946pbie@6PhtbJBLrNMQ1897f6r63RuUBlo06@UPwdLQ92fYR7JwSW7KsnM@2lJ7p8WSCAFdyFAQj40EDuy8oLFasY4CUhc0EZfxAOip3ENO5TJ3j3cTd2uhO6c6b4ovD19XXMBvC7AUMRa4xUgGN4@GkZgqf6TPShlaaJz6TWyZPW0qBR3c6/sKrhlMIh1Y4FNnGx1CWrFdSrAO6pg3mtWVKds2kYk14k14wRWD2TbWqVRalCo0Cs@58OGZ5LMklVq0m3CWtpgYlpUNBYlPsZyGyWmxtxda@kRtLu/FpG0trjO3W0m59GrU02rT5FrONkFRusIoyWktrFzoRmHzk4ySWs5AiKXl@mhCQCr2q1xJqRFbjWvDWgF9RTFKV2L5zMIqwSInUt3lgWSqfa0nDNnfLchNcyDyLeUjbAl9ZgT9zoTnOqM/aLZFlFueq4tz3dSKukpBsWte0aic0cq0l/6/RF5Taoq3tNPEtrBKMyLB7jbHMlxQMtN6cdsDSjiu4VUpAiT2Hh9hR5lOvMagdUTriKSYxzIkXv5Al0@Ggm/2s0KkVJkJGMIWD407VJUHLhudfI5kWbdBouBsNx12QsAYxW7xH371j06S76qpWr1NBC6QnPNe1mksSTR1H3OooLnxFlyr6xuxahVZDUOJ2x8FqXJdm@lDDWKSMmJbGa0UaPQkpRHriLD3H65Tlo4@Kfh72vLiNjde8C7auwcr690eOnVDRkjdWtanrR6bIe6AduJsa7qYN9xxOKmWFza0B9HbSi8eRNzXy5jORTx5Hvq2Rbz8T@fFo/GRQFkKuKW48LXBXSMlUJtLIHFgIrcwac85yKHLk1c2F6woLMklFesukOB1/ukez/Vi37/J7GSP3zpQuU6pMacJS9J7wNIzziJ12lfePm22bj1V63nCk6IyMlaKszf4e4kEL0SvS3aNdT0T8qab1VNOWPJp53pqDgydOwr8w3o24Hfecr8uIay@r2y6ljLs7cD2S2pNat@pj@qpKcZI00T2rJHyYqIYxzU2Hv@8tCtfVPFy7zK7f9ze9sdvOEh0TB1Oob0jq9qgvdXt2Dhr5m87V04xt1eNpNluPj2rvs0f1VW2obNr6RrSYecAvRsr/PIXFocKmRB0unmZzd@oFsugG/4bJ3cLk7idM9l8RPXgve3IC5nascg8PlCORmbgr7/rGnTm9KyPiCT56tZYwvRJRkHClzG2PvcjovbNzx0nbBbgOFa0QV30CLU4bB1vDa5x4e3EbR9LHoDo8@PDBXTHWoq0IDz7uwI/FvdgUVlpnanp4uOR6lc9JKJLD9ZW@svHHuZjnGjjgJPAFZxFwDRTm@MRSi77N8@XSHGxKPJy6kKUKBfPUfL66eFuSBjj9WuZ4Zvj@l5evzmfbvx8dHRNNOEnIPlnjr@r@75Hbl9@QW/wIifg9JRSVnhP922@EkqR4N3yOnNviSQ2nAUy3B4PiyqA0S@fk4LPNoqGD0iwN8b3HbAO4MIuxfvP618tvz2fD4cfWxVDhDTEtrtkH91C8QXXnNsbEt3NntbtS7hw@xpTeRtrv10F3it1QdMGFxgSs5PjjUfEH85iuiseg@D7eA5pluJzt53PAM3G6ZOrUfv9nDzaMriYlmRjy3tHXEItrhtsHlMCHYw7@Ag)

### Usage

```
/path/to/pxem/interpreter THAT_PROGRAM_AS_IN_ABOVE <input.txt
```

COBOL program to be input must be fed from stdin, with LF-styled newlines, whose last line is terminated with LF.

### Alternative: Pxem, 100 bytes (filename) + 0 bytes (content) = 100 bytes, printables and LF only.

Filename is as follows:

```
ab.-.t.i.m.+.w.i.s.i.s.i.s.i.s.i.s.i*.zAB.z.i.c.o
.a02.-.tXX.a.mac.-.zAB.i
.z.i
.aXX.aab.-.t.i.m.+.a
```

### Commented version

```
XX.z (this is just to format well
.a<0x01>.tXX.z (reg=1
.a.i.m.+.wXX.z (while getchar()!=EOF; do (obtw EOF is -1
   .a.i.s.i.s.i.s.i.s.i.sXX.z (5.times { getchar(); }
   .a.i*.zXX.z (while getchar()!='*'; do
      .aAB.z.i.c.o<0x0A>.aXX.z (do print(c=getchar()) while c!=newline
      .a<0x02>.tXX.z (reg=2
   .aXX.aXX.z ( break; done
   .a.m<0x02>.zXX.z (while reg!=2; do
      .aAB.i<0x0A>.z.i<0x0A>.aXX.z (do c=getchar() while c!=newline
   .aXX.aXX.z ( break; done
   .a<0x01>.tXX.z (reg=1
.a.i.m.+.aXX.z (done
.a
```

Answer (score 1):

## GFortran, 84 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LDoIwEEX3fMXs@gga8BFeGmP4kpEOlARbUoiJX1@B4ixO7j13M611s0Nz6NoQvG80OmxmcrwoRF05QiVjUykL/T1dwioYfwoW11Hf8ppnZSZuTDIxut7M@8TzUlRklLIrvb9GyXbwGlBvCCKVgOM40BTqCezyREfTI/SzhC@hjv/6uGqZXGCwH4I3wWQX7OMP)

Yet again, Fortran beats [Cobol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140311/15940) ☺. Borrows stuff from [this solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182522/15940).

```fortran
character(99)C;read*,n;do i=1,n;read'(A)',C
if(C(7:7)<'*')print'(A)',C(8:);enddo;end
```

<sub>Previously: <s>[95 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY7LDsIgEEX3fgU7Hqmm9ZHaojGmX4JlKCQVGkpM/Hospc7i5N5zN6OcD17Y/aByiLHXwos@gCdNQzvuQUhWWC4dMvdqCUlg8qS46HZGkY7UbU1vmGEaNFg@eWPDtpNrSzlYaVSidIkxXnbleug1Cr0ii4ohMU0jzLkekVv@GWB@5H5i6AtCF399SJqVZzS6D6A3oNkt2MYf)</s> ; <s>[98 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY7LDoMgEEX3/Qp2PGKN9hGrpGkav4TKICQWDJIm/XoqYmdxcu@ZWYxyPnhhj6PKIcZBCy@GAJ60Le25ByFZYbl0yNzrNSSByZPioj8YRXrSdA0tLZSYYRo0WD57Y8N@Qm4d5WClUYnSJcZ4PVTboNck9IYsaobEPE@w5HpCbn1phOWR@5mhLwhd/HWZNKsuaHIfQG9Ai1uxL38)</s>(-47 by removing array) ; <s>[145 bytes](https://tio.run/##NU9LDoIwEN33FN0x01TiN2iJMRxlhEGa1JaUxsTTIz9n8eb9Nq8NMUXyu1e7knGsO4pUJ45wu6Em50JNiZ6OjanAoIhMDSit0JdbyFCBRxRNkPZ@0L7cKhlUmGEFFoVtYf5QmAJzz3mmMkwd@7KP1qelqJfC1WDJvrGtmLAJMx/Hi9gvJ5@OugVW46Ak9b3jYZVHGaYFLx4eqz4p@WXq9N/OZ1vtz9KFD8s3yyFMsIU/)</s></sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), 277 bytes.

```
define g[x
set[s v]to(
set[j v]to((x)+(1
repeat(length of(item(i)of[l v
set[s v]to(join(s)(letter(j)of(item(i)of[l v
change[j v]by(1
end
replace item(i)of[l v]with(s
define f
set[i v]to(1
repeat(length of[l v
g(6
if<(s)contains[*]?>then
delete(i)of[l v
else
g[1
change[i v]by(1
```

[Try it on Scratch!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/757968830/)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 28 bytes

```
{$["*"=x@6;"";" "/1_" "\x]}'
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pWiVbSUrKtcDCzVlKyVlJQ0jeMB5IxFbG16lxcadE6SgZgoJBYUJCTqhQLEzI2MtZSKMnILFYAokSF5Pzc3NS8EoQ8SEtSTmIGgkCVy89TAIL0/BRkYUOFpKJSZIUgS/LySxQS8xRKi0sTc2D2KILVaMB0gd1WDHQ+mG+kpZBflJiXjhAxVsgF8vOBApqxAElWQTQ=)

Takes a list of strings and returns a list of strings.

Explanations:

```
{$["*"=x@6;"";" "/1_" "\x]}'  Main function. Takes implicit input
                           '  For each string in the lists...
{                         }   Execute a function that
 $[                      ]    Checks if
       x@6                    The character at the 6th position (0-indexed)
   "*"=   ;                   Is equal to an asterisk
           "";                If it does, return an empty string
                        x     Else, return the string
                    " "\      Splitted by whitespace
                  1_          Trim the first element (i.e. the line numbers)
              " "/            Join together by whitespace (to preserve the original text)
```

Comment: Save two byets by indexing into a list instead of `$[]`: [tio](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rWUFJQ0jeMB5IxFdZKSppKWkq2FQ5mtepcXGnROkoGYKCQWFCQk6oUCxMyNjLWUijJyCxWAKJEheT83NzUvBKEPEhLUk5iBoJAlcvPUwCC9PwUZGFDhaSiUmSFIEvy8ksUEvMUSotLE3Ng9iiC1WjAdIHdVqxkDeEbaSnkFyXmpSNEjBVygfx8oIBmLACRwEBu)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 20 bytes

```
7&}."1(#~'*'~:6&{"1)
```

This assumes the input is a matrix of equal-length space-padded lines.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 50 bytes

```php
foreach(file(C)as$s)$s[6]>" "||print substr($s,7);
```

same length:

```php
foreach(file(C)as$s)$s[6]^a^q||print substr($s,7);
foreach(file(C)as$s)$s[6]^b^x&&print substr($s,7);
foreach(file(C)as$s)echo$s[6]^b^x?substr($s,7):"";
```

regex solution, 51 bytes:

```php
<?=join(preg_filter("#^.{6} (.*)$#","$1",file(C)));
```

builtins only, 108 bytes:

```php
<?=join(array_map(function($s){return substr($s,7);},array_filter(file(C),function($s){return$s[6]^b^x;})));
```

take code from a file named `C`. Run with `-nr` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc5e449789da5dcbc8c8842c01cf920b8a1e72c4).

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 13 bytes

```
{{6>'*#},7f>}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f6Kf/v7razE5dS7lWxzzNrvZ/nZ/WfwMwUEjKScwAE1xgvqGWQmJBQU5qMYRrpJBflJiXnlpsD@EbaylUpiZm6MCE9UDCWgYmCjn5ZakKuakKxflAAioJAA)

Explanation:

```
{           }  e# Block. Input:                ["000000 blah blah" "000001* apples" "000002 oranges?" "000003* yeah, oranges."]
 {     },      e# Filter on the following:
  6>           e#   Remove first 6 characters: [" blah blah" "* apples" " oranges?" "*yeah, oranges"]
    '*#        e#   Find a '*':                [-1 0 -1 0]
               e# End filter:                  ["000000 blah blah" "000002 oranges?"]
         7f>   e# Remove first 7 characters:   ["blah blah" "oranges?"]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 22 bytes

```
('\6¯_0=`*!{]\1%ß1}]^ö
```

No explanation, sorry. I forgot how this works.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 15

```
V.z*.DNU7n@N6\*
```

Explanation:

```
V.z*.DNU7n@N6\*
V.z              For each line N in input
                  Print
     N             N
   .D U7           but with characters 0-6 removed
  *                times
          @N6       Item six of N
         n          Does not equal
             \*     "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
fo≠' ←m↓7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qKnx0Lb/afmPOheoKzxqm5D7qG2y@f///w3AQCEpJzEDTHCB@YZaCokFBTmpxRCukUJ@UWJeemqxPYRvrKVQmZqYoQMT1gMJaxmYKOTkl6Uq5KYqFOcDCagkAA)

same idea as Jelly.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 40 bytes

```
=FILTER(MID(A:A,8,73),MID(A:A,7,1)<>"*")
```

COBOL has a max line length of 80.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ê┬|Y¶à6
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=88c27c59148536&i=000000+blah+blah%0A000001*+apples%0A000002+oranges%3F%0A000003*+yeah,+oranges.%0A000*04+love+me+some+oranges)

### Explanation

```
m6%B42=C
m        map each line:
 6%      split at index 6, push both parts
   B     uncons, pop and push first element
    42=C if equal to 42, cancel
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 68 bytes

```cpp
[](auto&l){l.remove_if([](auto&s){int c=s[6];s=&s[7];return c&2;});}
```

Input is a `std::list<std::string>`, it's modified in place.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHxasIwEMb/z1McDmpbnGg3NmiqexCVEWOqgTQpuVQQ6bN3MdXhZrcLJJf8Pr7LJbyun/ecd6xxBkpYdKtNfMkjlZzV1IrKHMWnLOPbMSZnqR3wBa7eNhQXEa7eN9QK11gNPMpom9C2o@RJaq6anYBCGnRWsGp5d6Ykuvu9V0i9XxLivUnFpI4TcibgA90uzy/yImRXIRznPb7EaBYCWF0rsdajyS8yhy3TfvxEXChhT7AzunHoUSAt/bdo9lh0q9ghTEOF0/5OOMAyMJbpvcCPAfiSwkmww@SmmT5o0tkrKP81UAlA46er8q6RsJbxcZ70TZXGQvhDiDD3D5h8G4YmuWkcFAVgryYPYLzWY3ozzYZNs79N2@4L)

Answer (score 0):

## Pascal, 122 B

This is a complete `program` requiring a processor complying to ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”:

```pascal
program p(input,output);var l:string(80);begin while not EOF do begin readLn(l);if''=l[7]then writeLn(subStr(l,8))end end.
```

Ungolfed version with some explanatory comments:

```pascal
program uncommentFixedFormatCobol(input, output);
    var
        { This “discriminates” the built-in schema data type `string`
          to have a capacity of up to 80 characters, i.e. the maximum
          width of one COBOL _fixed-format_ source code line. }
        line: string(80);
    begin
        { `EOF` is shorthand for `EOF(input)`. }
        while not EOF do 
        begin
            { `readLn(line)` is shorthand for `readLn(input, line)`. }
            readLn(line);
            { Similarly, `write(x)` is shorthand for `write(output, x)`. }
            
            { ---- Remember, in Pascal `string` indices are 1-based. ----- }
            { This may look like an empty string check, and `''` is indeed
              an empty string, yet in Pascal the `=`-comparison first pads
              both operands  to the same length using `' '`.  This line is
              in fact doing `if line[7] = ' ' then`, but one byte shorter. }
            if line[7] = '' then
            begin 
                { `subStr(line, 8)` shorthand for
                  `subStr(line, 8, length(line) - 8 + 1)` }
                writeLn(subStr(line, 8))
                { Wait! What if `line[8]` does not exist? The standard
                  says it shall be an error if `firstCharacterIndex +
                  substringLength − 1` is greater than the length of the
                  supplied string. If `length(line)` equals seven, then
                  we’re calling `subStr(line, 8, 0)` which is fine. }
            end
        end
    end.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 19 bytes

```
W=xP|?42A=xSxF6@O]x
```

There are a few ways to do this that all are 19 bytes, but the theoretically optimal way (`= x SUBST(PROMPT 0 6 @)`) suffers from keyword clashing, meaning it has to be `=xS P0 6@`, wasting two separators.

```py
# for each line in stdin
WHILE (= x PROMPT)
    #  If not equal to to 42 (ASCII("*"))
    #   |    | ASCII value of first char
    #   |    |     | Strip the first 6 chars of x
    : | ? 42 ASCII (= x SUBST (x FALSE 6 @))
      # Output the tail (all but the first char) of x
      : OUTPUT (] x)
```

This uses the new `]` and `@` operators to simplify string operations, as `]` replaces `SxF1""` and `@` replaces `""` when coerced to String since empty list is empty string.

Input is in stdin, output is in stdout.

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyJXPXhQfD80MkE9eFN4RjZAT114IiwiMDAwMDAwIGJsYWggYmxhaFxuMDAwMDAxKiBhcHBsZXNcbjAwMDAwMiBvcmFuZ2VzP1xuMDAwMDAzKiB5ZWFoLCBvcmFuZ2VzLlxuMDAwKjA0IGxvdmUgbWUgc29tZSBvcmFuZ2VzXG5cbiIsIjIuMCJd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
tMfqdhT>R6.z
```

[Try it here.](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=tMfqdhT%3ER6.z&input=000000+blah+blah%0A000001%2a+apples%0A000002+oranges%3F%0A000003%2a+yeah%2C+oranges.%0A000%2a04+love+me+some+oranges&debug=0)

###### Explanation:

```
tMfqdhT>R6.z | Full program
-------------+----------------------------------------
        R .z | For each line of input
       > 6   |  Remove the first 6 characters
  f  hT      | Filter over whether the first character
   qd        |  is a space
tM           | Remove the first character of each
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 39 bytes

Outgolfed [user100411's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237165/113493)

```
for x
{ ((1${x:6:1}1))||echo "${x:7}"
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY27CsJAEEX7_YphCbgbjRgVnwStBGtLsZjoxBViVhIfkbhfYmOh-E3-jXnoFBfOneHM_eljot5L7pxTvnoGQmav0zFwBp9aoGNIWQZCuFaWjnoj17hS3m60Vhp4UfUNZ-Z3PjQMPSHZRe1Cgvls4UFMuAEnl4w3GrDuCW6lXOYQ0TgoDLicrgyvBI_PulUO-CGqMljJrg14OISUVNgGHWO0pWRScceGK6Fq_OtmUdutLoT6TLAnSHQevyWrfn0B)

### Usage

Each argument represents a line. e.g.

```bash
cat<<'EOF'>f
for x
{ ((1${x:6:1}1))||echo "${x:7}"
}
EOF
bash f '000000 blah blah' '000001* apples' '000002 oranges?' '000003* yeah, oranges.' '000*04 love me some oranges'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
¤æ6ið=;ı7ỵ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kp9S7IKlpSVpuhYbDi05vMws8_AGW-sjG80f7t66pDgpuRgqueBmkgEYKCTlJGaACS4w31BLIbGgICe1GMI1UsgvSsxLTy22h_CNtRQqUxMzdGDCeiBhLQMThZz8slSF3FSF4nwgAZWEWAUA)

##### Explanation

```python
¤æ6ið=;ı7ỵ  # Implicit input
¤           # Split the multi-line input on newlines
 æ    ;     # Filter this list of strings by:
  6i        #  The 6th character (0-indexed)
    ð=      #  Is a space
       ı    # Map over this new list of strings:
        7ỵ  #  Remove the first 7 characters
            # Implicit output, joined on newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang, 52 bytes

```erlang
a(A)->[lists:nthtail(7,X)||X<-A,lists:nth(7,X)/=42].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/LCsJADEX3/YosZ0pb6wMEn3TvBwhSSqzRDowzpRkFof9epw/N4sI9NzcQajSaR0xcNqp2XdehyGR8uGjFjjfGVQ6VFuvoLNv2vIuz6B8McLZfLfIk0MoQC98rkQmU3TzIFT0Ul1yCvQPZuz@ab09eT@20npO5JcETlRGF7/pa/XJFWWHDAsW0JGXSpcPAVWM1SDD4eQhY15p4tAuwjX@F@Dj6ZQgfwir64aTHYboCbd8ETwK2XqbwCw)

Answer (score 0):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 29 bytes

```
/^.{6}\*.*$/d
s/^.{7}//
/^$/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f9fP06v2qw2RktPS0U/hasYxDWv1dfn0o8D8v//NwADhaScxAwwwQXmG2opJBYU5KQWQ7hGCvlFiXnpqcX2EL6xlkJlamKGDkxYDySsZWCikJNflqqQm6pQnA8koJL/8gtKMvPziv/rugIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 94 bytes

```
listen to S
while S
cut S in N
cut S
while N-S-7
roll S in C

if C-1
join S
say S

listen to S
```

[Try it](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)