# We do tower hopping

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem, optimization

## Task

Given an array of non-negative integers `a`, determine the minimum number of rightward jumps required to jump "outside" the array, starting at position 0, or return zero/null if it is not possible to do so.

A *jump* from index `i` is defined to be an increase in array index by at most `a[i]`.

A *jump outside* is a jump where the index resulting from the jump `i` is out-of-bounds for the array, so for 1-based indexing `i>length(a)`, and for 0-based indexing, `i>=length(a)`.

### Example 1

Consider `Array = [4,0,2,0,2,0]`:

```
Array[0] = 4 -> You can jump 4 field
Array[1] = 0 -> You can jump 0 field
Array[2] = 2 -> You can jump 2 field
Array[3] = 0 -> You can jump 0 field
Array[4] = 2 -> You can jump 2 field
Array[5] = 0 -> You can jump 0 field
```

The shortest path by "jumping" to go out-of-bounds has length `2`:

We could jump from `0->2->4->outside` which has length `3` but `0->4->outside` has length `2` so we return `2`.

### Example 2

Suppose `Array=[0,1,2,3,2,1]`:

```
Array[0] = 0 -> You can jump 0 fields
Array[1] = 1 -> You can jump 1 field
Array[2] = 2 -> You can jump 2 field
Array[3] = 3 -> You can jump 3 field
Array[4] = 2 -> You can jump 2 field
Array[5] = 1 -> You can jump 1 field
```

In this case, it is impossible to jump outside the array, so we should return a zero/null or any non deterministic value like `∞`.

### Example 3

Suppose `Array=[4]`:

```
Array[0] = 4 -> You can jump 4 field
```

We can directly jump from index 0 outside of the array, with just one jump, so we return `1`.

## Edit:

Due to multiple questions about the return value:
Returning `∞` is totally valid, if there is no chance to escape.
Because, if there is a chance, we can define that number.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: What do you mean by "if you can jump outside of the Collection with a **minimum of jumps**!"?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino is this troll or you really don't get it?
Check Example #2. It has `2 Solutions`, with `2 or 3 Jumps`, option with `2 Jumps` would be the right.

Comment: I really don't get what a minimum of jumps is... it suggests to me that there's meant to be a number of jumps such that if you can't escape the collection in fewer jumps than that it should return false, but the examples mention nothing about that.

Comment: Also, please add more test cases.

Comment: I edited your challenge such that the formatting is less confusing and the task can now be more easily understood. Feel free to edit / rollback if you disagree with the changes I've made.

Comment: Also, in general, when people ask for clarification or raise suggestions, they're generally not "trolling". I'd suggest you not assume that.

Comment: @0x45 whether 2 or 3 jumps, we can escape the array so we return `TRUE` so I don't quite understand what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino We want the **most** optimal path. Which (according to Example 2) would be Index 0 to Index 4 from index 4 we can jump outside.
This check of best path should be the crux to this task.

Comment: But since we're returning true/false, it doesn't matter whether or not we find the best path, just whether or not there is a path...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Challenge spec says truthy/falsy...

Comment: If we cannot escape, you return false, if you took the return list approach, you should return a empty list.

Comment: Also, **please consider using [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) for your challenges!** Many of these concerns might have been addressed earlier if you had posted there.

Comment: @0x45 wait so if it is escapable return # steps?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino well, thats a great idea. I will consider to update it to your suggestion. Stand by-

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136372/skip-like-a-rabbit), [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139955/skip-like-a-frog?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, I totally disagree with your assumption

Comment: @0x45 What assumption? The fact that I linked you to some related challenges? I never said *duplicate*. I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @0x45 please [assume good intentions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). We are asking these questions **not** because we're trying to make fun of your challenge. Actually, it's quite the opposite: we're interested in your challenge. Just think about it, why would we ask clarifying questions if we disliked your challenge? We have the downvotes/close votes for that purpose. (And as I see, nobody has downvoted your post!)

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify what I think it's now asking; please feel free to roll it back if there's anything you disagree with.

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks, i'm not native speaking english.
Your assumptions are correct

Comment: @0x45 yep, we totally understand here! we have lots of people posting from all over the world, which is why we have places like [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to help you edit your challenge in a friendly manner without anyone getting frustrated by something as reasonable as a simple language barrier! :) I really like this challenge and hope it gets lots of good answers!

Comment: It would be good to have a test case where greedily jumping the maximum distance at every step is not optimal. For example `[2, 3, 1, 1]`.

Comment: @0x45 can we use maxint as a null value?

Comment: @0x45 Can we use ∞ as a null value?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit ∞ is valid.

Comment: @ngn No. So you would say, you could escape the Array with `MaxInt` Value, eventhough you can't. However, `∞` is valid. See updated question

Comment: When you say `You can jump 4 fields`, do you mean `You MUST jump 4 fields`, or `You can jump UP TO 4 fields`?

Comment: @Flater up to 4 fields, you gotta make the best decision to escape the array with a minimum of jump. So always the highest isn't necessary the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
Γö→▼Mo₀↓ŀ
```

Returns `Inf` when no solution exists.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkKtR/KipsUjz0Lb/5yYf3vaobdKjaXt88x81NTxqm3y04f///9EmOgY6RhAcyxVtoGMIZBkDsSGQZwLExkA5Y6AoSIURSDYWAA)

### Explanation

Husk's default return values come in handy here.

```
Γö→▼Mo₀↓ŀ  Implicit input: a list, say [2,3,1,1]
Γ          Deconstruct into head H = 2 and tail T = [3,1,1]
 ö         and feed them into this function:
        ŀ   Range from 0 to H-1: [0,1]
    Mo      For each element in range,
       ↓    drop that many element from T: [[3,1,1],[1,1]]
      ₀     and call this function recursively on the result: [1,2]
   ▼        Take minimum of the results: 2
  →         and increment: 3
```

If the input list is empty, then `Γ` cannot deconstruct it, so it returns the default integer value, 0.
If the first element is 0, then the result of `Mo₀↓ŀ` is an empty list, on which `▼` returns infinity.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>70</s> 58 bytes

```hs
f[]=0
f(0:_)=1/0
f(x:s)=minimum[1+f(drop k$x:s)|k<-[1..x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYhBDsIgFAX3PQULFxAR@eqqKSchxBALlrTQBmrswrsjtIt5mXmDTqOZppytVII3FvP2SQRcq25tIsK74PzHSzhb3Md5QeOp/r@xu0hgbFMqe@2CcGE1Ub9WnIb5y7xe0JtFo3uSpVS0QfJxLOX0drA3p1D8XoC9q0Nx9Qc)

EDIT: -12 bytes thanks to @Esolanging Fruit and the OP for deciding to allow infinity!

Returns `Infinity` when there is no solution which makes the solution a lot simpler. Since we can only move forwards `f` just looks at the head of the list and drops `1<=k<=x` items from the list and recurs. Then we just add 1 to each solution the recursive calls found and take the minimum. If the head is 0 the result will be infinity (since we cannot move there is no solution). Since `1+Infinity==Infinity` this result will be carried back to the callers. If the list is empty that means we have left the array so we return a cost of 0.

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYhBDsIgFAX3PQULFxAR@eqqKSchxBALlrTQBmrswrsjtIt5mXmDTqOZppytVII3FvP2SQRcq25tIsK74PzHSzhb3Md5QeOp/r@xu0hgbFMqe@2CcGE1Ub9WnIb5y7xe0JtFo3uSpVS0QfJxLOX0drA3p1D8XoC9q0Nx9Qc), but only if you allow `Infinity` as the null value (which the OP hasn't clarified yet).

Comment: Actually, OP has now allowed this, so that should be valid.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 124 bytes

```python
def f(a):
 i={0};l=len(a)
 for j in range(l):
	for q in{0}|i:
	 if q<l:i|=set(range(q-a[q],q-~a[q]))
	 if max(i)/l:return-~j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwEEXX9hSznECKVVxFc5LiImCiU2LapBEUa68eJ5SB//mPN9MnP8ZwLOVmHTg0QjVA@tv9zl57Gxg04MYEA1CAZMLdomdnV1lkxuZCvIEcxItXtOjZZtzM2Jo@XmVs19pCbNrTvJHE3qtk8yuFdh3KlChkdNif5EF2siYff5Q/)

-11 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder
-12 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder and Rod

Comment: You failed `print(f([4,1,0,4,1,1,1]))` You return `3`, but should be `2`
Like `[0] -> [3] -> outside`

Comment: @0x45 how so... wait, when you jump, do you have to jump as far as possible or anywhere in between?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder oh yeah, duh. also thanks for the `-~` trick, forgot about that one.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino "A jump from index i is defined to be an increase in array index by **at most** a[i]."

Comment: @MartinEnder oh okay thanks, fixed

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder wait that's actually a requirement :/ ok fixed

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, you take the most optimal jump to archieve a minimum of jumps to escape the array.

Comment: @0x45 ok, thanks for clarifying. I think I fixed it

Comment: Looks good... :)

Comment: [127 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYpBCsMgFETXySlcalBIaFc29iLiQqi2P1gTxUJLmlzdasPADPN4yyc9Zn/K@WYsslgT3jYg1n67OOGML6Bt7BzRhMCjqP3dYFedPwwFyg5U/Q1YNoxhdBy@Yu0ONTAtg6KB7XXJdnjoqd8YyFU4Hk16Rc/2KS8RfMIWyzMdaE9rlyhC8g8) by declaring `len(a)`, bitwise and set tricks. Also, why do you need `-1<`?

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwEEXX9hSzTCDBVlzF5iTFRcBEp8S0SSMo1l49TpSB//mPN/Mr36ZwKOViHThmuGoA9bv9nLz2NhBowE0JRsAAyYSrZZ6cXWWRGJkr0gZ0sutj7xWuerGZ/d0ozRDPIsqtNuc/Ee7myZDvvUo2P1KQ21jmhCEzx4aj6EQratLRR/kC) switch to python2, saving with indentation and replacing `>=` with `/`, but loosing in `[*i]` -> `{0}|i` and `{*range}` -> `set(range)`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh you're right, I don't think it's ever useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## <s>[APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/)</s> [ngn/apl](https://github.com/ngn/apl), 18 bytes

EDIT: switched to my own implementation of APL because Dyalog doesn't support infinities and the challenge author [doesn't allow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156497/we-do-tower-hopping?noredirect=1#comment381474_156497) finite numbers to act as "null"

```apl
⊃⊃{⍵,⍨1+⌊/⍺↑⍵}/⎕,0
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQZcjzra0/4/6moGoupHvVt1HvWuMNR@1NOl/6h316O2iUChWn2gah2D/0CV/9O4TBQMFIwgmCuNy0DBEMgyBmJDIE/HBEgYgiVAgoYKhgA)</s>
[try it at ngn/apl's demo page](https://ngn.github.io/apl/web/index.html#code=%u2395%u2190%20%u2283%u2283%7B%u2375%2C%u23681+%u230A/%u237A%u2191%u2375%7D/%u2395%2C0)

returns <s>`⌊/⍬`</s>
 `∞` for no solution

Comment: What is the "right argument" of `?`?

Comment: This challenge is in desperate need of better test-cases. But your solution is invalid for example `2 3 1 1` should be mapped to `2`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer `0N` which is k's integer null; if you're interested, I can explain further in the apl room

Comment: @H.PWiz now it can deal with that

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

```hs
(1%)
0%_=1/0
a%(h:t)=min(1+h%t)$(a-1)%t
_%_=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYrRCsIgGEbvfYpdJCi55V9dBT6JjfFjLkfTZAq9fWbbLs7H@eA4TC87z2VU98KAciLpoOAkCVLmbpkrPwUGR0czPzBsgdNMhprI4nEKagrZLmgyS@796TzGZuwWiw9etO4FafR1WyHFeWP9UkD1SwXW/3fYfd9a9l8zzvhMpTUx/gA)

Outputs `Infinity` when impossible. The auxiliary left argument to `%` tracks how many more spaces we can move in our current hop.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>56</s> 53 bytes

Includes `+1` for `a`

```
perl -aE '1until-@F~~%v?say$n:$n++>map\@v{$_-$F[-$_]..$_},%v,0'  <<< "4 0 2 0 2 0"; echo
```

Just the code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -a
1until-@F~~%v?say$n:$n++>map\@v{$_-$F[-$_]..$_},%v,0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBC4IwGIbv/ooPmyedbKWXRuXJc/cKWfQFgs6xzVVE/vTWoAcensP7ajRDHWaLUJeclUwEPivXD7RplyXzBytfRG2JyvP9KPW58W/SUdKeKOkuZUm6T5H5ggURfymlNBVE7ZiY1Q3vkHmIrOBoeuXAopZGusnAFd0DUQE@5agHtAUYtHFAsE46DBUwWP9NGPDYTZQn1XfSrp@UDVT@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 80 bytes

```perl
sub f{$_[0]>=@_||1+((sort{$a?$b?$a-$b:-1:1}map f(@_[$_..$#_]),1..$_[0])[0]||-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVolPtog1s7WIb6mxlBbQ6M4v6ikWiXRXiXJXiVRVyXJStfQyrA2N7FAIU3DIT5aJV5PT0U5PlZTxxDIAGnVBOKaGl1Dzdr/xYmVQFUmOgYwqGnNhRAzgmC4mIGOIZBvDMSGCHWa1v//5ReUZObnFf/X9TXVMzA0AAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 bytes

```
ṛ/ṆȧJ’Ṛ
Rḟ"ÇƤZ$$Tị$Œp+\€Ṁ<Li0ȧ@Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUQAu/9qZWxsef//4bmbL@G5hsinSuKAmeG5mgpS4bifIsOHxqRaJCRU4buLJMWScCtc4oKs4bmAPExpMMinQOG4ov///1s0XQ)

This is just too long...

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
<LḢ
ḊßÐƤṁḢḟ0‘Ṃµ1Ç?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/G5@GORVwPd3Qdnn94wrElD3c2AvkPd8w3eNQw4@HOpkNbDQ@32/8/3P6oac3//9HRJjoGOkYQHKsTbaBjCGQZA7EhkGcCxCCeIZAXCwA)

### Explanation

```
<LḢ  Helper link. Input: array
<    Less than
 L   Length
  Ḣ  Head - Returns 0 if its possible to jump out, else 1

ḊßÐƤṁḢḟ0‘Ṃµ1Ç?  Main link. Input: array
            Ç   Call helper link
             ?  If 0
           1      Return 1
                Else
          µ       Monadic chain
Ḋ                   Dequeue
 ßÐƤ                Recurse on each suffix
     Ḣ              Head of input
    ṁ               Mold, take only that many values
      ḟ0            Filter 0
        ‘           Increment
         Ṃ          Minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript ES6](https://nodejs.org), 118 bytes

```javascript
(x,g=[[0,0]])=>{while(g.length){if((s=(t=g.shift())[0])>=x.length)return t[1];for(i=0;i++<x[s];)g.push([s+i,t[1]+1])}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc29DsIgHATw3adw/JMiAXWr9EUIQ1P5MqQ0QLVJ02dHauJiHG763eUe/bNPQ3RTPo3hrormBRZsuBAUUykR79aXdV6BIV6NJlu0Og2QOGRuSLJOZ0BIUIk6vnwrUeU5jscsmGx1iOA4bV3T3BaRZIsMmeZkQaTG4b3SMIm2rQxhTMEr4oMBDfWe4TO@1FRGhx/dhf2VK6Z180nV8gY)

Performs a breadth first search of the array to find the shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 80 bytes

```c
f(A,l,M,j,r)int*A;{M=~0;for(j=0;l>0&&j++<*A;)if(M<1|M>(r=f(A+j,l-j)))M=r;A=-~M;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BCsIwFETvUrD8b38h0eImTSEHyAnUhVQiCWmU4C62V68f3Ygws5nHzIztbRzX1YGhSJYCZfTpuTWqWL0I5e4ZghYqDqKuQ9P0TNA7sL182QGy5mITKLYBEa3Oyuh2sWpep4tPgOWRec1BtbnSR6dUkQPg8HjG0pGg3dczHfCHCJKc7tnyj3QzSUR@eAM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 79 bytes

Returns the number of jumps or `Inf` if you can't escape. Recursively look at the first element and either return `Inf` or `1` depending on if you can escape, otherwise add `1` to the shortest solution for truncated arrays representing each valid jump. The control flow is done with two ternary statements like `test1 ? ontrue1 : test2 ? ontrue2 : onfalse2`.

```julia
f(a,n=endof(a))=a[1]<1?Inf:a[1]>=n?1:1+minimum(f(a[z:min(z+a[1],n)]) for z=2:n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/TSNRJ882NS8lH8jS1LRNjDaMtTG098xLswIx7Wzz7A2tDLVzM/Myc0tzNYCKoqusgDyNKm2QvE6eZqymQlp@kUKVrZFVnuZ/h@KM/HKFNI1oAx1DHSMdYyA2jNXkggub6BgAhcAYWRik0hCk8j8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>83</s> <s>73</s> 72 bytes

<sup>-10 thanks to @user202729

-1 thanks to @JonathanFrech</sup>

```python
lambda a:a and(a[0]and-~min(f(a[k+1:])for k in range(a[0]))or 1e999)or 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCsMgEEX3PYVkpUSCpt0k0JNYkSlqK4lGjBRy@nSSDLyZ94eft/pdUr/752ufIb4tEBiRZCkoofGSGBL1mKZWjpq10i@FTCQkUiB93FljDH/SDcNwiNhzCanSCJl67n4wU2NCzEupxtBm3daGdWu1IXXFgaUMZ1dK8xtRj2tzwfuLMwsu0e@IPPPhEl3/AQ) Returns infinity for a null value.

Comment: `and min(...)+1for` can be `and-~min(...)for`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Edited.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 97 bytes

```cs
f=l=>{for(int c=l.Count,s=0,j=l[0];j>0;s=f(l.GetRange(j,c-j--)))if(s>0|j>=c)return s+1;return 0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZI9a8MwEIZ3/4obJeoPOemmyEugXVIo7dAhZDCqbGRUGXRyS3H92107SU1wO2RwbzgOdHqfe4@TGMnaqV6aHBEegzaAIdDnXkt4r/UrPOTaEvRO23J/gNyVSI89p84xnj/Rq7f4rrFyc663tTFKel1bjO@VVU7LeKfRb7T1WQhjhgIE2MYY3hfCiKwtakeGB5DCDP8b60MULKyE2bMDrzLGURTEDHL@KbelIlUooyqKKKW6IJixryoTkjrlG2cBb1J@Lhnveh7Mp90Oo9VGxS9Oe7XTVpGCWPUB1xiAFm5DYCGspgwdpXyUT5LVwqiBkB4h62NOL1BsaVeT9iySJP3nBU7GkmS9MOokP3Jm9pZf4Pr3Qfyglj6L9E9LF666oOu/AQ)

Returns 0 if no path was found.

**Explanation**

```cs
f = 
    l =>                                      //The list of integers
    {
        for (
            int c = l.Count,                  //The length of the list
                s = 0,                        //Helper to keep track of the steps of the recursion
                j = l[0];                     //The length of the jump, initialize with the first element of the list
                j > 0;                        //Loop while the jump length is not 0
                s = f(l.GetRange(j, c - j--)) //Recursive call of the function with a sub-list stating at the current jump length. 
                                              //Then decrement the jumplength. 
                                              //Returns the number of steps needed to jump out of the sup-list or 0 if no path was found. 
                                              //This is only executed after the first run of the loop body.
            )
        {
            if (j >= c |                      //Check if the current jump lengt gets you out of the list. 
                                              //If true return 1 (s is currently 0). OR
                s > 0 )                       //If the recursive call found a solution (s not 0) 
                                              //return the number of steps from the recursive call + 1
                return s + 1;
        }
        return 0;                             //If the jump length was 0 return 0 
                                              //to indicate that no path was found from the current sub-list.
    }
```