# Finding Fastest Frog's Frolicks

Tags: code-golf, number, array

A frog sits on a lily pad wishing it were on the other side of the river.  There are some lily pads of varying sizes between the frog and the other side of the river.  Larger lily pads allow the frog to jump further than smaller ones and the frog wishes to reach the other side of the river in as few jumps as possible.

You will receive a list of lilypads represented by natural numbers (includes zero), each number being the maximum number of spaces that the frog can jump when he sits on that lily pad.  The frog can and often will need to jump fewer than the maximum spaces. The frog will start on the zeroth lilypad and end when his index is out of bounds for the list of the lilypads (on the other bank).  You will need to output the series of jumps that gets the frog to the other bank.  You can output either then length of the jump or the indices of the lilypads the frog lands on.  If the input has multiple optimal solutions you need only output 1.

Since frogs don't own computers you are going to need to make your code as short as possible (the frog counts in bytes) so the frog can understand it.

---

### Test cases

Outputs the sizes of the jumps

```
[4,2,2,1,1] -> [4,1]
[5,3,1,1,2,0,1] -> [4,2,1]
[6,9,1,2,1,1,1] -> [1,6]
```

Comment: [very closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156497/we-do-tower-hopping?noredirect=1&lq=1) (return # of jumps rather than sequence of jumps)