# The repetitive byte counter

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, source-layout, self-referential

Your task is to write a non-empty program / function of byte count **L**, which, when repeated **M** times, checks whether a given positive integer **N** is equal to **L × M**.

You should, in theory, support an arbitrary number of repetitions (an arbitrary positive integer value of **M**), but it's fine if, due to language limitations, it cannot work over a certain threshold.  Reading the source code of your program or accessing information about it is **strictly forbidden**.

For providing output, you should choose a consistent value for one of the states (either truthy or falsy) and use any other (not necessarily consistent) possible output for the other state ([Discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12308/59487)).

Your answers will be scored by your initial program's length **L** (in bytes), with less bytes being better.

### Example

Let's say your (initial) program is `ABCDE`. Then:

- `ABCDE` (1 repetition) should check if the input equals **5**.
- `ABCDEABCDE` (2 repetitions) should check if the input equals **10**.
- `ABCDEABCDEABCDE` (3 repetitions) should check if the input equals **15**. Etc...

The score of this sample code would be **5**, as the initial source is 5 bytes long.

Comment: Just to clarify: _source code of length `L` concatenated after itself `M` times should return whether its input `N` is equal to `L*M`_?

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
’
```

Output is **0** for a match, non-zero for a non-match.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8wBRP///zcxAgA)

#### How it works

This makes advantage of the overly liberal output format. Repeating `’` **M** times simply decrements the input **M** times, so the result will be zero if and only if the input is **LM**, where **L = 1**.

Comment: Oh god I didn't see this coming... (*inb4 everyone ports it to other esolangs...*)

Comment: I did have a 0-byte answer in mind, but, eh, *[tag:quine]*. :P

Comment: My first thought. Beaten by 23 minutes :(

Answer (score 11):

### Haskell, 8 bytes

```
(-8+).id
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WQ9dCW1MvM4UrHc6EC2VgCMHo/7mJmXkKtgop@VwKCgVFmXklCioKuYkFCmkK0RY6hmY6RiaxaDLpOGUyEDL/AQ)

Like many other answers it returns 0 for truthy and non-0 for falsy by repeatedly subtracting the length of the code from the input number.

Comment: I was *so* close to tinkering to getting to this...

Answer (score 8):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
\d+
*
^$
_
^_{20}

_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg7CoAwEEDB/p1DQbTJbj4kJ/ASkihoYWMhduLZY8qZ@3jOa5PaD/Nal31iJHcUcnnVfFBqFRSLRCShBm1uEbEJZ3CCU3zEJ4IhCEF/) Just repeat the part in the *Code* window to see how it handles the multiples.

Gives `0` for the correct multiple and positive integers for everything else.

#### Explanation

Let's look at the single program first:

```
\d+
*
```

This converts a decimal number to unary (using `_` as the unary digit).

```
^$
_
```

If the string is empty (which can't happen at this point, because the input is guaranteed to be positive), we replace it with a single `_`.

```
^_{20}
```

Now we get rid of the first 20 underscores. Iff the input was `20`, this results in an empty string.

```
_
```

And finally we count the number of underscores in the result, which is zero iff the input was `20`.

---

Now what happens when we repeat the source code. Since we don't insert a linefeed when joining the programs, the first line will go right at the end of the last line, we get this when the double the program:

```
\d+
*
^$
_
^_{20}

_\d+
*
^$
_
^_{20}

_
```

Now instead of counting the underscores, we end up with the following stage:

```
_\d+
*
```

This stage does nothing, because there are no more digits in the working string at this point, so the regex can't match.

```
^$
_
```

Now this stage becomes relevant. If the input was a smaller multiple of 20, the string has been emptied by the previous copy of the source code. In that case, we turn it into a single underscore, which we know can never be turned into an empty string again by our program. This way we ensure that *only* the **M**th multiple is accepted (and not all multiples up to the **M**th).

```
^_{20}
```

We remove the first 20 underscores once more. So **M** repetitions of the source code will remove **20M** underscores from the string, if possible.

```
_
```

And when we get to the end of the program, we still count underscores so that valid inputs give zero.

Answer (score 7):

## x86 32-bit machine code fragment, 1 byte

```
48                      dec    eax
```

Input in EAX, output in EAX: 0 for true, non-zero for false.  (Also leaves the ZF flag set for true, unset for false, so you could `je  was_equal`).  As a "bonus", you don't have to worry about wrapping; 32-bit x86 can only address 4GiB of memory, so you can't make M large enough to wrap all the way around and find `1 == 2**32 + 1` or something.

To make a callable function, append a `0xC3`  `ret` instruction after repeating `0x48` M times.   (Not counted in the total count, because many languages need to repeat just the function body, or an expression, to be able to compete).

Calleable from GNU C with the prototype `__attribute__((regparm(1))) int checkeqM(int eax);`  [GNU C's `regparm` x86 function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#index-regparm-function-attribute_002c-x86), like `-mregparm`, uses EAX to pass the first integer arg.

For example, this complete program takes 2 args, and JITs M copies of the instruction + a `ret` into a buffer, and then calls it as a function.  (Requires executable heap; compile with [`gcc -O3 -m32 -z execstack`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276488/why-is-execstack-required-to-execute-code-on-the-heap))

```
/******* Test harness: JIT into a buffer and call it ******/
// compile with gcc -O3 -no-pie -fno-pie -m32 -z execstack
// or use mprotect or VirtualProtect instead of -z execstack
// or mmap(PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) instead of malloc

// declare a function pointer to a regparm=1 function
// The special calling convention applies to this function-pointer only
// So main() can still get its args properly, and call libc functions.
// unlike if you compile with -mregparm=1
typedef int __attribute__((regparm(1))) (*eax_arg_funcptr_t)(unsigned arg);

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc<3) return -1;
    unsigned N=strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0), M = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);

    char *execbuf = malloc(M+1);   // no error checking
    memset(execbuf, 0x48, M);     // times M  dec eax
    execbuf[M] = 0xC3;            // ret
    // Tell GCC we're about to run this data as code.  x86 has coherent I-cache,
    // but this also stops optimization from removing these as dead stores.
    __builtin___clear_cache (execbuf, execbuf+M+1);
     //   asm("" ::: "memory");  // compiler memory barrier works too.

    eax_arg_funcptr_t execfunc = (eax_arg_funcptr_t) execbuf;
    int res = execfunc(N);
    printf("%u == %u  =>  %d\n", N,M, res );
    return !!res;   // exit status only takes the low 8 bits of return value
}
```

[non-PIE executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) are loaded lower in virtual memory; can do a bigger contiguous malloc.

```
$ gcc -g -O3 -m32 -no-pie -fno-pie -fno-plt -z execstack coderepeat-i386.c
$ time ./a.out 2747483748 2747483748   # 2^31 + 600000100 is close to as big as we can allocate successfully
2747483748 == 2747483748  =>  0

real    0m1.590s     # on a 3.9GHz Skylake with DDR4-2666
user    0m0.831s
sys     0m0.755s

$ echo $?
0

 # perf stat output:
       670,816      page-faults               #    0.418 M/sec                  
 6,235,285,157      cycles                    #    3.885 GHz                    
 5,370,142,756      instructions              #    0.86  insn per cycle
```

Note that [GNU C doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386979/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-c#comment85866179_9387041) object sizes larger than `ptrdiff_t` (signed 32-bit), but `malloc` and `memset` do still work, so this program succeeds.

## ARM Thumb machine code fragment, 2 bytes

```
 3802            subs    r0, #2
```

First arg in `r0` and return value in `r0` is the standard ARM calling convention.  This also sets flags (the `s` suffix).  Fun fact; the *non*-flag-setting version of `sub` is a 32-bit wide instruction.

The return instruction you need to append is `bx lr`.

## AArch64 machine code fragment, 4 bytes

```
d1001000        sub     x0, x0, #0x4
```

Works for 64-bit integers.  Input / output in `x0`, as per the standard calling convention.  `int64_t foo(uint64_t);`

AArch64 doesn't have a Thumb mode (yet), so 1 instruction is the best we can do.

Comment: Note for anyone else who comes across this: the call to `__builtin___clear_cache` is only necessary because you're executing memory that you got from `malloc`. If you got the memory from `mmap` instead, the optimization doesn't happen.

Comment: Yes, gcc happens not to break if you omit `__builtin___clear_cache` after writing into a `mmap`ed buffer.  But only because gcc doesn't know about `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` and considers the stores a possibly visible side-effect that the called function might read.  So it happens to work, but there's no reason *not* to follow the rules and tell the compiler that some stores are actually used, definitely not dead.

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 16 (or 1) bytes

Boring answer:

```
<C-x>
```

one byte.

Less boring answer:

```
uÓ^$/0
16Ø^a$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v/Tw5DgVfQMuQzPGwzPihBJVuP7//29oBgA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 75d3 5e24 2f30 0a31 3601 d85e 1261 240a  u.^$/0.16..^.a$.
```

I actually wrote this about 5 minutes after the challenge came out. It took me 30 minutes to patch this horrible pile of spaghetti code that I call a *language*.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
int=lambda x,i=int:i(x)-27;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzOvxDYnMTcpJVGhQifTFsi1ytSo0NQ1Mrf@n5ZfpJCnkJmnEG2oo2BkBsTmQGyho2BqDMQmQGyqo2BmEGvFpQAEBUVAzRp5OgpgSlPzPwA)

Code repeated twice:

```python
int=lambda x,i=int:i(x)-27;int=lambda x,i=int:i(x)-27;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzOvxDYnMTcpJVGhQifTFsi1ytSo0NQ1MrfGI/U/Lb9IIU8hM08h2lBHwcgMiM2B2EJHwdQYiE2A2FRHwcwg1opLAQgKioCaNfJ0FMCUpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic (83 series), 4 bytes

```
:Ans-4
```

Takes input in `Ans`: for example, you might type `17:prgmCODEGOLF` to run this with an input of `17`. Prints (and returns in `Ans`) the value `0` if the input is equal to **L × M**, and a nonzero value otherwise.

Note that the `:` is part of the code, so if you are entering this into the program editor, you should see

```
PROGRAM:CODEGOLF
::Ans-4
```

if you enter it once and

```
PROGRAM:CODEGOLF
::Ans-4:Ans-4:An
s-4
```

if you enter it three times.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 6 bytes

```perl
$_-=6;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXtfWzPr/f7N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

uses `0` for equal

Comment: Also a valid Perl 6 `-p` solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
-₂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X/dRU9P//0b/owA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 24 bytes

```
({}[(((()()()){}){}){}])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6NloDCDRBULO6FoJiNf//NzIBAA)

Returns `0` for equal and something else for not equal.

### How it works:

```
({} #pop the top of the stack
  [(((()()()){}){}){}] #subtract 24
) #push the result.
```

This code run `n` times will subtract `n * 24` from the input, giving 0 only when the input = `n*24`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 1 byte

```
v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JrPj/v@z/f0MA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 12 bytes

```hs
(-)$0
 +12--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX0NXU8WAS0Hb0EhX939uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKagqHR/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Outputs `0` for truthy and some non-zero integer for falsy.

### Alternate solution, 12 bytes

```hs
id
 .(-)12--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzOFS0FPQ1fT0EhX939uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKagqHR/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 15 bytes

```
]#<@.-&+
>fv
v+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/P1bZxkFPV02byy6tjKtM@/9/E2MA)

[Try it doubled!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/P1bZxkFPV02byy6tjKtMG437/7@xAQA)

Uses 0 for equal and anything else for unequal.

## Explanation:

This code repeated many times will look something like this:

```
]#<@.-&+
>fv
v+]#<@.-&+
>fv
v+]#<@.-&+
>fv
 .
 .
 .
v+]#<@.-&+
>fv
v+
```

1. `]` right turn. Sends the IP down.
2. `>` move east. Sends the IP right.
3. `f` push a 16.
4. `v` move south. Sends the IP down. If this is the last time, Goto step 8.
5. `]` right turn. Sends the IP left.
6. `+` add. Adds the 16 to the top of the stack.
7. `v` move south. Sends the IP down. Goto step 2.
8. `<` move west. Send the IP left.
9. `#` skip. jump over the `]` and wrap around to the end.
10. `+` add. Adds the 16 to the top of the stack.
11. `&` input. Push a number from the user.
12. `-` subtract. get the difference of sum we were working on and the input.
13. `.` print. Print the result.
14. `@` end.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <s>56</s> 46 bytes

```
a=(a or io.read())-46io.write(a<=0 and a or"")
```

Outputs a 0 (without a trailing newline) if equal and either nothing or a series of negative numbers (with preceding zero in some cases) if not equal.

Alone: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/0VYjUSG/SCEzX68oNTFFQ1NT18QMyCkvyixJ1Ui0sTVQSMxLUQCpUVLS/P/fFAA)

Repeated a bunch of times: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/0VYjUSG/SCEzX68oNTFFQ1NT18QMyCkvyixJ1Ui0sTVQSMxLUQCpUVLSHKqq//83MjYAAA)

### Explanation

```
a=(a or io.read())-46
```

On the first iteration (when `a` hasn't been defined yet and is therefore `nil`), sets `a` to a number taken from input, otherwise to itself. In both cases, 46 is then subtracted from `a`.

```
io.write(a<=0 and a or"")
```

This just prints `a` if it is less than (to take care of cases where the input was larger than the total length) or equal to zero, and the empty string otherwise.

*-10 bytes* for remembering that Lua does conversions between numbers and strings automatically. Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pure Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 15

Input given as a command-line parameter.  Output as a shell exit code - `1` for TRUE and `0` for FALSE.

```
(((a+=15)-$1))
```

- [Try it online x1](https://tio.run/##FctBCoAgEEbh/ZziX7hQQmhqDCKis1gZtlFI72/11t/bfYntyg9qKBV3AgvYgScMM8YeI0ME4iDTgjOTJnyVUGEt1D81rbXvVnbGKjaG2g/CETPURobOnEJ7AQ)
- [Try it online x2](https://tio.run/##XYtNCoAgFAb37xTfwoUSQi@fQUR0ln4M2ySk97faNruBmXXJsR7pRgm54LzAAvbgHt0A18IxRCAe0o/YE2nCSw4F1kJ9U9VaL83E3ljFxtBP69eHLSaomQzt6Qr1AQ)
- [Try it online x3](https://tio.run/##fctLCoAgFEbh@V3FP3CghNDNaxARraWHYZOEdP9WG@jMzuBblxzrkW6UkAvOCyxgD@7RDXAtHEME4iH9iD2RJrzlUGAt1Ieq1nppJvbGKjaG/rd@PGwxQc1kaE9XqA8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＰＩ⁼Ｉθ×¹³Ｌ⊞Ｏυω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9jaGFyY29hbP//77yw77yp4oG877ypzrjDl8K5wrPvvKziip7vvK/Phc@J//8xMw) Based on my answer to [I double the source, you double the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132558) Explanation:

```
         ⊞Ｏυω   Push empty string to predefined empty list
        Ｌ       Take the length
     ×¹³        Multiply by 13
  ⁼Ｉθ           Compare to the input
 Ｉ              Cast to string
Ｐ               Print without moving the cursor
```

Manages to output `1` for truthy and `0` for falsy. Subsequent repetitions compare the input against `13`, `26`, `39`, `52` etc. but each time the answer is overprinted so only the final answer is seen.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 32 Bytes

```
((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32))
```

if true be 0 and false as others, 31 bytes

```
(f=k=>n=>n>0?n-k:_=>f(k+_))(31)
```

```js
console.log([
    ((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32)) (31),
    ((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32)) (32),
    ((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32)) (33),
    ((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32)) (64),
    ((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32))((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32)) (32),
    ((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32))((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32)) (63),
    ((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32))((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32)) (64),
    ((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32))((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32))((f=k=>n=>n>0?n==k:f(k+32))(32)) (96)
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## MIPS, 4 bytes

Uses `$a0` as argument and return value.

```
0x2084fffc    addi $a0, $a0, -4
```

## MIPS, 8 bytes (using MIPS calling convention)

```
0x2084fff8    addi $a0, $a0, -8
0x00041021    move $v0, $a0
```

## x86, 5 bytes

This is my first x86 answer so feedback welcome. Uses _fastcall convention with ecx as first argument.

```
83 e9 05                sub    $0x5,%ecx
89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
```

[Peter Cordes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30206/peter-cordes) has a 1 byte solution in the comments.

---

**Brainfuck commentary**: The hard part is getting brainfuck to return a single value. Otherwise something like this would be easy.

```
- >,[-<->] < .
```

Comment: Your x86 code fragment would be the same size for 32-bit integers, no need to limit to 8.  But if you used a custom calling convention (arg in AL, retval somewhere else,), you could use the 2-byte AL special encoding `sub $4, %al` / `mov %al, %dl`.  Or still return in AL/EAX and then you get Dennis's solution, with `dec %eax` (1 byte in 32-bit mode).  And yes, custom calling conventions are fine for asm.  It's asm, not just "asm that's easy to call from C"; real code written in asm does use custom calling conventions where it helps, so this is totally justifiable.

Comment: ARM's normal calling convention is first arg in `r0` which is also the retval, so Thumb `sub r0, #2` is 2 bytes.

Comment: Note that neither of these are *functions*: they require a `ret` at the end of the repeat block before you could call them.  Normally I include the `ret` in byte counts for my x86 asm answers.  But I think bending the rules here to just the function *body* makes sense, otherwise many languages can't compete at all.

Comment: (nvm, this doesn't leave the retval in %al).  `xchg %eax, %ecx` / `sub $4, %al` / `xchg %eax, %ecx` is 4 bytes, and follows the _fastcall convention.  Using the AL, imm8 and xchg-with-eax short encodings are often helpful for code golf.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for providing such a detailed response! I was under the impression that some standard calling convention must be followed, otherwise it wouldn't qualify as a function, though as you said actually returning would make this challenge difficult. I also for some reason thought using 32 bit registers would require a 32 bit immediate, but that is probably me reading the instruction reference wrong.

Comment: @PeterCordes I do remember seeing that instructions that deal with eax have shorter forms. That's interesting to me. I am used to reading gdb asm output, so passing in in eax is unfamiliar territory.

Comment: I usually use `objdump -drwC -Mintel` to get a hexdump of the machine-code bytes.  `add r32, imm8` is also 3 bytes: opcode + ModR/M + imm8.  All instructions that can take an imm32 have an alternative opcode that takes a sign-extended imm8.  See http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html for example; all the "classic" ALU instructions (but not MOV) that date back to 8086 have all those encodings, including the special AL/AX/EAX ones with no modr/m, just op + imm8/16/32. [This answer has examples](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123194/user-appreciation-challenge-1-dennis/123458#123458)

Comment: And BTW, apparently the Irvine32 library passes an arg in EAX.  So does [`gcc -mregparm=3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474166/how-to-write-build-c-code-to-preserve-registers-that-are-normally-call-clobber/49476309#49476309).  I don't know why the usual x86 and x86-64 calling conventions avoid that; it's not unusual for functions to want to return their first arg, or a modified copy of their first arg (e.g. `strcpy`, `strchr`, or `strlen`).  Or use a retval as an arg like `foo( bar() )`

Comment: @PeterCordes why not post your 1 byte solution? I think it's great.

Comment: I thought it was just an improvement to yours; Dennis already came up with the "idea" of a single-byte dec.  But sure, I decided [to write it up](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/the-repetitive-byte-counter/160236#160236), and included a `main` that calls it from C after JITing a buffer (to make the answer interesting, and to show off  :P, and because I was curious how fast it would run).  Tested for inputs of about 2.6 GiB, above that `malloc` fails in 32-bit mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes do you mind adding the tip about calling conventions here? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code I've found it to be very useful. Also any other tips should be documented in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

## Octave: 23 bytes

```
+23;[ans,i]((N==ans)+1)
```

If N = L*M, the expression returns `0+i` (i.e. a purely imaginary number), otherwise the expression results in a complex number with a real component.

For a slightly nicer result at the cost of an extra byte:

```
+24;[ans,-1]((N==ans)+1)
```

If N = L*M the expression returns `-1`, otherwise a positive number.

Demo:

```
N=48;
+24;[ans,-1]((N==ans)+1)                                                 #>> 24 
+24;[ans,-1]((N==ans)+1)+24;[ans,-1]((N==ans)+1)                         #>> -1
+24;[ans,-1]((N==ans)+1)+24;[ans,-1]((N==ans)+1)+24;[ans,-1]((N==ans)+1) #>> 23
```

---

<sub>PS, you can get the same result with `+24;if N==ans;-1;end;ans` but the bytecount is the same</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
‹
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%80%B9&inputs=1&header=&footer=)

Outputs 0 for truthy and something else for falsy.

Port of the other answers, decrements.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

This is using the same technique as [Benoit Esnard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38454/benoit-esnard) in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132680/58563) (from *I double the source, you double the output!*).

Prints **0** if **n = 47 * M**, or a non-zero value otherwise.

```js
n=prompt(setTimeout`alert(n)`)-47/*
n-=47//*///
```

#### Demo for M = 1

```js
n=prompt(setTimeout`alert(n)`)-47/*
n-=47//*///
```

#### Demo for M = 2

```js
n=prompt(setTimeout`alert(n)`)-47/*
n-=47//*///n=prompt(setTimeout`alert(n)`)-47/*
n-=47//*///
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 24 bytes

```
({}[(((()()()){}){}){}])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fo7o2WgMINEFQs7oWgmI1////b2QCAA)

Just subtracts 24 from the input.  Outputs `0` for true and anything else for false.

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 68 bytes

```
{<>}<>(({}[((((()()()()){}){}()){}){}])<>{})((){[()](<{}<>>)}{}<>{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v@/2sau1sZOQ6O6NloDBDQhULO6FohgdKymjR2QAZStjtbQjNWwqQbqsdOsBVFA8f///wMA)

This one is more sophisticated it outputs `1` for true and `0` for false.